# Morphing Graphics, color and location

Tags: graphics, color, animation

I would like to make a small animation :

**1-We start with a random distribution of gray points :**

```
Graphics[{
          Black, Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}],
          Gray,Point /@ RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {4000, 2}]},
          PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

**2-Then I would like that those points progressively color themselves to obtain the following** :

```
Graphics[{
          Black, Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}],
          Pink,Point /@ RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {1000, 2}],
          RGBColor[.4, .4, 1],Point /@ RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {1000, 2}],
          Green,Point /@ RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {1000, 2}],
          Yellow,Point /@ RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {1000, 2}]},
          PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

Ideally :
-the points progressively adopt the color. All at the same time, at the same rate (2 seconds ?)
-OR each points suddenly change color but just 100 at a time.

**3-Finally, once the point are colored i would like to see them move, to join their piers like such :**

```
 normalRDN[μ_, σ_, No_] :=
 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], No]


Graphics[{
  Black, Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}],
  Pink,Point /@ ((normalRDN[#, .5, 1000] & /@ {-1, -1})\[Transpose]),
  RGBColor[.4, .4, 1],Point /@ ((normalRDN[#, .5, 1000] & /@ {-1, 1})\[Transpose]),
  Green,Point /@ ((normalRDN[#, .5, 1000] & /@ {1, -1})\[Transpose]),
  Yellow,Point /@ ((normalRDN[#, .5, 1000] & /@ {1, 1})\[Transpose])},
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

I am not sure of the means available for doing such animations, thus my illustrative codes might not be relevant.

Comment: Which law should define the movement? Probably the easiest way would to start with your "ordered" version (last image) and define random displacements for each colored dot. Interpolation in between should be not too complicated.

Comment: @YvesKlett starting with the end product would work, but I think starting at the random distribution would work, also. That said, I'd probably use simple kinematics with a color dependent gravity and a heavy damping force (to overdamp out the oscillations), and have each colored dot attracted to a "dark mass" near each corner. To give some additional spatial distribution, I'd also add a repulsive force between dots of the same color.

Comment: "progressively color themselves" one at a time or all together increasing color intensity?

Comment: @Vitality, all together I think.

Comment: @500, Vitaliy, besides, if you want to do something with physics take a look at: [Firework blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/07/01/celebrating-the-fourth-of-july-with-mathematica-fireworks/)

Comment: @Yu-Song, SO cool !

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try a simple way. Typical key frame animation is done by nothing more than n-degree interpolation (and n is usually 1), and they look quite reasonable.

Here is how I would tackle (it is generic version, so individual points have its own colors).

1. Define "start" and "final" positions:

   ```
   startPos = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {4000, 2}];

   normalRDN[μ_, σ_, No_] := RandomVariate[
     NormalDistribution[μ, σ], No];

   (* Tuples does the neat trick to create corner points *)
   finalPos = Join @@ Table[((normalRDN[#, .5, 1000] & /@ c)\[Transpose]),
      {c, Tuples[{-1, 1}, 2]}];
   ```
2. Define "start" and "final" colors as a list of triples:

   ```
   startCol = Table[0.5, {4000}, {3}];

   finalCol = Join[Table[{1., .5, .5}, {1000}], Table[{.4, .4, 1.}, {1000}],
      Table[{0., 1., 0.}, {1000}], Table[{1., 1., 0.}, {1000}]];
   (* Numericize them to make sure that the end results are all nicely packed. *)
   ```
3. Define "duration" functions: a function from time to [0, 1]

   ```
   locationDuration[t_] := Piecewise[{{0, t < 2},
      {0.5 t - 1, 2 <= t < 4}, {1, True}}]

   colorDuration[t_] := Piecewise[{{0, t < 0}, {0.5 t, 0 <= t < 2}, {1, True}}]
   ```

   They are just piecewise linear functions, but you can find your own (such as CDF--much smooth) or try random perturbation.
4. Define "easing" function: Interpolating from start to end values with duration

   ```
   easing[t_, f_, sPos_, fPos_] := (1 - f[t]) sPos + f[t] fPos;
   ```

   Again, it can be more sophisticated, but usually linear is OK.
5. Put them together: The key here is usage of VextexColors; very effective way to change colors.

   ```
   Manipulate[
      Graphics[Point[easing[t, locationDuration, startPos, finalPos], 
      VertexColors -> easing[t, colorDuration, startCol, finalCol]], 
      PlotRange -> 2, Background -> Black], {t, -0.5, 4.5, Animator, 
   AnimationRepetitions -> 1}]
   ```

Here is the result (tiny).

[image: Animation]

Forget to mention that when you are using VertexColors, it doesn't get antialiased by default unlike other 2D graphics (true for Polygon too). It may result in square points, not circular points. You may want to turn on the hardware AA in Preference->Appearance->Graphics. One way to avoid (if your graphics hardware does not support AA) is to use color directive separately for each color group.

Thanks!

Comment: @Y-Sung, Thank You very Much !!! Do you know how I could export that in a little movie or .gif ?

Comment: Very nice! I took the liberty to paste some images into place. Please feel free to do this properly.

Comment: @Yevs, Nope. Don't mind at all. Thanks

Comment: Make a `Table` of the frames then use `ListAnimate` and finally `Export["animation.gif",p]` where p is the output of `ListAnimate`.

Comment: @500, Also, you can try swf (Flash) or mov (QuickTime, in M8) export...

Comment: @vucko, I am sorry but I don`t understand I guess, this fails : frames = Table[Graphics[
    Point[easing[t, locationDuration, startPos, finalPos], 
     VertexColors -> easing[t, colorDuration, startCol, finalCol]], 
    PlotRange -> 2, Background -> Black], {t, -0.5, 4.5, .05}];   p = ListAnimate[frames];   Export["animation.gif", p]   What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @500 sorry, skip the `ListAnimate` part and just do `Export["animation.gif",frames]`.

Comment: @vucko. Thank You !

Comment: Looks like the merge went through. Again, welcome to the site.

Comment: @rollyer, Thank you!

Comment: @Yu-Sung, I added PointSize[] in front and it works to get them round !

Comment: @500, yes that would be one way too. Make points large enough so that it doesn't require subpixels to make them round.

Comment: Yu-Sung Chang, it appears you are going to be a good addition to the site.  Nice answer. :-)

Answer (score 15):

The contribution of this reply is to suggest that an interesting sequence can be created by **running the animation in reverse:** begin with the *final* (relatively ordered, highly colored, low-entropy) state and let it evolve physically so it "blows up."  Then let the points gradually lose their colors.  *This needs no interpolation to perform.*

**The basic functions are few:** `step` to create the next stage of the forward motion, `desaturate` to turn all colors a little grayer, and `display` to plot one frame.  In the following implementation, `step` utilizes a more basic function, `move`, which displaces a single point.  It is responsible for keeping the points within bounds.  (For convenience, the bounds turn out to be the rectangle $[1,3] \times [1,3]$.)

As an example, let's let the points diffuse (a Brownian motion).

```
ClearAll[move, step, desaturate, display];
move[Point[{x_, y_}], {dx_, dy_}] := 
 Point[{If[1 <= x + dx <= 3, x + dx, x - dx], If[1 <= y + dy <= 3, y + dy, y - dy]}]
```

(`move` displaces {x,y} by {dx,dy}, optionally reversing either of both of dx and dy in an effort to stay within the box.)

```
step[p_List, e_] := With[
   {dp = Table[RandomReal[{-e, e}, {Length[p[[i]]], 2}], {i, 1, 4}]},
   ParallelTable[MapThread[move, {p[[i]], dp[[i]]}], {i, 1, 4}]
];
```

(`step` generates random small displacements of up to `e` in any direction and then applies them to a set of points via `move`.)

```
desaturate[RGBColor[r_, g_, b_], e_] := With[{m = 0.6},
   RGBColor @@ ({r, g, b} (1 - e) + e {m, m, m})];
desaturate[c_List, e_] := desaturate[#, e] & /@ c;
```

(`desaturate` mixes a color with a little bit of gray.)

```
display[p_, colors_] := 
   Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{1, 1}, {3, 3}],  Riffle[colors, p]}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

That's all we need.  Here's how the pieces can be used.

**Create the initial (ultimately final) state.**

```
n = 200;
colors = {Blue, Yellow, Red, Green};
points = Flatten[
   MapIndexed[Function[{xy}, Point[xy + #2]] /@ #1 & , 
    RandomReal[BetaDistribution[2, 2], {2, 2, n, 2}], {2}], 1];
```

**Diffuse the points.**

```
frames1 = 
  ParallelMap[display[#, colors] &, stage1 = NestList[step[#, 0.075] &, points, 192]];
```

**Turn them gray.**

```
frames2 = 
  ParallelMap[display[Last[stage1], #] &, NestList[desaturate[#, 0.1] &, colors, 64]];
```

**Assemble the animation and *reverse* it.**

`ca` inserts some pauses at the beginning, middle, and end.

```
ca = Function[{s, i}, ConstantArray[s[[i]], 16]];
ListAnimate[
  Join[ca[frames1, 1], frames1, ca[frames1, -1], frames2, ca[frames2, -1]] // Reverse]
```

The reverse diffusion is so random and undirected that it looks pretty amazing when all the points coalesce at the end.

[image: Animation]

Comment: As always, a pleasure to read your answer! :)

Comment: Same as above ! THank You very much !

Answer (score 13):

How about using a random walk? Starting from an initial list of random points `pts0` we're creating a random walk by moving each point over a distance `dr` in an arbitrary direction at each time step. Since the points should drift towards a centre we also apply a force to each point depending on the distance of the point to the centre given by `force`. The parameter `df` indicates the strength of the force. Then `pts[[i, All, j]]` is the random walk for point `j` of colour `i`.

```
dim = {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}};
dr = .1;
df = .08;
nn = 1000;
tsteps = 40;
force[pt_, p0_] := (p0 - pt)/Sqrt[2]
p0 = Tuples[{-0.5, .5}, 2];
pts0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, nn, 2}];
cols = {Yellow, Green, Blue, Red};
angs = RandomReal[2 Pi, {4, tsteps, nn}];
pts = Table[FoldList[# + (dr {Cos[#], Sin[#]} & /@ #2) + (df force[#, 
           p0[[i]]] & /@ #) &, pts0[[i]], angs[[i]]], {i, 4}];
```

We could use `pts` directly to create an animation, but for a smoother effect we're moving the points along bspline curves spanned by the random paths

```
curves = Table[BSplineFunction[#] & /@ Transpose[pts[[i]]], {i, 4}];
pts1 = Table[curves[[i, j]][x], {i, 4}, {x, 0, 1, .005}, {j, nn}];
```

Then plotting the points for each time step gives:

```
grlist = Table[Graphics[{PointSize[.001], 
     Table[{cols[[i]], Point[pts1[[i, t]]]}, {i, 4}]}, 
    PlotRange -> dim, Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 150],
   {t, 1, Length[pts1[[1]]], 1}];
```

**Edit**

For the transition from grey to coloured points we're using a blend of `GrayLevel[.5]` with the appropriate colours:

```
col[t_, i_] := Blend[{GrayLevel[.5], cols[[i]]}, t]
dt = .005;
grlist0 = Table[Graphics[{PointSize[.001], 
     Table[{col[t, i], Point[pts0[[i]]]}, {i, 4}]},
    Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 150, PlotRange -> dim],
   {t, 0, 1, dt}];
```

Here, `dt` is the rate at which the colours change from gray to colour. By joining `grlist0` and `grlist`, and exporting everything to a .gif we get

```
Export["drift_small.gif", Join[grlist0, grlist]]
```

[image: drifting points]

Comment: this is so smooth ! Any way to start with Gray points ?

Comment: sorry, i have tried unsuccessfully to adapt other solutions strategy for color :-(

Comment: @500 I've added blending to my answer.

Comment: As usual you make something extra pretty.

Answer (score 10):

Yu-Sung has answered your question well. Here is my approach which is slightly different in some aspects, but the basic idea is nevertheless the same.

First generate the list of points and graphics for the first part:

```
pts1 = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {4000, 2}] ~Partition~ 4 // Transpose;
g1 = Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}], Gray, 
   Point[pts1 ~Flatten~ 1]}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}];
g2 = Graphics[{
        {Black, Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]},
        {Red, Point[#1]}, {Blue, Point[#2]},
        {Green, Point[#3]}, {Yellow, Point[#4]}},
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}] & @@ pts1;
```

For the transition from grayscale to colour, I use `ImageCompose` with varying alpha levels to simulate the transition.

```
frames1 = Table[ImageCompose[Image@g1, {Image@g2, α}], {α, 0, 1, 0.05}];
```

For the second part, we generate points from a multivariate distribution as:

```
pts2 = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[#, 0.25 IdentityMatrix[2]], 
    {1000}] & /@ Tuples[{-1, 1}, 2];
```

Note that I constructed `pts1` and `pts2` to have the same shape, so now I can simply pair them up and transition with a linear path and generate frames:

```
path[pt1_, pt2_, t_] := (1 - t) pt1 + t pt2
frames2 = Table[Graphics[{
        {Black, Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]},
        {Red, Point[#1]}, {Blue, Point[#2]},
        {Green, Point[#3]}, {Yellow, Point[#4]}},
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}] & @@ path[pts1, pts2, t], {t, 0, 1, 0.05}];
```

Combining the two and exporting, you get:

```
Export["morph.gif", frames1 ~Join~ frames2]
```

[image]

Comment: Uh, `Partition` plus infix notation makes my head ache, otherwise +1   ;-)

Comment: @YvesKlett That's there solely to get Mr.Wizard's vote ;)

Answer (score 3):

I nice 3D effect of the particles evolution using `Image3D` on @Heike's gif.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VDkO.gif"];
Image3D[img]
```

[image]