# Clustering a bivariate data set with Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, cluster-analysis

I need to partition a bivariate data set into predetermined "n" clusters and, at the same time, to fix the centroid position of each cluster. Is the [`ClusteringComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ClusteringComponents.html) function useful?

Thanks BR for your help. I will use your example to explain better my question
I want to Split your “data” into two  (n=2) clusters. Previously, I want to fix the coordinate (centroids) of the two clusters.

```
data = With[{ρ = -0.4}, 
RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{-1, 1}, {1, 2}, ρ], 10000]];

FIXEDcentroids = {{-2, 0}, {0.5, -0.4}};

Show[ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, Axes -> False], 
ListPlot[FIXEDcentroids, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.02]}]]
```

The next step should be to "force" the clustering process to split the “data” set according the position of the two predefined centroids.

If I use the `FindCluster` traditional form:

```
NumberOfCluster = 2;
clusterdata = FindClusters[data, NumberOfCluster];
```

I obtained two new centroids.

```
centroidFindClusters = Mean[#] & /@ clusterdata
```

Obviously the two new centroids are differents from those that I preselected (i.e. FIXEDcentroids). Therefore I am not able to solve my problem....
...if were possible to write: 
`FindClusters[data, FIXEDcentroids]` it would be perfect......

Comment: Welcome to mma.SE! If you edit the question with some example code and example data, I'm sure you'll get even better answers (please format your code by indenting it by four spaces or by using back-ticks (``) .

Comment: Without more information about your exact problem, it's hard to say, but in short, yes. You might also want to look at the [`FindClusters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindClusters.html) function.

Comment: By the way, welcome, and please consider registering your account. That way, any upvotes you get on this question are added to those you might get on future questions and answers. Then over time you will be able to [do more on the site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/privileges) (post graphics, edit things, etc).

Comment: Welcome Andrea! Please supply us with a workable data set and a concise summary of what exactly you´d like to achieve and what you´ve tried so far. Have a look at other popular questions [(recent sample)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10445/generating-an-ordered-list-of-pairs-of-elements-from-ordered-lists) to get a feeling how this could look like.

Comment: There's no guarantee that a clustering exists which has the cluster means that you specify. Are you trying to minimize the distance from the cluster means to the `FIXEDcentroids`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 11):

This may give you a start. Code below is built on an example from [**this page**](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/nonparametric-derived-and-formula-distributions/), where you can find more very neat stats examples. Get some data on duration of Old Faithful geyser eruptions and construct a distribution based on it:

```
data = ExampleData[{"Statistics", "OldFaithful"}];
\[ScriptCapitalD] = KernelMixtureDistribution[data, "SheatherJones"];
```

Now simulate eruptions based on this distribution:

```
rng = RandomVariate[\[ScriptCapitalD], 500];
```

The data are bi-variate and split into 2 main clusters. Use `FindClusters` to separate them (red and black):

```
Show[SmoothDensityHistogram[rng, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"],
 ListPlot[FindClusters[rng, 2], PlotRange -> {{1, 6}, {30, 110}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 220, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}, 
  PlotLabel -> Text[Style["Simulated Eruptions", FontFamily -> "Verdana", Bold]], 
  Background -> Directive[Opacity[.5], White], Axes -> None]]
```

[image]

Here is an alternative visualization:

```
p2 = ListPlot[FindClusters[rng, 2], PlotRange -> {{1, 6}, {30, 110}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 220, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Black}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Text[Style["Simulated Eruptions", FontFamily -> "Verdana", Bold]],
    Background -> Directive[Opacity[.5], White], Axes -> None];

p1 = Plot3D[Evaluate[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], {x, y}]], {x, 1, 6}, {y, 30, 105}, 
  Mesh -> 25, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> Text[Style["Duration vs. Waiting Time", FontFamily -> "Verdana", 
     Large]], BoxRatios -> 1, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  MeshStyle -> Opacity[.3], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
  Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {2, -2, 1}, 
  Epilog -> Inset[p2, {Right, Bottom}, {Right, Bottom}], ImageSize -> 570]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here I can give you some direction!

### Bi-variate Data

We draw random data from a built-in distribution in MMA. First see the `PDF` of our `BinormalDistribution`.

[image]

Now we draw some $10000$ data sample and visualize it using `ListPlot`

```
data = With[{\[Rho] = -0.4}, 
RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{-1, 1}, {1, 2}, \[Rho]],10000]];
ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

### Clustering..

Now MMA does the clustering with in a blink! We save the $n$ say $(=10)$ cluster in `clusterdata`.

```
NumberOfCluster = 10;
clusterdata = FindClusters[data, NumberOfCluster];
centroid = Mean[#] & /@ clusterdata;
```

### Visualize!

We can show the centroids as well as the handy `PolytopeQuantile` for each clusters.

```
Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"];
quantile = 0.8;
col = RGBColor[#] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {NumberOfCluster, 3}];
Show[{Show[MapThread[
 ListPlot[#1, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> #2] &, {clusterdata, col}], 
Epilog -> {Directive[Black], PointSize[Large], Point[centroid]}, 
PlotRange -> All]}~Join~
MapThread[Graphics[{Darker@#1, Thick, 
  PolytopeQuantile[#2, {quantile}]}] &, {col, clusterdata}], 
  ImageSize -> 500, 
  PlotLabel -> "PolytopeQuantile:=" <> ToString[100*quantile] <> "%"]
```

[image]

Hope this helps...

BR