# Is there a convenient/automatic way of uploading a notebook into SE?

Tags: notebooks, internet

This [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3535/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-copy-paste-text-interspersed-se-code-snippets-into) discusses how to streamline the other way - extracting code from a fragmented and longish SE answer but I imagine a two-way workflow like:

Fashion an answer/question in an SE-templated notebook with a submit button that converts both text/input cells into their SE equivalents. The notebook could also be effectively uploaded to SE by having the conversion include a link back to a public repository to which the original notebook is also sent.

Comment: There isn't a convenient/standardized way yet, but see a couple of ideas that Sjoerd and belisarius have been toying with [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/632/5) to attach a notebook as a gif (not convert to SE style)

Comment: I was also thinking about it, and this was one of the reasons I started the [code formatter](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/programmatic-formatting-for-mathematica-code-possible/2810#2810) project, since appropriate code formatting is one of the essential parts. I have it high on my todo list to debug the current formatter and adopt it to SE format, and in general I think we are coming closer to the point when we accumulate enough tools to make such thing possible.

Comment: Try this `NotebookPut@
 ImportString[
  Uncompress@
   FromCharacterCode@
    TakeWhile[
     Flatten@ImageData[Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/mV4FJ.png"], 
       "Byte"], # != 0 &], "NB"]`

Comment: What additional features to this: [100127](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84556/5478) are you looking for? Probably an automatic images uploading, right?

Comment: @Kuba This was the first question I posted on SE and something many people seem to have considered then and since but alas still no ongoing solution. Your initial stab is already v. handy though - I've made some comments at your Markdown answer.