# speed up iteration with conditionals plus optimize memory usage

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, performance-tuning

Given `list1` and `list2` whose elements are vectors of a certain (fixed) dimension, I am interested in the behaviour of a scalar function `cfn[list1[[i]],list2[[j]]]`.
As I defined it this function outputs for me a list of entries formatted as `{list1[[i]], list2[[j]], scalar}`
since I would also like to keep track of which vectors the scalar number came from.

The fastest way to generate such a list is of course to use  Outer to map my function over the two lists

```
Outer[cfn[#1 ,#2]&, list1 ,list2,1]
```

However this will produce for me a complete list of values for the function after scanning through my lists and since my lists are very long the process is long and I run out of memory if I increase the dimension (typically `list1*list2` is a function also of the fixed dimension and I seem to be fine doing order of 10 million computations).

If I am uninterested in all the function values, but say only those in a certain range `cmin < cfn[list1,list2] < cmax`
is there an efficient way to scan the lists and pick out just these?
I tried the obvious nested For loops and as expected ended up slowing down the computation significantly.

Thanks!

Edit: As requested in the comments I am attaching a simplified version of my code which only computes the inner product of the two vectors after some redefinitions.
`n` is a number that we specify and `list1` and `list2` are lists whose entries are integer valued vectors of length `(n-1)` e.g., `list1[[1]] = {0, 0, 0, 4}`
etc.

```
cfn[list1_List, list2_List, n_] := Module[{rhow}, 
    rhow = Table[1, {i, 1, n - 1}]; 
        Lambda = list1 - list2 + rhow; 
hdim = Lambda.Lambda; 
    Return[{list1, list2, hdim}]]; 

Timing[data = Flatten[Outer[cfn[#1 , #2, n] &, list1 , list2, 1], 1];
       selectdata = Select[data, cmin < #[[3]] < cmax &];]
```

The second code which nests the For loops:

```
rhow = Table[1, {i, 1, n - 1}];
sampledataAlt[list1_List, list2_List, n_] := Module[{},
            sampledata2 = {};
            For[i = 1, i <= Length[list1], i++,
            For[j = 1, j <= Length[list2], j++,
                Lambda = list1[[i]] - list2[[j]] + rhow;
                hdim  = Lambda.Lambda;
                If[cmin < hdim < cmax, 
 dataNEW = {list1[[i]], list2[[j]], hdim}, dataNEW = {}];
                sampledata2 = Join[sampledata2, dataNEW];]];
                Return[sampledata2];]
 Timing[test = Partition[sampledataAlt[list1, list2, 5], 3];]
```

where I have made some list manipulations to split things up.

For my trial with `Length[list1] = 126` and `Length[list2] = 210` the second code is marginally faster, but it slows down when I increase the list sizes.

Comment: Would it be possible to have full, executable examples please?  I find that I am much more likely to attempt to answer questions like this if I can copy and paste something into Mathematica, run it and then start playing around

Comment: what's wrong with `Outer[cfn[#1, #2] &, list1[[Range[2, 4]]], list2[[Range[3, 5]]]]`

Comment: I have added a sample code which is a simplified version of what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: One thing I would definitely try for numerical lists is to use `Compile`. If there are certain properties of your `cfn` function such as monotonous behavior, or anything else that would allow you to guess the ordering of your results, then you may consider a similar [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10445/generating-an-ordered-list-of-pairs-of-elements-from-ordered-lists)

Comment: Thanks for the code but would you mind going one step further and create some random input test lists please?

Comment: @WalkingRandomly: I now have a pair of lists for you to try. See [lists.nb](http://cl.ly/453P1Q2s411r).

Comment: Thanks again.  I loaded them. Also set n=100,cim=3,cmax=6 -- no idea if that makes sense.  Ran your samples and got lots of 'Objects of unequal length errors'

Comment: @WalkingRandomly. Sorry `n` is related to the length of the vectors. You want to set `n =5` if you are using the lists I uploaded.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Thanks for your input. Compile did occur as a possibility, but since I really am after the behaviour of the function, it didn't seem to help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach is to calculate all the function values, but don't attach the elements of `list1` and `list2` until *after* filtering out the unwanted values. This should save quite a bit of memory. In the code below I redefine `cfn` to return only the dot product, use `Outer` as you did, then `Position` to locate the elements between `cmin` and `cmax`. Your final data structure is pulled together from `list1`, `list2` and `data` using the output from `Position`.

```
cfn[l1_, l2_] := (#.#) &[l1 - l2 + 1]

list1 = Developer`ToPackedArray[list1];
list2 = Developer`ToPackedArray[list2];

data = Outer[cfn, list1, list2, 1];
p = Position[data, x_ /; 10 < x < 15, {2}, Heads -> False];
selectdata = Transpose[{list1[[p[[All, 1]]]], list2[[p[[All, 2]]]], Extract[data, p]}];
```

Comment: This is a nice trick; I will check if it works for my problem.