# Little problem with Through

Tags: list-manipulation

```
list = Partition[Range[20], 5, 5, 1, {}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18, 19, 20}}
> ```

```
pos = Transpose[{Through[First, Last] /@ list, Through[Last, First] /@ list}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 5}, {6, 10}, {11, 15}, {16, 20}}
> ```

As you see, I've used `Through` twice. I think once should be enough, but I haven't been able to see how to do it with one `Through`. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not `{First[#], Last[#]} & /@  list` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks yes, me silly, haha, you can post that as one answer.

Comment: I'm sure there will be more creative answers.

Comment: To properly use `Through[]`: `Through[{First, Last}[#]] & /@ list`. Slot-free version: `Composition[Through, {First, Last}] /@ list`.

Comment: @0x4A4D nice+1, you've done it, I've tried `Through[{First,Last}]/@list`, you can answer my question too.

Comment: `Through[{First, Last}] /@ list` won't work, as you've seen. That's because the syntax is supposed to be `Through[{f1, f2, f3, ...}[arg1, arg2, arg3, ...]]`. You put in the functions, but forgot the arguments.

Comment: Anyway, maybe you can answer your own question, if you understood what I was trying to point out to you.

Comment: @0x4A4D Fine, seems people do not like this question. I'll delete it later, thanks.
well, my output-style was edited,@@,

Comment: I didn't ask you to delete the question; I asked you if you could write an answer to your question (answering your own question is acceptable in this site, in case that wasn't made clear to you.) You can stand to gain rep from upvotes to your answer, and we can critique your understanding of the matter at hand.

Comment: @ox4A4D ok, I learned that, I'll post one answer.

Comment: Are you aware that you can do this with `Part`?  `list[[All,{1,-1}]]`

Comment: @SimonWoods en, that time my first thought is use `through`, I tried your method here by `{First[#], Last[#]} &/@`. Maybe you can also give me come comments about that question.
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27114/6648

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tried this

```
list = Partition[Range[20], 5, 5, 1, {}];
Through[{First, Last}] /@ list
(* {Through[{First,Last}][{1,2,3,4,5}],Through[{First,Last}][{6,7,8,9,10}],
    Through[{First,Last}][{11,12,13,14,15}],Through[{First,Last}][{16,17,18,19,20}]} *)
```

Let's see the example in help page of `Through`

```
Through[{f, g, h}[x]]   
(* {f[x],g[x],h[x]} *)
```

as @0x4A4D  metioned in the comment. We need one argument for

```
Through[{First, Last}[#]] & /@ list
(* {{1,5},{6,10},{11,15},{16,20}} *)
```

this is one error usage

```
Through[{f, g, h}][x]
(* Through[{f,g,h}][x] *)

Through[{f, g, h}[#]] &[x]
(* {f[x],g[x],h[x]} *)
```

Comment: Well done. ${}$

Comment: Please don't make this an orgy of different formatting styles...

Comment: @rm-rf hi,Do you mean the <kbd>tag?  I'm learning format in SE, Do you think the hint word `Output` is necessary?

Comment: @HyperGroups nice answer (+1). The `<kbd>` tag stands for *keyboard*, which is usually used for indicating a *key* on the *keyboard*, e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. So it may not be a best choice for "Output". In fact, on this site, people usually just put the output results in blockquotes without any "hint word".

Comment: @Silvia Ok, I learned that.

Comment: @HyperGroups Yes, that, but also several other things that I've noticed from other posts. 1) There is no need to repeat the question title in `<h1>` or to have a heading "My answer", because both are clear from the context. 2) Please do not use `<pre>` — when you asked me earlier, I was referring to its use in some tricky situations (very rare). You're indenting by 4 _and_ using `<pre>`, which messes up the layout. Please learn how to indent using markdown instead (hundreds of thousands of users across the SE network have no problem with it...). [continued...]

Comment: 3) `<kbd>` tags should be used for indicating keys on a keyboard. 4) The quote block is being heavily abused (not just by you). While sometimes it is justified, I disagree with its use for output (although I can't do much about it). I prefer the alternate convention of commenting out the output (like I did in my edit above), because then you can simply copy the block and run in _Mathematica_ and you won't run into issues. Also, output in code within blockquote  will mess with [this API based code extractor](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3537/5), since is is inserted in an input cell.

Comment: @rm-rf I agree that using `(*...*)` would be more convenient for copying the whole code block all at once. But about the extractor, please see [my comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3535/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-copy-paste-text-interspersed-se-code-snippets-into/3537#comment83655_3537). :)

Comment: @rm-rf fine, I'll take some suggestions.