# NDSolveValue - Heat flux continuity

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, discontinuity, heat-equation

I'm having some problems with `NDSolve` and the problem of conduction of heat. Specifically I'm having problems with the continuity of heat flux. First, let me explain what is the physical problem:

[image]

Let´s say I want to study the heat conduction in a composite material with n layers (see figure above), each one presenting a different value for its thermal properties (thermal conductivies, $k_1, k_2,..., k_n$, specific heat, $c_{p_1},...,c_{p_n} $ and densities, $\rho_1, ..., \rho_n$). In this case we could write:

$
k[z] = k_1 + \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n-1} (k_{i+1}-k_i) H[z-z_i]
$

$
\rho[z] = \rho_1 + \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n-1} (\rho_{i+1}-\rho_i) H[z-z_i]
$

$
c_p[z] = c_{p_1} + \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n-1} (c_{p_{i+1}}-c_{p_{i}}) H[z-z_i]
$

where $z$ indicates the depth and $H$ is a function that changes abrubtly (ideally is the `UnitStep` function). As you can see, there will be discontinuities in $k[z]$.

The PDE describing our problem is the heat equation:

$
\rho c_p \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \nabla.(k\nabla T) + Q_{ext}
$

where $ \rho, c_p, k$ and $ Q_{ext} $ are the density, the specific heat, the thermal conductivity and heat generation rate of the external heat source.

In our problem, we have convection of heat at the top of layer 1 and a constant temperature at the bottom of the last layer. We also require the continuity of both the temperature and the heat flux. Therefore, the boundary conditions can be expressed as:

$
k_1 \frac{\partial T}{\partial z}_{z=0} = h (T_{env}-T_{z=0})
$

$
T_{z=z_n} = T_{wall}
$

$
k_n \frac{\partial T}{\partial z}_{z\rightarrow z_n^+} = k_{n+1} \frac{\partial T}{\partial z}_{z\rightarrow z_n^-} \text{; for n = 1,...,n-1}
$

where $h$, $T_{env}$ and $T_{wall}$ are just constants.

The last written set of boundary conditions indicates the continuity of the heat flux, $q'' = - k \frac{\partial T}{\partial z}$, between the interfaces of the different layers. They are the ones I don't know how to impose in `NDSolveValue`.

This is what I have been doing so far:

```
(*Required packages*)

Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
(*Some paremeters*)
conds = {αp -> 0.8*10^-4, Tenv -> 22, Tcore -> 35, ha -> 12, 
   Ptotal -> 1.30, Vtotal -> 2.25*10^-6, rlaser -> 0.13, 
   Llaser -> 4.5*10^-3, lasert -> 3*60};
dvalues = {1*10^-3, 3*10^-3, 3*10^-3, 1*10^-3, 
  6*10^-3}; (*thicknesses*)
kcond = {0.235, 0.445, 0.445, 0.185, 
  0.51}; (*thermal conductivity of layers*)
ρdens = {1200, 1200, 1200, 1000, 1085}; (*densities*)
cspe = {3589, 3300, 3300, 2674, 3800}; (*specific heat*)
(*Depth of layers*)
zvalues = Table[Sum[dvalues[[j]], {j, 1, i}], {i, 1, Length[dvalues]}];
noflayers = Length[zvalues]; (*number of layers*)
(*Z dependence of thermal properties*)
kcondz[z_] := 
 kcond[[1]] + 
   Sum[(kcond[[j]] - kcond[[j - 1]])*(1/2 + 
       Tanh[(z - zvalues[[j - 1]])/αp]/2) , {j, 2, 
     noflayers}] /. conds;
ρxc[z_] := ρdens[[1]] cspe[[1]] + 
    Sum[(cspe[[j]] ρdens[[j]] - 
        cspe[[j - 1]] ρdens[[j - 1]])*(1/2 + 
        Tanh[(z - zvalues[[j - 1]])/αp]/2) , {j, 2, 
  noflayers}] /. conds;
Qlaser[t_, r_, 
   z_] := (Ptotal/Vtotal) UnitStep[
     rlaser - r] UnitStep[-t] Exp[-z/Llaser] /. conds;
(*Penne's bioheat equation in cylindrical coordinates*)
eqn = (D[kcondz[z], z]*D[u[t, r, z], z]) + 
    kcondz[z]*(D[u[t, r, z], z, 
        z] + (1/r) D[r D[u[t, r, z], r], r]) - (ρxc[z] D[
       u[t, r, z], t]) + Qlaser[t, r, z] /. conds;
(*Region studied*)
Ω = 
  ImplicitRegion[True, {{r, 0.001, 1}, {z, 0, zvalues[[noflayers]]}}];
(*Solution*)
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn == 
    NeumannValue[(u[t, r, z] - Tenv) (ha)/(kcondz[z]) /. conds, 
     z == 0], 
   DirichletCondition[u[t, r, z] == Tcore /. conds, 
    z == zvalues[[noflayers]]], 
   DirichletCondition[u[t, r, z] == Tcore /. conds, r == 1], 
   u[-lasert, r, z] == Tcore /. conds}, {u, 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)}, {t, -lasert /. conds, 
   1500}, {r, z} ∈ Ω, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]
```

`NDSolveValue` indeed finds a solution. The problem is, if you try to plot `tdiff[z]*D[sol[t,r,z],z]` (that is, the heat flux), you will find a lot of discontinuities (see figure below). Therefore this is not a physical solution to the problem.

```
Plot[-kcondz[z] Evaluate[sol[[2]][0, 0.5, z]], {z, 0, 
  zvalues[[noflayers]]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Discontinuity of heat flux]

Can somebody please show me a way to impose the boundary conditions concerning the heat flux continuity at the interfaces of the layers?

Thanks

Comment: The continuity of heat flux can be imposed by making a change of variable. You just need to make the change $k ξ = z$. I'm a little busy at the moment so can't write an detailed answer this week. 8楼 of [this post](http://tieba.baidu.com/p/3979151769) is an answer for a similar problem. (It's written in Chinese, but I think you can at least read the code. )

Comment: @xzczd I will give a look at this post. I will try to use Google Translator. Thanks!

Comment: @xzczd I was thinking about the change of variable that you suggested but, since the relation between $\xi$ and $z$ is not unequivocal, I believe there will be problems if you have a composite material with more than two layers. For instance, in our problem $\xi$ assumes the value of 0.0221569 for both z = 0.0113 and z = 0.004102. Therefore, the condition $T_{z=0.0113}=T_{wall}$ cannot be expressed in terms of $\xi$. Am I right?

Comment: I made a mistake in my last comment. The relationship between $z$ and $\xi$ should be $dz=k d\xi$ i.e. $z=k\xi + b$. (Notice $b$ is probably piecewise, too.)

Comment: @xzczd Thanks! I will try to write something along these lines.

Comment: @xzczd I've followed your suggestion and written a code that guarantees that $\xi$ and $z$ have an unequivocal relationship. However, I cannot get rid of the following problem:

"No places were found where $\xi = 0.0413921$" was True, so DirichletCondition[-35+u==0, $\xi$=0.0413921] will effectively be ignored".

How can I solve this?

Comment: http://verl.npre.illinois.edu/Documents/J-10-02.pdf

Comment: Without the exact code, it's hard to tell what causes your problem. Anyway I've written an answer, have a look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This post contains several code blocks, you can copy them easily with the help of [`importCode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3537/1871).

---

## Pre-*v10* Soluion

> **Note**: If you're in or after *v10*, it's recommended to turn to the solution in **Update: `"FiniteElement"`-based  Solution** section of this answer. That one is much simpler and more efficient.

Finally I managed to find some time to write this answer. The key idea of this solution is, as said in the comment above, making the change $dz=kd\xi$ to ensure the continuity of heat flux.

…OK, I think I need to explain why the transformation $dz=kd\xi$ will ensure the continuity of heat flux first. Well, actually this has been mentioned in the **Scope** of document of [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) but a little vague. Anyway, have you ever noticed the behavior of `NDSolve` when it faces a piecewise coefficient? If not, check the following examples.

> Example 1, **1st** order ODE, with piecewise coeffcient

```
coef = Piecewise[{{1, x <= 2}, {-1, x > 2}}];
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{coef y'[x] == x, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 3}];
Plot[sol1[x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

As shown above, `NDSolve` outputs a **0** order continuous solution.

> Example 2, **2nd** order ODE, with piecewise coeffcient

```
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{coef y''[x] == x, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == -1}, y, {x, 0, 3}];
Plot[{sol2[x], sol2'[x]}, {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

As shown above, `NDSolve` outputs a **1st** order continuous solution.

> Example 3, **3rd** order ODE, with piecewise coeffcient

```
sol3 = NDSolveValue[{coef y'''[x] == x, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == -1, y''[0] == 0}, 
   y, {x, 0, 3}];
Plot[{sol3[x], sol3'[x], sol3''[x]}, {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

As shown above, `NDSolve` outputs a **2nd** order continuous solution.

> Example 4, 1D heat conduction equation, with piecewise coeffcient for the $\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}$ term

```
coef4 = Piecewise[{{1, x <= 3/2}, {3, x > 3/2}}];
sol4 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] == coef4 D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == x (3 - x), 
    u[t, 0] == 0, u[t, 3] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 3}, MaxStepSize -> 0.01];
Plot[{sol4[2, x], Derivative[0, 1][sol4][2, x]}, {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

As shown above, `NDSolve` outputs a solution that is **1st** order continuous in **x-direction**.

To sum up, for differential equation involving **n** order derivative term with a piecewise coefficient, `NDSolve` will give a solution which is **n-1** order continuous in the corresponding direction.

Back to your question, after the transform $dz=kd\xi$, the dependent variable of your equation will become

$$U(t, r, \xi)=u(t,r,z(\xi))$$

*Notice I've used a new variable $U$ to strictly distinguish the function relationship.*

According to the illustrations above, after the transformation, $\frac{\partial U(t,r,\xi)}{\partial \xi}$ will be continuous in the output of `NDSolve`, while

$$\frac{\partial U(t,r,\xi)}{\partial \xi}=\frac{\partial u(t,r,z(\xi))}{\partial z(\xi)}\frac{\partial z(\xi)}{\partial \xi}=k \frac{\partial u(t,r,z(\xi))}{\partial z(\xi)}$$

So, making the transformation is equivalent to impose the heat flux continuity condition.

OK, analysis finished, let's programme.

Notice I've made some tiny modifications to `dvalues` and `zvalues` just to make it conciser:

```
conds = {αp -> 0.8/10^4, Tenv -> 22, Tcore -> 35, ha -> 12, 
       Ptotal -> 1.3, Vtotal -> 2.25/10^6, rlaser -> 0.13, 
       Llaser -> 4.5/10^3, lasert -> 3 60}; 
dvalues = {0, 1/10^3, 3/10^3, 3/10^3, 1/10^3, 6/10^3}; 
kcond = {0.235, 0.445, 0.445, 0.185, 0.51}; 
ρdens = {1200, 1200, 1200, 1000, 1085}; 
cspe = {3589, 3300, 3300, 2674, 3800}; 
zvalues = Accumulate[dvalues]; 
Qlaser[t_, r_, z_] = (Ptotal UnitStep[rlaser - r] UnitStep[-t] 
            Exp[-(z/Llaser)])/Vtotal /. conds;
```

Your original definition for `kcondz` and `ρxc` contains `Tanh`, which seems to be a smoothing for the function. As far as I can tell, this somewhat complicated definition isn't necessary for obtaining a solution and stops one from making an analytic transform. (One can turn to numeric transform instead, of course. ) So I chose the simpler `Piecewise` approach:

```
coefuncgenerator[cond_List] := 
 Piecewise[MapThread[{#1, #2[[1]] < z <= #2[[2]]} &, {cond, Partition[zvalues, 2, 1]}], 
  First@cond]

kcondz[z_] = coefuncgenerator[kcond]; 
ρxc[z_] = coefuncgenerator[ρdens cspe]; 

Plot[ρxc[z], {z, 0, Last[zvalues]}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Now let's find the relationship between `z` and `ξ`:

```
ξfunc = ξ /. First[DSolve[{ξ'[z] == 1/kcondz[z], ξ[0] == 0}, ξ, z]];
```

It's a pity that at least currently [`DChange`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80241/1871) can't do the change of variable for us, so I make the transformation in a more primitive way:

```
zfunc[ξ_] = 
 Piecewise@Transpose@{z /. Solve[ξ == #, z][[1]] & /@ ξfunc[z][[1, All, 1]], 
      ξfunc[z][[1, All, -1]] /. {z -> ξ, a_?NumericQ :> ξfunc@a}};

Plot[zfunc@ξ, {ξ, 0, ξfunc@Last@zvalues}]
```

[image]

> **Remark**
>
> You can also find relationship between `z` and `ξ` numerically in the
>   following way:
>
> ```
> ξfunc = 
>   NDSolveValue[{ξ'[z] == 1/kcondz[z], ξ[0] == 0}, ξ, {z, 0, Last@zvalues}];
>
> derivativeOnGrid = 
>   Sequence @@ (Partition[#[[-2, -1]], #[[2, 3]] + 1]\[Transpose] // Rest) &;
>
> zfunc = ListInterpolation[{#["Coordinates"][[1]], 1/derivativeOnGrid@#}\[Transpose], {#[
>        "ValuesOnGrid"]}] &@ξfunc;
> ```
>
> Notice this approach will make the last step i.e. differential
>   equation solving slower.

```
ρxcnew[ξ_] = ρxc@zfunc@ξ // Simplify;
kcondznew[ξ_] = kcondz@zfunc@ξ // Simplify;

neweqn = kcondznew[ξ] (D[u[t, r, ξ], ξ, ξ]/kcondznew[ξ]^2 + 
            D[r D[u[t, r, ξ], r], r]/r) - ρxcnew[ξ] D[u[t, r, ξ], t] + 
       Qlaser[t, r, zfunc[ξ]];
```

*Notice the `D[kcondz[z], z]*D[u[t, r, z], z]` in the original equation is taken away because it's zero in this case.*

I'm not in *v10* yet so can't use `"FiniteElement"` method. In *v9* I added an extra condition `Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 10^-3, ξ] == 0` to suppress the warning `NDSolveValue::bcart`. Though `NDSolveValue` still spits out the warning `NDSolveValue::ibcinc`, it gives an answer:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
   sol = NDSolveValue[{neweqn == 0, 
           ha (u[t, r, ξ] - Tenv) == D[u[t, r, ξ], ξ] /. ξ -> 0, 
           u[t, r, ξfunc[Last[zvalues]]] == 
               Tcore, Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, 10^(-3), ξ] == 0, 
           u[t, 1, ξ] == Tcore, 
           u[-lasert, r, ξ] == Tcore} /. conds, 
         u, 
         {t, -lasert /. conds, 0}, {r, 1/10^3, 1}, {ξ, 0, ξfunc@Last@zvalues}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> {25, 30}, 
    "MinPoints" -> {25, 30}, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}, 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}]; ]
(* {103.8961825, Null} *)

(* Temperature *)
Plot[sol[0, 0.5, ξfunc[z]], {z, 0, Last[zvalues]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* Heat flux *)
Plot[Derivative[0, 0, 1][sol][0, 0.5, ξfunc[z]], {z, 0, Last[zvalues]}, 
   PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice the option `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}` is necessary here, because `NDSolve` will automatically set `"ScaleFactor" -> 0` for non-Dirichlet boundary condition, when i.c. and b.c. are inconsistent, this will make the non-Dirichlet inconsistent b.c. be severely ignored, for more information you may want to read this obscure [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#1306392612) and [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871).

Feel free to ask in the comment if you have difficulty in understanding the answer.

---

## Update: `"FiniteElement"`-based  Solution

> The last written set of boundary conditions indicates the continuity of the heat flux, ……, They are the ones I don't know how to impose in `NDSolveValue`.

After several discussions ([1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126210/1871), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131542/1871)) in this site during past 2 years, it has been clear that `"FiniteElement"` method introduced since *v10* is able to take care of heat flux continuity automatically, **as long as the form of the equation is proper**. (Check links above for more information. )
And your trial turns out to be almost successful, except that:

1. When dealing with a region with internal boundaries, it's necessary to specify them when generating the mesh, or the quality of the solution will be bad. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/178849/1871)'s a simpler example illustrating this issue.
2. Your translation for the Robin type b.c. is incorrect, the correct one should be

   ```
   NeumannValue[(u - Tenv) ha, z == 0]
   ```

   As to the reason, please check **Details** section of document of `NeumannValue`.
3. The `Tanh` term aiming at smoothing the discontinuity seems to be troublesome.

OK, let's fix these issues.

> **Note**: Definitions for `zvalues`, `kcondz`, etc. are the same as those in **Pre-*v10* Soluion** section and omitted in this section.

We first generate a mesh with internal boundaries:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
r0 = 0; rend = 1;
line = Flatten[{{{r0, #}, {rend, #}} & /@ 
     Flatten@{0, zvalues}, {{#, 0}, {#, zvalues[[-1]]}} & /@ {r0, rend}}, 1];
coord = Flatten[line, 1] // Union;
indexrule = MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, coord];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coord, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> (LineElement[{#}] & /@ (line /. indexrule))];
Show[bmesh[Wireframe], AspectRatio -> 1]
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
(* Show[mesh[Wireframe], AspectRatio -> 1] *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then introduce the Robin b.c. in the correct way, I've also made some simplification in coding:

```
With[{u = u[t, r, z]}, 
 eqn = kcondz[z] (D[u, z, z] + (1/r) D[r D[u, r], r]) - ρxc[z] D[u, t] + 
   Qlaser[t, r, z];
 robinbc = NeumannValue[(u - Tenv) ha, z == 0];
 bc = DirichletCondition[u == Tcore, r == 1 || z == zvalues[[-1]]];
 ic = u == Tcore /. t -> -lasert;]
```

Finally, solve the equation and plot. We can see the result is the same as the previous, but `NDSolveValue` only takes about 45 seconds to finish:

```
tend = 1500;
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn == robinbc, bc, ic} /. conds, {u, 
     Derivative[0, 0, 1][u]}, {t, -lasert, tend} /. conds, {r, z} ∈
     mesh]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {45.6404, Null} *)
Plot[sol[[1]][0, 0.5, z], {z, 0, zvalues[[-1]]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[kcondz[z] Evaluate[sol[[2]][0, 0.5, z]], {z, 0, zvalues[[-1]]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Method -> "FiniteElement"` isn't set in `NDSolveValue`, because it'll be automatically chosen when `NeumannValue` is used to build the equation.

Comment: What does the new variable `\[Xi]` represent physically? Why would it cause the heat flux to be continous?

Comment: In the `neweqn` with the change of variable I don't see the term corresponding to `D[kcondz[z], z]*D[u[t, r, z], z]` that was present in the original equation.

Comment: @JackLaVigne The term `D[kcondz[z], z]*D[u[t, r, z], z]` is actually zero in this case so I simply omit it. (I believe OP has derived the equation in a somewhat blind way :) ).

Comment: @JackLaVigne As to the $\xi$ part, I've added some explanation to the beginning of my answer, have a look.

Comment: Actually I have included the term $\frac{d k}{dz} \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$ because of the k dependence with z (remember it had a Tanh to smooth it).

Comment: By the way, thank you very much for your outstanding answer!

Comment: @J.Edwards Ah, I forgot the `Tanh`! Then it's indeed necessary for your original approach.

Comment: @J.Edwards Recently I revisit the tutorial for `"MethodOfLines"` and noticed an additional option adjustment is needed for obtaining a reasonable result. See my edit.