# Transient temperature profile in cylinder

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I am trying to simulate the temperature profile inside a very long cylinder that is suddenly immersed into a cooling fluid:

For this, I am writing a single heat equation where the physical properties are varying in space. As BC, I am assuming that I know the initial temperature profile and that I know the temperature of the cooling medium far away from the cylinder. Assuming that the radius of the cylinder is 3:

```
d[x_] := (1 + 4 UnitStep[x-3])
f0[x_] := (120 - 140 UnitStep[x - 3])

heateq = D[u[x, t], x, x] + 1/x*D[u[x, t], x] == 
   1/d[x]* D[u[x, t], t];

sol = First[NDSolve[{
     heateq,
     u[x, 0] == f0[x],
     u[10, t] == -20,
     (D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> 0) == 0
     },
    u[x, t], {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10.}]];

frames = Table[
   Plot[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. sol], {x, 0, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 10}], {t, .001, 10, .2}];

ListAnimate[Show[#, Graphics[Line[{{5, 0}, {5, 300}}]]] & /@ frames]
```

However, this does not work and gives me errors such as "Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>".

Comment: How to solve it?

Comment: after realizing that it is sufficient not to calculate the solution at x=0, another problem becomes clear: NDSolve produces solutions that give a heat flux discontinuos over the bounday cylinder-cooling medium.
Thermal conductivities are:

k=0.58 W/(mK) for the cooling medium 
0.21 W/(mK) for the cylinder. 

I am looking for heat flux continuity over the boundary. How to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that works :

```
xmin = 0.1;
myMaxPoints = 500;
d[x_] := (1 + 4 UnitStep[x - 3])
f0[x_] := (120 - 140 UnitStep[x - 3])

heateq = D[u[x, t], x, x] + 1/x*D[u[x, t], x] == 1/d[x]*D[u[x, t], t];

sol = First[NDSolve[
    {heateq, u[x, 0] == f0[x], 
     u[10, t] == -20, (D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> xmin) == 0},
    u[x, t],
    {x, xmin, 10}, {t, 0, 10.},
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MaxPoints" -> myMaxPoints}}]];

frames = Table[
   Plot[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. sol], {x, xmin, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-20, 120}}], {t, .001, 10, .2}];

ListAnimate[Show[#, Graphics[Line[{{5, 0}, {5, 300}}]]] & /@ frames]
```

[image]

## Trial and error path to find the above solution :

1. The initial code gives the error message :

[image]

This is inherent to the fact that you use polar coordinates. A solution is to make run x from 0.1 to 10. With the Neumann boundary condition : flux = 0, this is equivalent to make a small hole of diameter 0.1 in the middle of the cylinder. Physically it is totally realistic :

```
xmin = 0.1;
d[x_] := (1 + 4 UnitStep[x - 3])
f0[x_] := (120 - 140 UnitStep[x - 3])

heateq = D[u[x, t], x, x] + 1/x*D[u[x, t], x] == 1/d[x]*D[u[x, t], t];

sol = First[NDSolve[
    {heateq, u[x, 0] == f0[x], 
     u[10, t] == -20, (D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> xmin) == 0},
    u[x, t],
    {x, xmin, 10}, {t, 0, 10.}]];
```

2. Then we have the message :

[image]

This is more complicated to interpret. One has to know that :

- `MaxPoints` concerns the spatial grid
- The spatial grid is determined by the initial condition, here `f0[]`
- `MinStepSize` is no more than "spatial length of the simulation"/`MaxPoints`. It exists just for convenience
- 10000 points is clearly too much. The responsible is `f0` which contains the too much stiff `UnitStep` function : the spatial discretization process try to much to approximate it.

There are 2 solutions :

- replace `f0[x]` with something less stiff, for example `50 - 140/Pi ArcTan[100. (x - 3)]`
- or use a smaller value than default for `MaxPoints`. It is what we are going to do. There is a stupid difficulty : one must know that the syntax is `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid","MaxPoints" -> myMaxPoints}}`. That is to say one has to know that `MaxPoints` belongs to the options of "MethodOfLines"/"TensorProductGrid" (not "FiniteElement"). And fortunately, thanks to the message that talks about `MaxPoints` we know that `NDSolve` has automatically selected the method "MethodOfLines"/"TensorProductGrid".

We can try "MaxPoints"-> 300 (more or less randomly) :

```
xmin = 0.1;
myMaxPoints = 300;
d[x_] := (1 + 4 UnitStep[x - 3])
f0[x_] := (120 - 140 UnitStep[x - 3])

heateq = D[u[x, t], x, x] + 1/x*D[u[x, t], x] == 1/d[x]*D[u[x, t], t];

sol = First[NDSolve[
    {heateq, u[x, 0] == f0[x], 
     u[10, t] == -20, (D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> xmin) == 0},
    u[x, t],
    {x, xmin, 10}, {t, 0, 10.},
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MaxPoints" -> myMaxPoints}}]];
```

then :

[image]

300 was to small. Then maybe "MaxPoints"-> 500 :

```
xmin = 0.1;
myMaxPoints = 500;
d[x_] := (1 + 4 UnitStep[x - 3])
f0[x_] := (120 - 140 UnitStep[x - 3])

heateq = D[u[x, t], x, x] + 1/x*D[u[x, t], x] == 1/d[x]*D[u[x, t], t];
sol = First[NDSolve[
    {heateq, u[x, 0] == f0[x], 
     u[10, t] == -20, (D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> xmin) == 0},
    u[x, t],
    {x, xmin, 10}, {t, 0, 10.},
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MaxPoints" -> myMaxPoints}}]];
```

That OK, no more warning.

Then, only at end, we can try make the animation :

```
frames = Table[
   Plot[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. sol], {x, xmin, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-20, 120}}], {t, .001, 10, .2}];
ListAnimate[Show[#, Graphics[Line[{{5, 0}, {5, 300}}]]] & /@ frames]
```

Note : The step in the diffusivity coefficient `d[x]` is not very visible. It seems to be normal, though I have not investigated a lot.

Comment: "The step in the diffusivity coefficient `d[x]` is not very visible."  Actually `d[x]` won't cause any visible step in the solution, because in this case `NDSolve` automatically finds a solution that is 1st order continuous in x-direction. (For more information you may want to read this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121739/1871). OP doesn't mention if (s)he wants a solution that is heat flux continuous, but if (s)he really wants one, (s)he should show us the thermal conductivities of cooling medium and cylinder. (`d[x]` is just thermal diffusivity.)

Comment: thermal conductivities are k=0.58 W/(m*K) for the cooling medium and 0.21 W/(m*K) for the cylinder. I am looking for heat flux continuity over the boundary.

Comment: and my code will give me a heat flux that is discontinuos over the bounday cylinder-cooling medium k[x_] := (0.21 + (0.58 - 0.21))* UnitStep[x - 3]

Plot[k[x]*D[u[x, t], t] /. t -> 0.5 /. sol, {x, 0.1, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, All}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"distance", "heat flux"}]   so the question becomes: how to write a boundary condition that leads to a solution with continuous heat flux?

Comment: @Luigi You should add this to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Just avoid evaluating when x=0

```
sol = NDSolve[{
   (D[u[t, x], x, x] + (1/x) D[u[t, x], x]) - (1/d[x]) D[u[t, x],t] ==
    NeumannValue[0, x == 0.001],
   u[0, x] == f0[x],
   u[t, 10] == -20}, u, {t, 0, 30}, {x, 0.001, 10}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
  "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 0.01}}}}]

frames = Table[
   Plot[Evaluate[u[t, x] /. sol], {x, 0, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-20, 120}}], {t, 0, 30, 1}];

ListAnimate[Show[#, Graphics[Line[{{3, 0}, {3, 300}}]]] & /@ frames]
```

[image]

Comment: The parentheses aren't necessary. `(1/x) D[u[t, x], x] == 1/x D[u[t, x], x]` returns `True` :)