# heat balance solution in two adjacent layers with continuous flux over boundary

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I am trying to solve the heat equation for a system made of a cylinder (hot) that is suddenly immersed in a cooling medium (cold). I am doing this using a 1D approximation with single differential equation (in cylindrical coordinates) and physical properties that vary in space. The code is:

```
diamcyl = 0.800;
T1 = 140;
T2 = -20;

k2 = 0.58;    (* W/mK *)
rho2 = 1000;   (* kg/m3 *)
Cp2 = 4200;  (* J/KgK *)

k1 = 0.128; (*W/(mK)*)
rho1 = 800; (* kg/m3 *)
Cp1 = 1670; (*J/(KgK)*)

(*properties as a function of space*)
rho[x_] := (rho1 + (rho2 - rho1)* UnitStep[x - diamcyl/2]);
k[x_] := 10^6*(k1 + (k2 - k1)* UnitStep[x - diamcyl/2]);    
Cp[x_] := (Cp1 + (Cp2 - Cp1)* UnitStep[x - diamcyl/2]);

heateq = 1/x*D[x*k[x]*D[u[x, t], x], x] == rho[x]*Cp[x]*D[u[x, t], t];

u0[x_] := (T1 + (T2 - T1)*UnitStep[x - diamcyl/2]);
solm20 = First[
   NDSolve[{heateq, u[x, 0] == u0[x], 
     u[10, t] == T2, (D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> 0.001) == 0}, 
    u, {x, 0.001, 2}, {t, 0, 5},
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MaxPoints" -> 1000}}]];
```

The solution transient temperature profile that I obtain looks smooth and is continuous over the boundary of the cylinder. However, the heat flux exhibits a discontinuity over this boundary.

```
Show[Table[
  Plot[u[x, t] /. solm20, {x, 0.001, 2}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {T2, T1}}, PlotRangePadding -> {None, 10}, 
   Prolog -> {LightGray, Rectangle[{0, -100}, {diamcyl/2, 200}]}, 
   GridLines -> {{diamcyl/2}, {T2}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"distance [mm]", "temperature [\[Degree]C]"}], {t, 
   0, 2, 0.05}],

 Plot[u0[x], {x, 0.01, 2}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]]

Show[Table[
  Plot[Evaluate[k[x]*D[u[x, t], x] /. solm20], {x, 0.01, 2}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}, PlotRangePadding -> {None, 10}, 
   GridLines -> {{diamcyl/2}, {T2}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"distance [mm]", "temperature [\[Degree]C]"}], {t, 
   0.01, 2, 0.05}]]
```

How to obtain a solution with continuous heat flux? Or, I could also ask it in this way: how to impose a Neumann condition over the boundary of the cylinder?

Comment: You have `u[10, t] == T2` but at the same time `{x, 0.001, 2}` do you mean `u[2, t] == T2`?

Comment: Luigi, you've already asked 5 questions in this site (and 1 question in meta about how to format your code), please learn to format your code properly. If you have difficulty in understanding the answers you got [in meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1977/1871), just continue to ask in the comment.

Comment: sorry for the improper formatting.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a way to do it:

```
T1 = 140;
T2 = -20;
k1 = 10^6*0.128*x;
rho1 = 800;
Cp1 = 1670;
k2 = 10^6*0.58*x;
rho2 = 1000;
Cp2 = 4200;
tend = 1/2;
lend = 2;
lm = 0.4;

v1 = rho1*Cp1;
v2 = rho2*Cp2;

opts = Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}};

u0[x_] := Evaluate[With[{p = lm, T1 = T1, T2 = T2}, If[x < p, T1, T2]]]
(*Plot[u0[x],{x,0,lend}]*)


C1[x_] := Evaluate[With[{p = lm, k1 = k1, k2 = k2}, If[x < p, k1, k2]]]
M1[x_] := Evaluate[With[{p = lm, v1 = v1, v2 = v2}, If[x < p, v1, v2]]]

(* this depends a bit what you want *)
(*heateq1=M1[x]*D[u[x,t],t]\[Equal]1/x*Inactive[Div][{{C1[x]}}.\
Inactive[Grad][u[x,t],{x}],{x}]*)

heateq1 = 
  M1[x]*D[u[x, t], t] == 1/x*Div[{{C1[x]}}.Grad[u[x, t], {x}], {x}];

sol1 = NDSolveValue[{heateq1, u[x, 0] == u0[x]}, 
   u, {x, 0, lend}, {t, 0, tend}, opts];
Plot[sol1[x, tend], {x, 0, lend}]
```

[image]

```
NIntegrate[sol1[x, tend], {x} \[Element] sol1["ElementMesh"]]
-17.231627750587393`

dsolm1 = C1[x]*D[sol1[x, t], x];
Plot[Evaluate[dsolm1 /. t -> tend], {x, 0, lend}]
```

[image]

Because there was some discussion in the comments I verified this result with another FEM tool and for the FEM I get the same results (up to some numerical acceptable difference) there. Note that the difference to the old answer is partially due to the use of the activated PDE - but that depends a bit on what you actually want to model.

**Old Answer**

I am not exactly sure what you are looking for, perhaps this:

```
heateq2 = 
  If[x < diamcyl/2, rho1*Cp1, rho2*Cp2]*D[u[x, t], t] == 
   1/x*Inactive[
      Div][{{If[x < diamcyl/2, 10^6*x*k1, 10^6*x*k2]}}.Inactive[Grad][
       u[x, t], {x}], {x}];
(*heateq2 = heateq2//Activate *)
solm20 = First[
   NDSolve[{heateq2, u[x, 0] == If[x < diamcyl/2, T1, T2](*,u[2,
     t]\[Equal]T2*)}, u, {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 5}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}]];
```

Note that I set no boundary condition on the right hand side - with the finite element method that implies a Neumann zero boundary condition.

```
Show[Table[
  Plot[u[x, t] /. solm20, {x, 0.001, 2}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {T2, T1}}, PlotRangePadding -> {None, 10}, 
   Prolog -> {LightGray, Rectangle[{0, -100}, {diamcyl/2, 200}]}, 
   GridLines -> {{diamcyl/2}, {T2}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"distance [mm]", "temperature [\[Degree]C]"}], {t, 
   0, 2, 0.05}], 
 Plot[u0[x], {x, 0.01, 2}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]]

Show[Table[
  Plot[Evaluate[k[x]*D[u[x, t], x] /. solm20], {x, 0.01, 2}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}, PlotRangePadding -> {None, 10}, 
   GridLines -> {{diamcyl/2}, {T2}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"distance [mm]", "temperature [\[Degree]C]"}], {t, 
   0.01, 2, 0.05}]]
```

[image]

[image]

I also changed the left and side region to go from 0 and not 0.001 (this will need V11, else you can change it back to 0.001)

One thing to think about is if you want the equations to be activated, and I think you do. I tried to verify this with another FEM tool and it gives essentially the same results.

Comment: Interesting, but `NDSolve` will output a solution that is 1st order continuous in x-direction by default (see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121739/1871) for more information), why it finds a heat flux continuity solution in this case? What's the key point here?

Comment: `@user21`: when I run your code in Mathematica 10.0 I get the following error:
`NDSolve::femcnmd: The PDE coefficient {{-(If[x<0.4,10^6 x k1,10^6 x k2]/x)}} does not evaluate to a numeric matrix of dimensions {1,1}. >>`

Comment: `@user21`: have you left out the symmetry condition `(D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> 0.001) == 0` (cylinder axis) on purpose?

Comment: @xzczd, I am not exactly sure what you are referring to but I think what you mean is due to the FEM.

Comment: @Luigi, your first point - that's why I put the V11 stuff in the answer. The second point: in FEM if you do not specify anything that naturally means Neumann zero. See the reference for [NeumannValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html)

Comment: After some trial on Wolfram Cloud, I think I found the key point. If we make a mathematically trivial modification on `heateq2` i.e. modify the equation to `heateq2 = 
  (*If[x < diamcyl/2, rho1*Cp1, rho2*Cp2]**)D[u[x, t], t] == 
   1/x*Inactive[
      Div][{{If[x < diamcyl/2, 10^6*x*k1/(rho1*Cp1), 10^6*x*k2/(rho2*Cp2)]}}.Inactive[Grad][
       u[x, t], {x}], {x}];`, the heat flux will be discontinuous again :)

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: ok. but then I am confused. why does the position of the physical constants (rho and Cp) affects the solution of the equation?

Comment: @xzczd witht his modification you need to be a bit careful in the case of a NeumannValue BC as putting the coefficients in the Div Grad term will change what the NeumannValue means. I'll have a look and will see if I can get the mass matrix to work better in this case, but it might take a while until I get there.

Comment: @Luigi, as far as I understand now, it should only make a difference with respect to the meaning of NeumannValue. I'll investigate but it will take some time until I'll get to it.

Comment: `@user21`, thanks for the explanation and I look forward to learn this from you.

Comment: @xzczd The heat equation in a inhomogeneous medium is : rho[x] c[x] D[T[x,t],t] == Div (k[x] Grad T[x,t]). It is not equivalent to D[T[x,t],t] == Div (k[x]/(rho[x] c[x]) Grad T[x,t]) except if (rho[x] c[x]) is independant from x, which is not the case *at the medium transition*. So I think the "trivial" modification of xzczd is not valid.

Comment: @andre Yeah, when the definition of `rho[x]` and `c[x]` becomes more complicated, this trivial modification is incorrect of course, but in this case `rho[x] c[x]` is constant (it's just 2 constants linked by a `UnitStep`), so the modification is valid.

Comment: @xzczd I stay on my position, though I can't find definitely clean arguments. ... later ...  maybe ... Don't forget the precision *at the medium transition* : the key is here.

Comment: @xzczd By the way, Thank you very very much for your comment [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125672/5467). No conservation of the flux is a very bad thing. I have the intention to complete my answer - the problem is that this question (and the other related question) are polluted by others unrelated problems.

Comment: @andre You're welcome :) . It's a pity that the "heat flux continuity" issue hasn't come out in a cleaner way in this site for so long…

Comment: @andre Just tested on Cloud, even if the equation is modified to `heateq2 = D[u[x, t], t] == (1/If[x < diamcyl/2, rho1*Cp1, rho2*Cp2])*(1/x)*Inactive[Div][{{If[x < diamcyl/2, 10^6*x*k1, 10^6*x*k2]}} . Inactive[Grad][u[x, t], {x}], {x}]`, the heat flux is still discontinuous :)

Comment: @xzczd could you clarify what you mean by that. What do you expect and why?

Comment: I mean, in [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126203/heat-balance-solution-in-two-adjacent-layers-with-continuous-flux-over-boundary/126210?noredirect=1#comment353552_126210) @andre suspected that my modification for `heateq2` in [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126203/heat-balance-solution-in-two-adjacent-layers-with-continuous-flux-over-boundary/126210?noredirect=1#comment342035_126210) is incorrect because I put the $c\rho$ term inside `Div`, so this time I modified the equation in a even more trivial way, and the result is the same.

Comment: @andre I started a new question for the issue mentioned above: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131542/1871