# Position of discontinuous coefficient influences the solution of PDE

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, discontinuity

This issue is raised in the discussion under [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126210/1871) about heat flux continuity and I think it's better to start a new question to state it in a clearer way. Just consider the following example:

```
Lmid = 1; L = 2; tend = 1;
m[x_] = If[x < Lmid, 1, 2];
eq1 = m[x] D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x];
eq2 = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x]/m[x];
```

Clearly, `eq1` and `eq2` is mathematically the same, the only difference between them is the position of the discontinuous coefficient `m[x]`. Nevertheless, the solution of `NDSolve` will be influenced by this trivial difference, if `"FiniteElement"` is chosen as the method for `"SpatialDiscretization"`:

```
opts = Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}};

ndsolve[eq_] := NDSolveValue[{eq, u[x, 0] == Exp[x]}, u, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tend}, opts];

{sol1, sol2} = ndsolve /@ {eq1, eq2};
Plot[{sol1[x, tend], sol2[x, tend]}, {x, 0, L}]
```

[image]

Apparently `sol2` is a weak solution that's just 0th order continuous in `x` direction.

Further check shows that, `sol1` is 1st order continuous in `x` direction, while `D[sol2[x, tend]/m[x], x]` is continous:

```
Plot[D[{sol1[x, tend], sol2[x, tend]/m[x]}, x] // Evaluate, {x, 0, L}]
```

[image]

To make this post a question, I'd like to ask:

1. Is this behavior of `NDSolve` intended, or kind of a mistake?
2. Is this behavior controlable? I mean, can we predict what's continuous in the solution, just from the form of the equation?

Comment: @andre Well, maybe they don't like pictures, I tried to improve the format. I didn't make further changes because I'm not sure if I can make it more attractive. (As we can see this question of mine doesn't generate much enthusiasm, too…)

Comment: I am just realising that the initial condition `x[x,0]=Exp[x]` is not compatible with flux continuity. Same probleme [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1631534/369701) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2027396/369701) !!

Comment: @andre I think it's not a big deal. We can simply consider the inconsistency as an approximation, or a weak solution problem ([here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127334/1871) is another example). Also, this inconsistency isn't hard to remove.

Comment: @xzczd, thanks for the bounty!

Comment: @user21 You deserve it :) .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an explanation of what happens. Let's setup the problem once more.

```
Lmid = 1; L = 2; tend = 1;
m[x_] = If[x < Lmid, 1, 2];
(*m[x_]=2;*)
eq1 = m[x] D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x];
eq2 = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x]/m[x];
opts = Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}};
ndsolve[eq_] := 
  NDSolveValue[{eq, u[x, 0] == Exp[x]}, u, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tend}, 
   opts];
```

Equation 1 and 2 are mathematically the same, however, when we evaluate them we get different results as shown here:

```
sol1 = ndsolve[eq1];
Plot[sol1[x, tend], {x, 0, L}]
```

[image]

```
sol2 = ndsolve[eq2];
Plot[sol2[x, tend], {x, 0, L}]
```

[image]

What happens? Let's look at how the PDE gets parsed.

```
ClearAll[getEquations]
getEquations[eq_] := Block[{temp},
  temp = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{eq, u[x, 0] == Exp[x]}, 
     u, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tend}, opts][[1]];
  temp = temp["FiniteElementData"];
  temp = temp["PDECoefficientData"];
  (# -> temp[#]) & /@ {"DampingCoefficients", "DiffusionCoefficients",
     "ConvectionCoefficients"}
  ]

getEquations[eq1]
{"DampingCoefficients" -> {{If[x < 1, 1, 2]}}, 
 "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{{{-1}}}}, 
 "ConvectionCoefficients" -> {{{{0}}}}}
```

This looks good. If you want a more 'visual' output of the above you can use `GetInactivePDE` to look at what the parser made of the input:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
GetInactivePDE[
 NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{eq1, u[x, 0] == Exp[x]}, 
   u, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tend}, opts][[1]]]
```

[image]

Again, nothing unusual here, but now let's look at the second equation.

```
getEquations[eq2]
{"DampingCoefficients" -> {{1}}, 
 "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{{{-(1/If[x < 1, 1, 2])}}}}, 
 "ConvectionCoefficients" -> {{{{-(If[x < 1, 0, 0]/
       If[x < 1, 1, 2]^2)}}}}}
```

And:

```
GetInactivePDE[
 NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{eq2, u[x, 0] == Exp[x]}, 
   u, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tend}, opts][[1]]]
```

[image]

For the second eqn. we get a convection coefficient term. Why is that? The key is to understand that the FEM can only solve this type equation:

$d\frac{\partial }{\partial t}u+\nabla \cdot (-c \nabla u-\alpha  u+\gamma ) +\beta \cdot \nabla u+ a u -f=0$

Note, that there is no coefficient in front of the $\nabla \cdot (-c \nabla u-\alpha  u+\gamma)$ term. To get things like $h(x) \nabla \cdot (-c \nabla u-\alpha  u+\gamma)$ to work, $c$ is set to $h$ and $\beta$ is adjusted to get rid of the derivative caused by $\nabla \cdot (-c \nabla u)$

Here is an example:

```
c = h[x];
β = -Div[{{h[x]}}, {x}];
Div[{{c}}.Grad[u[x], {x}], {x}] + β.Grad[u[x], {x}]
(* h[x]*Derivative[2][u][x] *)
```

In the case at hand that leads to:

```
Div[{{1/m[x]}}.Grad[u[x], {x}], {x}] - 
  Div[{{1/m[x]}}, {x}] // Simplify

(* {Piecewise[{{Derivative[2][u][x]/2, x >= 1}}, Derivative[2][u][x]]} *)
```

But that is the same as specifying:

```
 eq3 = D[u[x, t], t] == 
   Inactive[
     Div][{{1/If[x < 1, 1, 2]}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x, t], {x}], {x}];

sol3 = ndsolve[eq3];
(* Plot[sol2[x, tend] - sol3[x, tend], {x, 0, L}] *)
```

I have checked that flexPDE (another FEM tool) gives exactly the same solutions in all three cases. So this issue is not uncommon. In principal a message could be generated but how would one detect when to trigger that message? If you have suggestions about this, let me know in the comments. I think it were also good to add this example to the documentation - if there are no objections. I hope this clarifies the unexpected behavior a bit.

You can also find this information in the documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#588198981).

Comment: So the answer for my first question is "this behavior is intended"? "In principal a message could be generated but how would one detect when to trigger that message?" Maybe by detecting if the coefficient is continuous or not, or by detecting if the coefficient involves `Piecewise` etc.?

Comment: It's not exactly intended, but as I tried to explained it is a consequence of how the FEM works right now. Concerning the coefficient detection, what should happen in the case of `f[x_?Numeric]` or an interpolating function that has a discontinuity. Your "etc" is not as trivial as it may seem. I'll think a bit more about this and may I can come up with something. In the meanwhile I added this example to the documentation, pending approval, which I think it will get.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a answer, only a comment.
It is related to the continuity problem (see end of this comment).

The equations given by xzczd are the heat equation along a rod that has a thermal (volumic) capacity that double at point x=1. There are no boundaries conditions, so `NDSolve[..., "FiniteElement"...]` will take the Neuman boundaries conditions =0 (this is equivalent to thermal flux = 0, ie adiabatic boundaries). In this case the total heat quantity in the rod should stay constant over time. This quantity is very easy to calculate :

at t=0 :

```
NIntegrate[sol1[x, 0], {x, 0, 1}] + 
 2 NIntegrate[sol1[x, 0], {x, 1, 2}]
```

11.0598

at t=tend:

sol1 :

```
NIntegrate[sol1[x, 1], {x, 0, 1}] +   
2 NIntegrate[sol1[x, 1], {x, 1, 2}]
```

> 11.0598

**OK**

sol2 :

```
NIntegrate[sol2[x, 1], {x, 0, 1}] +   
2 NIntegrate[sol2[x, 1], {x, 1, 2}]
```

> 8.64626

**KO**

This problem is related to the continuity problem because if the continuity of flux=(conductivity*D[u,x]) fails at x=1 (conductivity = 1 here), then the global heat quantity is not conserved.

Comment: "The equations given by xzczd are the heat equation along a rod that has a thermal (volumic) capacity that double at point $x=1$." Well, not necessarily. Actually `m[x]` represents $C/k$ where $C$ is thermal capacity and $k$ is thermal conductivity. So the equation in my question can also represent "a rod with a thermal conductivity that reduces by half at $x=1$", in this case the total heat quantity is `NIntegrate[NIntegrate[temperature[time, x], {x, 0, 2}]` and `sol2` is (almost) the solution that obeys energy conservation.

Comment: Disagree : I'm agree that  `m[x] D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x]` and `D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x]/m[x]` should be equivalent, but I still think that `Div k[x] Grad u[x,t]` is not equal to `k[x] Div Grad u[x,t]` even if k[x] is piecewise constant. That's the reason why I have assumed that conductivity=1 along the whole rod (may be you have not seen my last update above, where I have written conductivity=1 at the end of the text)

Comment: If you mean, the discontinuity in $k$ should be represented by `HeavisideTheta` rather than `UnitStep` so `Div[k[x] Grad[u[t, x], {x, y}], {x, y}]` actually involves `DiracDelta`, then, though I don't know how to prove it analytically, numeric experiments indeed show that `DiracDelta` has no contribution in the solution. Here's the code I used: ``appro = With[{coe = 1000}, ArcTan[coe #1]/π + 1/2 &]; unitStepExpand = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@# &;k[x_] = unitStepExpand[If[x < 1, 2, 1]] /. UnitStep -> appro;eq = D[u[t, x], t] == Div[k[x] Grad[u[t, x], {x, y}], {x, y}];``……

Comment: ……`eqrefer = D[u[t, x], t] == k[x] Div[Grad[u[t, x], {x, y}], {x, y}];points = 5000;{sol, solrefer} = 
  NDSolveValue[{#, u[0, x] == (1 - x) x, u[t, 0] == 0, u[t, 1] == 0}, 
     u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}, 
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> points, 
         "MinPoints" -> points, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}] & /@ {eq, eqrefer};
Plot[{sol[1/10, x], solrefer[1/10, x]}, {x, 0, 1}]` You can adjust `coe` and `points` and observe, it's reasonable to think that the `DiracDelta` doesn't play a role in the solution.

Comment: @xzczd In the code of your 2 latest comments, the discontinuity is at x=1 and the right boundary is also at x=1. Is it a mistake or intentional ?

Comment: Oops… seems that I've made a silly mistake in the experiment. `k[x]` need to be corrected to `unitStepExpand[If[x < 1/2, 2, 1]] /. UnitStep -> appro`. OK, now my numeric experiment supports your conclusion: mathematically the discontinuous $k$ can't be taken out of `Div` directly. But further experiment shows this doesn't change my conclusion that much: `k[x_] = If[x < 1/2, 2, 1];eqfem1 = D[u[t, x], t]/k[x] == Div[ Grad[u[t, x], {x, y}], {x, y}];eqfem2 = D[u[t, x], t] == k[x] Div[Grad[u[t, x], {x, y}], {x, y}];`……

Comment: ……`opts = Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}};{solfem1, solfem2} = NDSolveValue[{#, u[0, x] == (1 - x) x, u[t, 0] == 0, u[t, 1] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}, opts] & /@ {eqfem1, eqfem2};
Plot[{solfem1[1/10, x], solfem2[1/10, x]}, {x, 0, 1}]`. `solfem2` and `sol` seems to be the same i.e. when `"FiniteElement"` is used, `… = k[x] Div[Grad[u[t, x], {x, y}], {x, y}]` is equivalent to `… = Div[k[x] Grad[u[t, x], {x, y}], {x, y}]` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem mentioned by the OP arises even with a ODE :

Compare :

```
m[x_]=If[x<0.5,1,2];  

f=NDSolveValue[  
{m[x] y''[x]==0, y[0]==0, y[1]==1},
y,
{x,0,1},
Method->{"PDEDiscretization"->{"FiniteElement"}}
];  

Plot[f[x],{x,0,1}]
```

[image]

with :

```
m[x_]=If[x<0.5,1,2];  

f=NDSolveValue[  
{y''[x]==0/m[x], y[0]==0, y[1]==1},
y,
{x,0,1},
Method->{"PDEDiscretization"->{"FiniteElement"}}
]; 

Plot[f[x],{x,0,1}]
```

[image]

This time, we have the analytical solutions, which are trivial : y = a x + b, eventually in several segments.

Comment: I think this case is a bit different. `0/m[x]` will evaluate to `0` before being handled by `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem, it seems, has to do with temporal integration, when the "MethodOfLines" is used concurrently with the FEM. When the coefficients are moved to the temporal partial derivative part of the equation the MethodOfLines includes the coefficients in the time integration scheme and not in the FEM spatial discretization, yet this yields the correct solution. The particulars are hard to figure out unless the details of how the "MethodOfLines" together with FEM works in Mathematica are known. The following verifies this. Using Piecewise instead of If below yields the same results (v.12.2).

The problem: the two solutions below yield different results simply because of the position of the coefficients:

**sol 1**, with coefficients on the spatial derivatives part (this yields incorrect results):

```
u = NDSolveValue[{D[T[t, x], t] - If[x < 0.4, 0.00093, 0.05405]*D[T[t, x],
x, x] == 0, T[0, x] == 300, T[t, 0] == 300, T[t, 1] == 400}, T, {t, 0,
100}, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" ->
{"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}];
```

**sol 2**, with coefficients on the temporal derivative part (this yields correct results):

```
u = NDSolveValue[{D[T[t, x], t]/If[x < 0.4, 0.00093, 0.05405] - D[T[t, x], x, x] == 0, 
 T[0, x] == 300, T[t, 0] == 300, T[t, 1] == 400}, T, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 1}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}];
```

Solution like sol1 but without using the MethodOfLines (correct solution):

```
u = NDSolveValue[{D[T[t, x], t] - If[x < 0.4, 0.00093, 0.05405]*D[T[t, x], x, x] == 0, 
 T[0, x] == 300, T[t, 0] == 300, T[t, 1] == 400}, T, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 1}, 
Method -> {"ExplicitEuler", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}];
```

Solution with the MethodOfLines but without FEM (correct solution):

```
u = NDSolveValue[{D[T[t, x], t] - If[x < 0.4, 0.00093, 0.05405]*D[T[t, x], x, x] == 0, 
 T[0, x] == 300, T[t, 0] == 300, T[t, 1] == 400}, T, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 1}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];
```

Solution without MethodOfLines and without FEM (correct solution):

```
u = NDSolveValue[{D[T[t, x], t] - If[x < 0.4, 0.00093, 0.05405]*D[T[t, x], x, x] == 0, 
 T[0, x] == 300, T[t, 0] == 300, T[t, 1] == 400}, T, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 1}, 
Method -> {"ExplicitEuler", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];
```

Solution w/o MethodOfLines and without FEM with coefficients in the temporal derivative side (correct solution):

```
u = NDSolveValue[{D[T[t, x], t]/If[x < 0.4, 0.00093, 0.05405] - D[T[t, x], x, x] == 0, 
 T[0, x] == 300, T[t, 0] == 300, T[t, 1] == 400}, T, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 1}, 
Method -> {"ExplicitEuler", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];
```

All solutions can be plotted with:

```
Plot[u[2, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0., 1}, {300, 400}},
Frame -> True,GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thin,
Dashed],FrameLabel -> {"x", Row[{"T(", Style[t, Italic], ",",
"x)"}]},PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red},
ImageSize -> 1.1*{550, 350}]
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Also, this problem does not appear when there is no time integration, e.g., for the 1-D Navier equation (elasticity (not Navier-Stokes)) with coefficients in piecewise form.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't an answer to my question. Actually my problem has already been resolved by [the answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131766/1871) from user21 (he's the developer of `FiniteElement` method of `NDSolve`). If you have difficulty in understanding his answer, you may consider comment under his answer, or start a new question.

Comment: Also, one thing incorrect in your post: by setting `Method -> {"ExplicitEuler", ……` you're still using `MethodOfLines`, it's just setting the ODE solver to `ExplicitEuler` in this case. Actually `MethodOfLines` is the only available method for time dependent PDE in `NDSolve`. This can be verified by  `sys = {D[T[t, x], t] - If[x < 0.4, 0.00093, 0.05405]*D[T[t, x], x, x]==0,T[0, x]==300,T[t, 0] == 300, T[t, 1] == 400};s1 = NDSolve[sys, T, {t, 0, 100}, {x,0,1},Method ->"ExplicitEuler"];s2 = NDSolve[sys, T, {t, 0, 100},{x, 0, 1}, Method-> {"MethodOfLines", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}];s1 === s2`

Comment: A careful reading of and the validation provided in my previous comment shows that only when the MethodOfLines is used TOGETHER with FEM the solution is erroneous when the coefficients are in the spatial derivatives part of the equation. The above comment by xzczd (both s1 and s2) do not use FEM . . . . Problem remains open in my view. Also, I mostly understand the answer by user21 but that does not remove the limitation!!

Comment: See the word "concurrently" in my original comment above

Comment: 1. As to `s1` and `s2`, my point is, you've actually used `MethodOfLines` in all the samples, so the statement "…without MethodOfLines…" is incorrect. 2. If you manages to understand user21's answer, then you'll see it's all because the so-called _formal forms_ of FEM under the hood are different, and one can always check the formal form with ``NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE``. Also, this solution is not erroneous, it's just obtained under another assumption of continuity. Another related post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211314/1871

Comment: The point in my original comment relevant to this is that sol1 and the third solution (the one after sol2) give different results and the only difference between those two is in time integration, i.e., that the first one (sol1) uses MethodOfLines and the third one uses ExplicitEuler (both use FEM). It does not matter whether both MethodOfLines and ExplitiEuler use the method of lines for time integration or not. The simple FACT is that those two give different results and none of the  comments in this topic can explain that. Of course I have no access to how MethodOfLines and ExplicEuler work.

Comment: work in Mathematica I mean, of course.

Comment: Aha, this is funny, and I can explain this. It's all because, `"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}` has been **ignored** in 3rd solution. This can be verified by `u2 = NDSolveValue[sys, T, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> {"ExplicitEuler", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}]; u3 = NDSolveValue[sys, T, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> {"ExplicitEuler"}]; u2 == u3`. This is not surprising, because `SpatialDiscretization` is a sub-option of `MethodOfLines`, not that of `ExplicitEuler`.

Comment: Since `NDSolve` doesn't complain, I originally thought `NDSolve` is so smart that it properly passes the `SpatialDiscretization` option in `u2` to `MethodOfLines`, but it turns out that I'm wrong. (Sigh...) `NDSolve` should have done a better error-checking in this case.

Comment: The fact that the two solutions above (u2 and u3) give the same answer does not mean that the FEM is ignored in u2. The two solutions u2 and u3 are supposed to be the same anyway. All I recall is that the program may automatically choose the FEM method for u3 since the solution method is not specified, and that has to do with the accuracy of the solution and not with the time integration scheme. I cannot find anything about ExplicitEuler not associated with SpatialDescritization

Comment: 1. Actually the warning `ibcinc` is a signal that `TensorProductGrid` method has been chosen. 2. The default setting in this case is `TensorProductGrid`, of course. See this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140805/1871 3. If you still feel suspicious, try e.g. defining a `u4` with `"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0000001` and compare `u2==u4`, you'll see the solution is still the same.

Comment: I'll check that . . . and with that, the bottom line is . . . do not use FEM in NDSolve or NDSolveValue . . .and that is a problem for irregular boundaries in 2D and 3D problems. Unfortunately.

Comment: In the comment under your previous post, you mentioned that you're dealing with heat transfer, then it's a bit strange to me that you find the result of `TensorProductGrid` more desired, because the heat continuity condition is naturally guaranteed in `FiniteElement` method, but not in `TensorProductGrid`. (I already linked the following related posts: 1. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121739/1871 2. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211314/1871 ) Anyway, it's your choice.