Issue with a Piecewise Diffusion Problem
I'm working on a piecewise diffusion problem in Mathematica where the diffusion coefficient is 1 in the first region (x ≤ 1) and 2 in the second region (x > 1). The initial condition is also piecewise. Here is the code I used:
D1 = 1; D2 = 2; LL = 10; C0 = 1; T0 = 50; L0 = 1;
sol = NDSolve[{D[CC[x, t], t] == 
    Piecewise[{{D1, x <= L0}, {D2, x > L0}}]*D[CC[x, t], x, x], 
   Derivative[1, 0][CC][LL, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][CC][0, t] == 0, 
   CC[x, 0] == Piecewise[{{C0, x >= L0}}]}, 
  CC[x, t], {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 50}]

The code runs and produces a result. The following picture is the result of CC at x=0.

However, I am wondering that, for a sufficiently large time, the concentration should equal 9/10, but my code seems to be stabilizing around 0.818 instead.
Could anyone help me understand what might be going wrong?
Thank you!

See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211314/1871 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131542/1871 . In short, the default TensorProductGrid method and FiniteElement method handle the discontinuous coefficients in different manners. Which one is physically correct depends on the form of continuity condition. For diffusion equation, FEM is more convenient because it usually automatically satisfies the continuity condition, but do notice FEM can still give incorrect result if you don't put the discontinuous coefficient(s) at proper position.

Change your bc to NeumannValue to force a FiniteElement-solution:
D1 = 1; D2 = 2; LL = 10; C0 = 1; T0 = 50; L0 = 1;
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[CC[x, t], t] == 
Piecewise[{{D1, x <= L0}, {D2, x > L0}}]*D[CC[x, t], x, x] + 
NeumannValue[0, x == LL] - NeumannValue[0, x == 0], 
CC[x, 0] == Piecewise[{{C0, x >= L0}}]},CC , {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 50}]

Plot [sol[x, T0], {x, 0, 10} , PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotLabel -> "sol[x,T0]"]



Thanks for your advice！I tried to use the commercial finite element software Comsol, and I got nearly the same result, the concentration stabilized around 0.904. I'm still wondering why the original code was wrong, but the FEM solution could work?

@Mikoto Your original code gives a warning "Using maximum number of grid points 10000 ...".Perhaps you need here additional option "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"  for NDSolveValue, difference method

Thanks for your advice!

You're welcome!
