# What does this error code mean?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I am using NDSolve to solve a PDE and I am getting the following error:

> "Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 20.099925422569758` \
>   at t = 95."

What does this mean exctly? Will the results the simulation produces be incorrect?

Comment: You need to present your complete code which is generating this error.

Comment: this is one of the problems I encountered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125672/5467)

Comment: On [this tutorial page](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Built-inFunctions/NumericalComputation/EquationSolving/AdvancedDocumentation/PDE.html), there is a section on understanding what that error is telling you. Scroll down to the "Spatial Error Estimates" section.

Comment: @march Your link goes to the legacy Mathematica 5 documentation. Is that intended ?

Comment: @andre. No, I just did a quick search and didn't notice the old style graphs, for some reason. I imagine there must be an updated version out there somewhere, but I'm also willing to bet that the information there is still relevant. (I haven't actually read that page, so...)