# The rectangular region composed of two triangular regions contains a pde connecting the bc of the first and the second kind

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, discontinuity

[image]

[image]

I'm going to solve the Laplacian equation of the electrostatic field, which consists of two triangular regions, a rectangular region, a square, and on the intersection of the two regions of $$y=x$$, there are the first and second boundary conditions. 
How to set the correct Boundary condition and solve the problem

tried

```
Ω1 = DiscretizeRegion@Triangle[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}];
(*RegionPlot[Ω1]*)
Ω2 = DiscretizeRegion@Triangle[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}];
(*RegionPlot[Ω2]*)

nv1 = NeumannValue[0, x == 0];
nv2 = NeumannValue[0, x == 1];
nv3 = NeumannValue[0, x == y];
nv4 = NeumannValue[0, x == y];

sol1 = NDSolveValue[{D[u1[x, y], x, x] + D[u1[x, y], y, y] == 
    nv1 + nv3, 
   DirichletCondition[u1[x, y] == 10, y == 1 && 0 <= x <= 1]}, 
  u1, {x, y} ∈ Ω1]
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{D[u2[x, y], x, x] + D[u2[x, y], y, y] == 
    nv2 + nv4, 
   DirichletCondition[u2[x, y] == 0, y == 0 && 0 <= x <= 1]}, 
  u2, {x, y} ∈ Ω2]

DensityPlot[sol1[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω1, 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
DensityPlot[sol2[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω2, 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

but the right answer should be this 
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your translation for the 8th equation i.e. continuity condition is wrong. This issue has been discussed in detail [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131766/1871) so I'd like to omit corresonding explanation and simply give the solution. Values of $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ aren't given in the question so I've picked them casually.

```
gamma1 = 1; gamma2 = 2;
gamma = Piecewise[{{gamma1, y > x}}, gamma2];

With[{phi = phi[x, y]},
  eq = gamma Laplacian[phi, {x, y}] == 0;
  (* Alternatively: *)
  (* eq= Inactive[Div][{{gamma, 0}, {0, gamma}}.Inactive[Grad][phi,{x,y}],{x,y}] == 0; *)
  bc = {phi == 10 /. y -> 1, phi == 0 /. y -> 0};]


sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, bc}, phi, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];

ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]~Show~Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The quality of solution above isn't that good actually, because `NDSolve` won't take the internal boundary at $y=x$ into consideration when discretizing the region automatically. To improve the quality, we can:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}}], 
     LineElement[{{3, 1}}]}];
bmesh[Wireframe]
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
mesh[Wireframe]
solbetter = NDSolveValue[{eq, bc}, phi, {x, y} ∈ mesh];

Plot[{sol[x, 1/2], solbetter[x, 1/2]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: great answer and thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Very neat. As often, the problem lies in the fact that people want (i) to stick to strong formulation and (ii) to write the diffusion constants in front.

Comment: hi,long time no see,can you explain some code "bmesh[Wireframe] mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh]; mesh[Wireframe]"

Comment: @dcydhb Please check the document of `ToElementMesh` and the tutorial `FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation`, especially the part starting from "A boundary element mesh may have internal structure; for example, to represent two material regions".

Comment: @xzczd ok,thanks a lot!

Comment: and there is another question where you have used the boundary condition 8 in your solbetter

Comment: @dcydhb It's automatically satisfied, just as in `sol`, because we're using the same `eq`.

Comment: @xzczd but have you ever define the bc 8 in sol?

Comment: @dcydhb As mentioned in my last comment, the 8th b.c. is satisfied automatically as long as `eq` is defined in the way above, this is a feature of `"FiniteElement"` method. Please check the link at the beginning of my answer for details.

Comment: @xzczd but i have not found the 8th bc in your defined eq,so do you mean the 8th was in the fem method?

Comment: @dcydhb To some degree, yes. Once again, the 8th b.c. is **automatically satisfied** when 1. `"FiniteElement"` method is chosen, 2. the discontinuous coefficient is in proper position. Please check the linked post for details.