# Wrong solution from multi materials FEM NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I'm quite new in Mathematica.
I have a problem with obtaining the right solution for multi-layer 1D heat transfer problem.
It seems that boundary condition not working.
Could you advise something?

I would be obliged.
Thank you in advance.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

g = {0.25, 0.114, 0.04}; (*thickness *)
gw = Accumulate[g]
λ = {8, 1.8, 44};
ρ = {3100, 2100, 7800};
cp = {1050, 1100, 540};
dc = λ/(ρ*cp);
a = Piecewise[{{dc[[1]], x < gw[[1]]}, {dc[[2]], 
     gw[[1]] <= x < gw[[2]]}, {dc[[3]], x >= gw[[2]]}}, {x, 0, 
    gw[[3]]}];

σ = First[UnitConvert[Quantity["StefanBoltzmannConstant"]]];
Trob = 1700;
Tamb = 297;
h = 10;
ε = 0.85;

bc1 = DirichletCondition[T[t, x] == Trob, x == 0.];
bc2conv = NeumannValue[h*(Tamb - T[t, x]), x == gw[[3]]];
bc2rad = NeumannValue[ε*σ*(Tamb^4 - T[t, x]^4), 
   x == gw[[3]]];
ic1 = T[0, x] == Tamb;

pde = D[T[t, x], t] - a*D[T[t, x], x, x];

sol = NDSolveValue[{pde == bc2conv + bc2rad, bc1, ic1}, 
   T, {t, 0, 36000}, {x, 0., gw[[3]]}, MaxStepSize -> 50];
```

likzew

---

For the biggining thank you all for answer.

The 1D FEM model seems to me not very complicated, but I understand that neeed some clarificatrion.
This is almost real situation. We have a three layers wall. Two part of them is ceramic materials  (0.25m and 0.114m) , and last one is steel sheel (0.04 m).
Using the Mathematica I trie to find solution which is sheel outside temperature after certain time.
For t=0 s, temperature of whole wall is 297 degC.
Boundary condition for x =0 is temperaturę Trob, boundary condition for x=0.404  contains convective and radiation therm.
Simple and easy.

As wrote that is a almost real becouse I use some simplification for x=0 boundary condition. For that I should use heat floux rather than temperature bc. In real we have often more layers. I have also omit thermal conductivity temperaturę dependence.
Becouse of thick ceramic layer with low thermal diffusivity I need solution for hours. That is why I calculate ht for 36000 s (10 hr) as example.

I enclose Comsol Multhiphisic 5.1 solution and my own solution obtained using Maple and method of lines which I delvelop a lot time ago. Both solution in range 0 - 36000 s (10 hr).

[image]

[image]

@xzczd

Here is a problem statement which I tried to solve using Mathematica. I am not sure if I was asked to do this.I am also not sure if this form is correct. But this is my definition of a problem.

[image]

=========================

Hmm...

I'm obviously doing something wrong in code.

Layer of steel, heated on one side (700degC, x = 0), on the other side (x = 10 cm) heat is picked up by convection (only). The result is obviously incorrect.

```
a = 44/(7840*560); (*steel*)
mesh = ToElementMesh[Line[{{0.}, {0.10}}], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.10/100];
pde = D[T[t, x], t] - a*D[T[t, x], x, x];
bc1 = DirichletCondition[T[t, x] == 700, x == 0.];
bc2 = NeumannValue[10*(297 - T[t, x]), x == 0.10];
ic1 = T[0, x] == 297;
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde == bc2, bc1, ic1}, T, {t, 0, 7200}, 
   x ∈ mesh, Method -> {"FiniteElement"}];
sol[7200, 0.10] (*=297K as T in t=0s*)
```

Results after 2h should be 691.2 K

Likzew

Comment: If I reduce the integration time to e.g. `{t, 0, 100}` I do obtain a solution, which can be plotted e.g. using `Plot3D[sol[t, x], {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, gw[[3]]}, PlotRange -> All]` and looks reasonable. You may have to wait a looong time to get the full range you want. I also do get a weird `Part` error, but I am not sure where that comes from. What do you see?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Mathematica.SE. Then, 1. You're imposing 3 boundary conditions, which is not correct. The `bc2rad` looks like the contribution of  thermal radiation, if so, probably it should not be a `NeumannValue`, but an inhomogeneous term of heat conduction equation. You'd better show us the system in traditional math notation so we can help checking. 2. The continuity of heat flux is lost in your code, check these posts for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131542/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121739/1871

Comment: There is a [Heat Transfer tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html) that should be quite useful for your case. Have a look. Also, you can only have one boundary condition at a particular part of the boundary, you have two: `bc2conv` and `bc2rad`. In the heat transfer section of the [PDEModels overview](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/PDEModelsOverview.html) you can also find some heat transfer verification tests.

Comment: @likzew It could be better you post temperature on every border with time step 1000. Then we can compare solutions.

Comment: Version 13 has [ToGradedMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToGradedMesh.html) and [ElementMeshRegionProduct](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMeshRegionProduct.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not checked @Alex Trounev's answer, but this answer shows that there is good agreement between *Mathematica* and COMSOL Multiphysics.

Since you have a variety of thicknesses, I create a little routine so that I could mesh each region with the same number of elements (100 each).

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(* User Supplied Parameters *)
g = {0.25, 0.114, 0.04};(*thickness*)
gw = {0}~Join~Accumulate[g];
λ = {8, 1.8, 44};
ρ = {3100, 2100, 7800};
cp = {1050, 1100, 540};
(* Create a Multiregion Mesh *)
ClearAll[seg, appendCrdRight]
seg[thick_, nelm_, marker_] := Module[{crd, inc, marks},
  crd = Subdivide[0, thick, nelm];
  inc = Partition[Range[crd // Length], 2, 1];
  marks = ConstantArray[marker, inc // Length];
  <|"c" -> crd, "i" -> inc, "m" -> marks|>
  ]
appendCrdRight[a1_, a2_] := Module[{crd, inc, marks, len, lcrd},
  len = a1["c"] // Length;
  lcrd = a1["c"] // Last;
  inc = Join[a1["i"], a2["i"] + len - 1];
  crd = Join[a1["c"], Rest[a2["c"] + lcrd]];
  marks = Join[a1["m"], a2["m"]];
  <|"c" -> crd, "i" -> inc, "m" -> marks|>]
a = Fold[appendCrdRight, MapIndexed[seg[#1, 100, First[#2]] &, g]];
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> Partition[a["c"], 1], 
   "MeshElements" -> {LineElement[a["i"], a["m"]]}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {PointElement[{{1}, {a["c"] // Length}}, {1, 
       2}]}];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> {Red, Green, Blue}]], 
 PlotRange -> {-0.01, 0.01}]
```

[image: Multiregion Mesh]

Now, we can set up the PDE system and solve it on our newly created mesh.

```
σ = First[UnitConvert[Quantity["StefanBoltzmannConstant"]]];
Trob = 1700;
Tamb = 297;
h = 10;
ε = 0.85;
rhocp = Evaluate[
   Piecewise[{{ρ[[1]] cp[[1]], gw[[1]] <= x <= gw[[2]]},
     {ρ[[2]] cp[[2]], gw[[2]] <= x <= gw[[3]]},
     {ρ[[3]] cp[[3]], gw[[3]] <= x <= gw[[4]]}}]];
k = Evaluate[Piecewise[{{λ[[1]], gw[[1]] <= x <= gw[[2]]},
     {λ[[2]], gw[[2]] <= x <= gw[[3]]},
     {λ[[3]], gw[[3]] <= x <= gw[[4]]}}]];
bc1 = DirichletCondition[T[t, x] == Trob, x == 0];
bc2conv = NeumannValue[h*(Tamb - T[t, x]), x == Last@gw];
bc2rad = NeumannValue[ε*σ*(Tamb^4 - T[t, x]^4), 
   x == Last@gw];
ic1 = T[0, x] == Tamb;
op = Inactive[Div][{{-k}}.Inactive[Grad][T[t, x], {x}], {x}] + 
   rhocp*Derivative[1, 0][T][t, x];
pde = op == bc2conv + bc2rad;
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde, bc1, ic1}, 
   T, {t, 0, 36000}, {x} ∈ mesh, StartingStepSize -> 0.01];
```

The model I set up in COMSOL Multiphysics (v 5.5) shows similar results to those shown in the OP.

[image: COMSOL Results]

For comparison purposes, I extracted the temperature data at each phase boundary point in COMSOL.

[image: Temperature Data at Phase Boundaries]

I exported these data to compare versus the *Mathematica* solution.

```
data = {{0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 
    10000, 11000, 12000, 13000, 14000, 15000, 16000, 17000, 18000, 
    19000, 20000, 21000, 22000, 23000, 24000, 25000, 26000, 27000, 
    28000, 29000, 30000, 31000, 32000, 33000, 34000, 35000, 
    36000}, {1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 
    1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 
    1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 
    1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700, 1700}, {297, 297.9169787`, 
    320.0562147`, 374.4552427`, 444.9013611`, 517.6131837`, 
    587.4876631`, 652.6604327`, 712.3644688`, 766.9603206`, 
    816.5391802`, 861.866491`, 902.8730203`, 940.4564489`, 
    974.5556695`, 1005.867455`, 1034.417079`, 1060.665637`, 
    1084.866141`, 1107.411419`, 1128.099762`, 1146.931167`, 
    1164.637928`, 1180.832645`, 1195.499525`, 1208.917884`, 
    1221.536363`, 1233.003818`, 1243.320249`, 1252.972747`, 
    1261.872597`, 1269.909554`, 1277.155111`, 1284.007597`, 
    1290.216067`, 1295.780522`, 1300.901468`}, {297, 297.0000101`, 
    297.0108185`, 297.2403045`, 298.3422144`, 301.3296677`, 
    306.8304462`, 315.0786727`, 326.0187665`, 339.0198185`, 
    353.9950315`, 370.1369655`, 387.5159699`, 405.1722292`, 
    423.1836315`, 440.8382141`, 458.14222`, 474.6735528`, 
    490.3439464`, 504.9171794`, 518.5145476`, 531.1360512`, 
    542.7808248`, 553.4493263`, 563.1415743`, 571.9455027`, 
    580.0023514`, 587.2015743`, 593.5431713`, 599.3724133`, 
    604.6264161`, 609.2270331`, 613.2390417`, 617.0233547`, 
    620.3526001`, 623.2267777`, 625.8287217`}, {297, 297.0000065`, 
    297.0084849`, 297.2058139`, 298.1991325`, 300.9831864`, 
    306.2034638`, 314.1201414`, 324.7019404`, 337.3400768`, 
    351.9481631`, 367.722907`, 384.7337123`, 402.0228897`, 
    419.6676093`, 436.9560503`, 453.8952359`, 470.0643493`, 
    485.3780489`, 499.6031165`, 512.8593059`, 525.1466173`, 
    536.4765686`, 546.8430665`, 556.2458626`, 564.7760878`, 
    572.5801167`, 579.5433842`, 585.6658902`, 591.2927421`, 
    596.3610853`, 600.7928104`, 604.6517643`, 608.293677`, 
    611.4944415`, 614.2540579`, 616.7511966`}};
Show[Plot[Evaluate[sol[t, #] & /@ gw], {t, 0, 36000}], 
 ListPlot[data[[2 ;; -1]], DataRange -> {0, 36000}]]
```

[image: COMSOL Mathematica Comparison]

As you can see, there is very little difference between COMSOL (dots) and *Mathematica* (solid lines).

## Update to Include the Basic Form

@AlexTrounev requested a comparison of the basic form to COMSOL as defined by:

$$\rho {{\hat C}_p}\frac{{\partial T}}{{\partial t}} - \lambda \frac{{{\partial ^2}T}}{{\partial {x^2}}} = 0$$

To use the FEM method, I recommend to cast your equations into coefficient form as shown [FEM Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1222366601).

$$\frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial {t^2}}}u + d\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}u + \nabla \cdot\left( { - c\nabla u - \alpha u + \gamma } \right) + \beta \cdot\nabla u + au - f = 0$$

I find it easier to make comparisons of commercial solver (such as COMSOL) results to *Mathematica* results.

As shown with the following workflow, the Alex's basic form also matches COMSOL quite closely.  I also included a case where I tried to thermal diffusivity in coefficient form and it fails to match COMSOL.  Finally, it may be interesting to note that COMSOL's Laplace Equation Interface does not contain a Laplacian, rather:

$$\nabla  \cdot \left( { - \nabla u} \right) = 0$$

```
(* User Supplied Parameters *)
g = {0.25, 0.114, 0.04};(*thickness*)
gw = {0}~Join~Accumulate[g];
λ = {8, 1.8, 44};
ρ = {3100, 2100, 7800};
cp = {1050, 1100, 540};
σ = First[UnitConvert[Quantity["StefanBoltzmannConstant"]]];
Trob = 1700;
Tamb = 297;
h = 10;
ε = 0.85;
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> Partition[gw, 1], 
  "BoundaryElements" -> {PointElement[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}]}]; nrEle \
= 100; pt = Partition[gw, 2, 1]; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
  "RegionMarker" -> 
   Transpose[{Partition[(Mean /@ pt), 1], {1, 2, 3}, 
     Abs[Subtract @@@ pt]/nrEle}]]
Show[mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> {Red, Green, Blue}]], 
 PlotRange -> {-0.01, 0.01}]
rhocp = Evaluate[
   Piecewise[{{ρ[[1]] cp[[1]], gw[[1]] <= x <= gw[[2]]},
     {ρ[[2]] cp[[2]], gw[[2]] <= x <= gw[[3]]},
     {ρ[[3]] cp[[3]], gw[[3]] <= x <= gw[[4]]}}]];
k = Evaluate[Piecewise[{{λ[[1]], gw[[1]] <= x <= gw[[2]]},
     {λ[[2]], gw[[2]] <= x <= gw[[3]]},
     {λ[[3]], gw[[3]] <= x <= gw[[4]]}}]];
bc1 = DirichletCondition[T[t, x] == Trob, x == 0];
bc2conv = NeumannValue[h*(Tamb - T[t, x]), x == Last@gw];
bc2rad = NeumannValue[ε*σ*(Tamb^4 - T[t, x]^4), 
   x == Last@gw];
ic1 = T[0, x] == Tamb;
(* Coefficient Form *)
op = Inactive[Div][{{-k}}.Inactive[Grad][T[t, x], {x}], {x}] + 
   rhocp*Derivative[1, 0][T][t, x];
pde = op == bc2conv + bc2rad;
Tcoef = NDSolveValue[{pde, bc1, ic1}, 
   T, {t, 0, 36000}, {x} ∈ mesh, StartingStepSize -> 0.01];
(* Alex's "Basic Form" *)
op = rhocp*D[T[t, x], t] - k D[T[t, x], x, x];
pde = op == bc2conv + bc2rad;
Tbasic = NDSolveValue[{pde, bc1, ic1}, 
   T, {t, 0, 36000}, {x} ∈ mesh, StartingStepSize -> 0.01];
(* Coefficient form with thermal diffusivity *)
bc2conv = NeumannValue[h*(Tamb - T[t, x])/rhocp, x == Last@gw];
bc2rad = NeumannValue[ε*σ*(Tamb^4 - T[t, x]^4)/
     rhocp, x == Last@gw];
op = Inactive[Div][{{-k/rhocp}}.Inactive[Grad][T[t, x], {x}], {x}] + 
   Derivative[1, 0][T][t, x];
pde = op == bc2conv + bc2rad;
Talphainside = 
  NDSolveValue[{pde, bc1, ic1}, T, {t, 0, 36000}, {x} ∈ mesh,
    StartingStepSize -> 0.01];
(* Plot Alex's "Basic Form" *)
Show[Plot[Evaluate[Tbasic[t, #] & /@ gw], {t, 0, 36000}], 
 ListPlot[data[[2 ;; -1]], DataRange -> {0, 36000}]]
(* Comparison of Methods *)
Show[Plot[Evaluate[Tcoef[t, #] & /@ gw], {t, 0, 36000}, 
  PlotStyle -> ConstantArray[{Opacity[0.2], Thickness[0.015]}, 4]], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Talphainside[t, #] & /@ gw], {t, 0, 36000}, 
  PlotStyle -> Dashed], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Tbasic[t, #] & /@ gw], {t, 0, 36000}, 
  PlotStyle -> DotDashed]]
```

[image: Basic Form]

Comment: Excelent. Working very well. Thank you very much.

Comment: Here is a shorter way to generate the mesh: `bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> Partition[gw, 1], 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {PointElement[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}]}];
nrEle = 10;
pt = Partition[gw, 2, 1];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
   "RegionMarker" -> 
    Transpose[{Partition[(Mean /@ pt), 1], {1, 2, 3}, 
      Abs[Subtract @@@ pt]/nrEle}]];`

Comment: @user21 Thanks.  I was thrashing around trying to adapt a 2d `bmesh` to `mesh` approach to 1d, but it was getting late so I brute forced it.

Comment: @TimLaska Ok (+1)! You solve it in a basic form. But now check that in a question likzew asked about solution in a form of heat equation with a=frac{\lambda}{\rho c_p}$. And we know that it should be difference between two solutions. But we don't know what solution is right. Could you explain this? – Alex Trounev just now

Comment: @AlexTrounev Generally, to get the best correspondence between COMSOL and _Mathematica_, I put the expressions into coefficient form.  For heat transfer in solids, COMSOL essentially solves $\rho {{\hat C}_p}\frac{{\partial T}}{{\partial t}} + \nabla  \cdot {\mathbf{q}} = 0$, where $\mathbf{q}$ is the heat flux.  That equation should be correct.  In terms of temperature using Fourier's Law, it becomes $\rho {{\hat C}_p}\frac{{\partial T}}{{\partial t}} + \nabla  \cdot \left( { - {\mathbf{k}}\nabla T} \right) = 0$.  I don't think we can factor out conductivity when it is a function of $x$.

Comment: @TimLaska Yes, you right. Me question is about the definition of a problem by likzew in his post. He asked about solution of the equation `pde = D[T[t, x], t] - a*D[T[t, x], x, x];`. Could you also show solution for this equation and compare with Comsol?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I will take a look as soon as I can.  Hopefully, tonight or tomorrow night.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I made an update.  Let me know if that works for you.  The basic form matches closely the coefficient form.

Comment: I would think that if you change to `-k/rhocp` you'd need to adjust the `NeumannValue` too.

Comment: @user21 Good catch! I will correct.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @TimLaska Thank you! It is very good job and a good lesson for the new Mathematica user generation.

Comment: @likzew, Tim made a proposal to add anisotropic meshing capabilities to the FEM mesh generation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/240408/18437). If you think this is worthwhile, consider giving this proposal an upvote.

Answer (score 6):

With a small modification of code we have

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

g = {0.250, 0.114, 0.040};(*thickness*)gw = Total[g];
λ = {8, 1.8, 44};
ρ = {3100, 2100, 7800};
cp = {1050, 1100, 540};
dc = Table[λ[[i]]/(ρ[[i]]*cp[[i]])/10^-5, {i, 
    Length[cp]}];
a[x_] := Piecewise[{{dc[[1]], 0 <= x < g[[1]]}, {dc[[2]], 
    g[[1]] <= x < g[[2]] + g[[1]]}, {dc[[3]], True}}]

σ = 
  QuantityMagnitude[
    UnitConvert[Quantity["StefanBoltzmannConstant"]]] // N;
Trob = 1700.;
Tamb = 297;
h = 10;
ε = 0.85;

bc1 = DirichletCondition[
   T[t, x] == Exp[-1000 t] + Trob/Tamb (1 - Exp[-1000  t]), x == 0.];
bc2 = 10^5/(ρ[[3]] cp[[3]]) NeumannValue[
    h*(1 - T[t, x]) + ε*σ*Tamb^3 (1 - T[t, x]^4),
     x == gw];
bc2rad = NeumannValue[ε*σ*Tamb^3 (1 - T[t, x]^4),
    x == gw];
ic1 = T[0, x] == 1;

pde = D[T[t, x], t] - a[x]*D[T[t, x], x, x];
mesh = ToElementMesh[Line[{{0.}, {gw}}], MaxCellMeasure -> gw/404, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
sol = NDSolveValue[{pde == bc2, bc1, ic1}, T, {t, 0, .36}, 
  x ∈ mesh, Method -> {"FiniteElement"}]

(*Visualization *)

{Plot[a[x]/10^5, {x, 0, gw}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Filling -> Axis], 
 Plot3D[Tamb sol[10^-5 t, x], {t, 0, 36000}, {x, 0., gw}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None], 
 Plot[Table[Tamb sol[10^-5 t, x], {t, 2000, 36000, 2000}], {x, 0., 
   gw}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: I think OP's question still needs clarification, see my comment above for more info.

Comment: @xzczd See update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. I tried to run your code, but I have obtained errors. I will look closer to why the problem occurs. But I counted however that I will able to solve this relatively easy FEM problem without any trick. As close to the definition of the problem as possible.

Comment: @likzew Which version are you in? Nonlinear FEM is not supported before _v12_.

Comment: @xzczd I have used 12.1 version.

Comment: @likzew Sorry, it is really produced errors. I post a new one. Try  again. Please, check what my normalization parameters mean. Also in your original code don't forget to normalize heat flux on `(\[Rho][[3]] cp[[3]])`. It is not a trick.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, Thank you once again for your efforts. Indeed now works without any problem. I compare results from your code to Comsol Multiphysics. For given t=18000s and 36000s, for x=0,404m Comsol returns respectively  484K and 616K whereas your solution 526K, 681K. For x = 0.25m, Comsol 1080K, 1301K, yours code 1009K and 1235K.

Comment: @likzew May be it means that Comsol solves equation in a basic form $\rho c_p \frac {\partial T}{\partial t}=\lambda \nabla^2 T$?

Answer (score 3):

Once again, thank you to everyone who decided to help me in this calculation.
As I wrote I have Mathematica since February 2020. 
I'm learning, but sometimes it's better to ask professionals.

Below is a solution that is based on MMA tutorials.
Especially:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/ModelCollection/ShrinkFitting.html

I also used the elegant way of creating a 1D mesh given by @user21.

It should work.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

HeatTransferModel[T_, X_List, k_, ρ_, Cp_, Velocity_, Source_] :=
  Module[{V, Q, a = k}, 
  V = If[Velocity === "NoFlow", 
    0, ρ*Cp*Velocity.Inactive[Grad][T, X]];
  Q = If[Source === "NoSource", 0, Source];
  If[FreeQ[a, _?VectorQ], a = a*IdentityMatrix[Length[X]]];
  If[VectorQ[a], a = DiagonalMatrix[a]];
  (*Note the-sign in the operator*)
  a = PiecewiseExpand[Piecewise[{{-a, True}}]];
  Inactive[Div][a.Inactive[Grad][T, X], X] + V - Q]
TimeHeatTransferModel[T_, TimeVar_, X_List, k_, ρ_, Cp_, 
  Velocity_, Source_] := ρ*Cp*D[T, {TimeVar, 1}] + 
  HeatTransferModel[T, X, k, ρ, Cp, Velocity, Source]

g = {0.25, 0.114, 0.04};
gw = {0}~Join~Accumulate[g];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> Partition[gw, 1], 
  "BoundaryElements" -> {PointElement[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}]}]; nrEle \
= 10; pt = Partition[gw, 2, 1]; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
  "RegionMarker" -> 
   Transpose[{Partition[(Mean /@ pt), 1], {1, 2, 3}, 
     Abs[Subtract @@@ pt]/nrEle}]];

ρ1 = 3100;
Cp1 = 1050;
k1 = 8;
ρ2 = 2100;
Cp2 = 1100;
k2 = 1.8;
ρ3 = 7800;
Cp3 = 540;
k3 = 44;

parameters = {ρ -> 
    Piecewise[{{ρ1, ElementMarker == 1}, {ρ2, 
       ElementMarker == 2}, {ρ3, ElementMarker == 3}}], 
   Cp -> Piecewise[{{Cp1, ElementMarker == 1}, {Cp2, 
       ElementMarker == 2}, {Cp3, ElementMarker == 3}}], 
   k -> Piecewise[{{k1, ElementMarker == 1}, {k2, 
       ElementMarker == 2}, {k3, ElementMarker == 3}}]};

σ = First[UnitConvert[Quantity["StefanBoltzmannConstant"]]];
Tamb = 297;
h = 10;
Trob = 1700;

bc2conv = NeumannValue[h*(Tamb - T[t, x]), x == 0.404];
bc2rad = NeumannValue[0.85*σ*(297^4 - T[t, x]^4), x == 0.404];
ic1 = {T[0, x] == Tamb};
bc1 = DirichletCondition[T[t, x] == Trob, x == 0];


pde = {TimeHeatTransferModel[T[t, x], t, {x}, k, ρ, Cp, "NoFlow",
       "NoSource"] == bc2conv + bc2rad, bc1, ic1} /. parameters;

sol = NDSolveValue[pde, T, {t, 0, 36000}, x ∈ mesh]

sol[36000, 0.404]

Plot[Table[sol[t, x], {t, 3600, 36000, 1800}], {x, 0, 0.404}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0.404}, {290, 1700}}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Plot: {t,3600,36000,1800}]

Likzew

Comment: So you use basic form of the heat equation while in your question you try to solve it in a form with `a`. It will be good if you change your question also to underlay this difference.