# Inverse Laplace transform of this complicated function

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, integral-equations, inverse, integral-transforms

I have been solving a coupled PDE system analytically and I need to find the inverse Laplace transform of $(1)$ and get $T(x,y)$. $s$ is the Laplace domain variable and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, T_{fi}, A , d$ are constants.

$$
\mathcal{L_x}(T)=\frac{As(s+\alpha) - \beta T_{fi}}{s(s^2 - \beta + \alpha s)}+ \frac{\gamma (e^{\sigma y}+e^{\sigma(2d-y)})}{s\sigma (1-e^{2\sigma d})} \tag 1
$$
where

$$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\beta s - \alpha s^2 - s^3}{s+\alpha}}$$

I have tried the *Wolfram alpha* widget but it fails to do the job. The problem comes especially with the second term.
Can anyone suggest a way to handle the inverse transformation of $(1)$ ?

---

**ORIGINS**

I have been trying to solve $(1.1)$, and the Laplace transform mentioned in equation $(1)$ comes from $(1.1)$ subjected to the given boundary conditions.

The term $A$ is $T(0,y)$, which is temporarily being treated as a constant
$$
\nabla^2 T - \beta T + \beta\Bigg[\alpha e^{-\alpha x} \Bigg(\int_0^x e^{\alpha s}T(s,y)\mathrm{d}s+\frac{T_{fi}}{\alpha}\Bigg)\Bigg]=0 \tag {1.1}
$$
(1.1) is dictated by the following boundary conditions:
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \vert_{x=0} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \vert_{x=L} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial y} \vert_{y=d} = 0 , \frac{\partial T}{\partial y} \vert_{y=0}=\gamma
$$

---

**Intermediate steps between $(1.1)$ to $(1)$**

Taking Laplace transform of $(1.1)$ w.r.t. $x$
$$
s^2 \mathcal{L_x}T(x,y) - \color{red}{sT(0,y)} - \color{green}{\frac{\partial T(0,y)}{\partial x}} + \mathcal{L_x}\Bigg(\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2}\Bigg)-\\ \beta \mathcal{L_x}T(x,y) + \frac{\alpha \beta}{\alpha +s}\mathcal{L_x}T(x,y) + \frac{\beta}{\beta +s} T_{fi} = 0 \tag 2
$$
$T(0,y)$ is an unknown and we denote it with the letter $A$ for the rest of this analysis. 
$$
\mathcal{L_x}\Bigg(\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2}\Bigg)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\mathcal{L_x}(T(x,y))
$$
Equation $(2)$ becomes
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\mathcal{L_x}(T)+\Bigg(s^2 - \beta + \frac{\alpha \beta}{\alpha +s}\Bigg)\mathcal{L_x}(T)-sA+\frac{\beta T_{fi}}{\alpha +s}=0 \tag 3
$$
Solve $(3)$ (an O.D.E) to find $\mathcal{L_x}(T)$ $\color{Blue}{\Rightarrow}$ Use $y$ B.C.(s) to determine the constants $\color{Blue}{\Rightarrow}$ Find $\color{black}{T=\mathcal{L_x^{-1}}(T)}$ $\color{Blue}{\Rightarrow}$ Use the $x=L$ B.C. to determine $A$

Solving $(3)$ gives
$$
\mathcal{L_x}(T)=\frac{As(s+\alpha) - \beta T_{fi}}{s(s^2 - \beta + \alpha s)}+C_1 e^{\sigma y} + C_2 e^{-\sigma y} \tag 4
$$
where, $$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\beta s - \alpha s^2 - s^3}{s+\alpha}}$$
The $y$ boundary conditions become:

$\frac{\partial T}{\partial y} \vert_{y=d} = 0 , \frac{\partial T}{\partial y} \vert_{y=0}=\gamma \color{Blue}{\Rightarrow} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L_x}(T)}{\partial y} \vert_{y=d} = 0,\frac{\partial \mathcal{L_x}(T)}{\partial y} \vert_{y=0}=\gamma$

Utilizing these conditions $C_2=C_1 e^{2\sigma d}$ and $C_1=\frac{\gamma}{s\sigma (1-e^{2\sigma d})}$

Substituting in $(4)$ gives us 
$$
\mathcal{L_x}(T)=\frac{As(s+\alpha) - \beta T_{fi}}{s(s^2 - \beta + \alpha s)}+ \frac{\gamma (e^{\sigma y}+e^{\sigma(2d-y)})}{s\sigma (1-e^{2\sigma d})} \tag 1
$$

---

For separation of variables I assumed the following ansatz

$$
T(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k(y)\cos(\frac{k\pi x}{L})=f_0(y)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(y)\cos(\frac{k\pi x}{L})
$$

Comment: This problem seems to hinge on the math, rather than on Mathematica, doesn't it? Wouldn't it be a better fit for https://math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @MarcoB I guess you are right to some extent. The transform I posted is the final step of a coupled heat transfer problem I have been working on (regrading which I already took some help from MathStack). Getting the inverse Laplace transform of $(1)$ is something which is supposed to be the next step. I was hoping if that could be done using Mathematica.

Comment: Perhaps this might be considered in terms of the Fourier transform instead of the Laplace transform.  Depending on the values of `alpha` and `beta` a stationary phase approximation might be appropriate.

Comment: @mikado I am sorry to say, but I was unable to understand the essence of your remark. In any case, I have added an **Origins** section to my original question to provide some context to the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you've deduced $(1)$ correctly? We know Laplace transform is a tool for initial value problem, but you seem to use it in $x$ direction where $x \in [0,1]$?

Comment: @xzczd Yes, I think so. And exactly, this is a boundary value problem. You are right about that. I tried Laplace transform when Separation of variables on $(1)$ made the process too messy. If it can help, I can post the intermediate steps between $(1.1)$ and $(1)$

Comment: I think that'll help. BTW, where's the term $A$?

Comment: Do you just want to obtain an analytic solution for problem (1.1)? Actually problem $(1.1)$ can be solved with [Finite Fourier cosine transform and its inversion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155817/1871) in a relatively straightforward manner, but the analytic result is rather complicated and I doubt if it's useful or not.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, I was targeting for an analytic solution. The equation $(1.1)$ represents the coupled heat transfer in miniaturized devices called heat sinks which are used to cool cpu and gpu(s). After obtaining $T$, I plan to deduce expressions for thermal performance of such devices. The term $A$ only arises when I try to use Laplace transform on $(1.1)$ and I was planning on using the available boundary conditions to determine it, once I get $T$ in terms of $A$

Comment: @xzczd For now I will post my attempt. It would be great if you could direct me towards any resources about the method you mentioned in your earlier comment

Comment: @xzczd I have also posted the ansatz I used when I attempted the problem using separation of variables.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your deduction is wrong. $A$ is constant only in $x$ direction, it's a function of $y$, so you cannot treat it as a constant when solving $(3)$. Just compare `DSolve[D[u[t], t, t] - A == 0, u[t], t]` and `DSolve[D[u[t], t, t] - A[t] == 0, u[t], t]`.

Comment: @xzcd Thanks a lot for this insight. I get my error now. I think Laplace transform is not the way ahead to do this. Finally, I would just like your comment on should I try with the Fourier cosine method you mentioned ?

Comment: Fourier cosine transform itself is a simple technique (much simpler than separation of variables in my view). Its usage is just similar to Laplace transform. You can refer to the link I posted above. Actually I've already found the analytic solution with finite Fourier cosine transform, but as already mentioned, the result is rather complicated, and I doubt if it'll be useful, and reading your earlier posts, I'm afraid the code I used may be a bit too advanced for you to understand at this stage, do you want to see my code?

Comment: I would certainly like to see your code and the resulting solution. If you post it as an answer, I am willing to accept it.  I concede that I am not too adept  at Mathematica, but I can certainly give it a try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This post contains several code blocks, you can copy them easily with the help of [`importCode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3537/1871).

---

As already mentioned in the comment above, the deduction of $(1)$ is incorrect because OP forgot $A$ cannot be treated as constant when solving ODE $(3)$, so it doesn't make much sense to continue discussing the Laplace inversion of $(1)$. Since OP's target is just to solve $(1.1)$ analytically, I'll show my solution based on [finite Fourier cosine transform and its inversion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155817/1871) as an answer. The code is a bit advanced, please check the document carefully by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> to understand it.

We first interpret the PDE and b.c.s to *Mathematica* code:

```
eq = Laplacian[
    T[x, y], {x, y}] - β T[x, 
     y] + β (α Exp[-α x] (Integrate[
         Exp[α s] T[s, y], {s, 0, x}] + Tfi/α)) == 0

bcx = {D[T[x, y], x] == 0 /. x -> 0, D[T[x, y], x] == 0 /. x -> L}

bcy = {D[T[x, y], y] == γ /. y -> 0, D[T[x, y], y] == 0 /. y -> d}
```

It's easy to notice the integral inside `eq` can be eliminated:

```
neweq = eq /. Solve[D[eq, x], Integrate[E^(α s) T[s, y], {s, 0, x}]][[1]] // 
  Simplify[#, α != 0] &
```

> $$\alpha \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2}+\alpha \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^3 T}{\partial y^2 \partial x}+\frac{\partial^3 T}{\partial x^3}=\beta \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}$$

The differential order in $x$ direction becomes $3$, so we need one more b.c., this can be deduced by setting $x$ to $0$ in `eq`:

```
newbc = eq /. x -> 0
```

OK, let's begin solving. **Definition of `finiteFourierCosTransform` and `inverseFiniteFourierCosTransform` isn't included in this post, please find them in the link above.** We make finite Fourier cosine transform in the range $y \in [0, d]$:

```
rule = finiteFourierCosTransform[a_, __] :> a;

tneweq = finiteFourierCosTransform[neweq, {y, 0, d}, n] /. 
   Rule @@@ Flatten@{bcy, D[bcy, x]} /. rule

tbcx = finiteFourierCosTransform[bcx, {y, 0, d}, n] /. rule

tnewbc = finiteFourierCosTransform[newbc, {y, 0, d}, n] /. (Rule @@@ bcy /. x -> 0) /. rule
```

> **Remark**
>
> I've stripped off `finiteFourierCosTransform` because `DSolve`
>   has difficulty in understanding expression like
>   `finiteFourierCosTransform[T[x, y], {y, 0, d}, n]`. Just remember that
>   `T[x, y]` actually denotes `finiteFourierCosTransform[T[x, y], {y, 0, d}, n]` in `tneweq`, `tbcx` and `tnewbc`.

`{tneweq, tbcx, tnewbc}` forms a boundary value problem of ODE, it can be easily solved by `DSolve`:

```
tsolzero = T[x, y] /. 
  First@DSolve[Simplify[#, n == 0] &@{tneweq, tbcx, tnewbc}, T[x, y], x]

tsolrest = T[x, y] /. 
  First@DSolve[Simplify[#, n > 0] &@{tneweq, tbcx, tnewbc}, T[x, y], x]

tsol = Piecewise[{{tsolzero, n == 0}}, tsolrest]
```

> **Remark**
>
> The `n == 0` case is solved separately, or `DSolve` won't handle the
>   removable singularity properly.

The final step is to transform back:

```
sol = inverseFiniteFourierCosTransform[tsol, n, {y, 0, d}]
```

[image]

…As already mentioned, the solution is rather complicated.

"So, how do you know the mess is correct?" OK, let's verify it by solving the problem numerically. However, the somewhat strange `newbc` stops us from using `NDSolve`, so I'll solve the problem based on FDM. I'll use [`pdetoae`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the generation of finite difference equations:

```
setparameters = 
  Function[expr, 
   Block[{α = 1, β = 2, γ = 3, L = 4, d = 5, Tfi = 6}, expr], 
   HoldAll];

test = Compile[{x, y}, #] &[sol /. C -> 20 // ReleaseHold // ToRadicals] // setparameters;

points@x = points@y = 50; domain@x = {0, L}; domain@y = {0, d};
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {x, y};
difforder = 2;
(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[T[x, y], grid /@ {x, y}, difforder];

delx = #[[3 ;; -2]] &; dely = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;

ae = dely /@ delx@ptoafunc@neweq;
aebcx = dely /@ ptoafunc@bcx;
aebcnew = dely@ptoafunc@newbc;
aebcy = ptoafunc@bcy;
var = Outer[T, grid@x, grid@y] // setparameters // Flatten;
{barray, marray} = 
 CoefficientArrays[Flatten@{ae, aebcx, aebcnew, aebcy} // setparameters, var]

nsol = ListInterpolation[Partition[LinearSolve[marray, -N@barray], points@y], 
   grid /@ {x, y}] // setparameters

 lst = Table[
    Plot[{test[x, y], nsol[x, y]}, {x, 0, L}, 
     PlotLegends -> {"Series Solution", "FDM Solution"}], {y, 0, d, d/25}] // 
   setparameters;

ListAnimate@lst
```

[image]

As we can see, the 2 solutions agree well, and will be better if you increase `points[x]`, `points[y]`, number of terms in `test`.

> **Remark**
>
> The discrepancy at $y=0$ and $y=d$ is slightly large, this is
>   expected, because the b.c.s are actually inconsistent.

Comment: This is extremely well put together. Really appreciate the effort that you had to put in here. I will go through each step separately now and understand them.

Comment: Can [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226346/three-dimensional-laplacian-insulated-on-lateral-faces-and-convectively-exposed) problem yield to the FFT method ?

Comment: @IndrasisMitra No. Just similar your previous question, $\frac{\partial t_c}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial t_h}{\partial x}$ are on the way. Once again, please check the property of finite Fourier transform carefully to understand what type of problem can be solved with it.

Comment: I apologize for this. I should have been more careful. Probably I got confused. I do have a two-dimensional variant to the said question where I encounter a partio-integral differential equation in one variable $T$ with no $t$ in b.c.(s).

Comment: I have posted a two-dimensional version of the aforementioned question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226562/can-this-boundary-value-problem-be-solved-using-finite-fourier-or-any-integral-t) which I think should yield to the transform method. I  have concluded this looking at the properties you have mentioned in your original FFT post and some similarities to the question you have answered above.