# Approach to analytically solve a Coupled system of PDE in Mathematica [Heat transfer in cylindrical coordinates]

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, boundary-conditions, heat-equation

I have the following two PDEs, which describe steady-state coupled heat transport between a externally heated axi-symmetric solid body (Eq. 1, $T(r,z)$) and a fluid (Eq. 2, $t(z)$) flowing inside it

$$\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2}=0 \tag1$$

$$\frac{\partial t}{\partial z}+\alpha(t-T(r_1,z))=0 \tag2$$

Eq. (1) is defined in the domain $r\in[r_1,r_2]$ where $r_1$ and $r_2$ describe the inner and outer radii of the cylinder and $z\in[0,L]$ where $L$ is the length of the cylinder. The boundary conditions for Eq. (1) are
$$\frac{\partial T(r,0)}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial T(r,L)}{\partial z}=0 \tag3$$

$$\frac{\partial T(r_2,z)}{\partial r}=\gamma \tag4$$

$$\frac{\partial T(r_1,z)}{\partial r}=\beta(T(r_1,z)-t) \tag5$$

For Eq. (2) it is known that $t(z=0)=t_{in}$

$\alpha,\beta,\gamma,t_{in}$ are known constants. It seems the solid and fluid temperatures are coupled through the B.C. at $r=r_1$ (solid-fluid interface, Robin condition).

Any suggestion on how to approach this problem analytically in Mathematica is appreciated. I get that this is not a Mathematica related question but I have had some excellent feedback on my earlier questions which have helped me find better solution methodologies.

---

Following Bill Watts' answer, I took some realistic parameters.

These constants correspond to a copper circular channel (thermal conductivity = 390 W/mK) with inner and outer radii of $1 mm$ and $2 mm$ respectively in which fluid enters with a velocity of $0.0333 m/s$. The cylinder is heated externally by a heat flux of $8000 W/m^2 $ and the heat transfer coefficient is $2000 W/m^2 K$

which give

`\[Alpha] = 28.852; \[Beta] = 5.128; \[Gamma] = 20.51; tin = 300; L = 0.03; r1 = 0.001; r2 = 0.002;`

and on plotting the boundary condition $(5)$, the discrepancy seems to have reduced
[image]

For the same set of parameters except with $r_2 = 5 mm$, the discrepancy almost vanishes

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where is Mathematica code?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I am sorry to say that I have not tried anything still in Mathematica. The maximum I did was express $t$ as an integral function of $T$ from $(2)$ and substituted in the boundary condition $(5)$ which transforms it into $$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \vert_{r=r_1}=\beta\Bigg[T-\alpha e^{-\alpha z}\bigg(\int_0^z e^{\alpha s} T(r,s) \mathrm{d}s + \frac{T_{fi}}{\alpha} \bigg)\Bigg]
$$ I could not figure out how to proceed after this.

Comment: I guess in Eq(2) the $T$ should be $T(r_1,z)$?

Comment: @xzczd Yes you are right. My bad. Just made the edit.

Comment: Just to be sure, a numeric approach would not be helpful right? Second question: Can any of the constants assumed to be small? It would be very helpful to start with the assumption that $\alpha$ is small. In that case a pertubational expansion in $\alpha$ might be feasible. A fully analytic treatment of a PDE is typically the exception not the default case. One often starts by analyzing certain special cases analytically and then proceeds by using those to verify the more general numeric solutions.

Comment: The new system is harder to solve analytically compared to the previous one mentioned in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/209913/1871) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3435036/58219) post, because $(2)$ and $(5)$ is equivalent to a b.c. involving first order derivative of $z$, thus finite Fourier transform won't help here. There might exists other integral transform that's suitable for this type of b.c., but searching such transform is beyond my reach.

Comment: @Max1 I am sorry to say but the constant $\alpha$ is known as heat transfer coefficient in the field of transport phenomena and cannot be assumed to be small. Although I can understand the point you are trying to make

Comment: @xzczd You are right. The previous problems I was dealing with was for a rectangular heat sink and hence the use of a Cartesian coordinate system. The present problem is for a cylindrical heat sink which changes in form due to the axi-symmetric coordinates. Anyway, I appreciate the inputs you made.

Comment: @Max1 My apologies. $\alpha$ is not the heat transfer coefficient. Although it still is not small, but my reasoning in my last comment was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is not perfect, but I will throw it out there anyway in case anyone has an interest to improve it.
Use separation of variables

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Work on the `T` equation first

```
pde = D[T[r, z], r, r] + (1/r)*D[T[r, z], r] + D[T[r, z], z, z] == 0
```

Separation by multiples

```
T[r_, z_] = R[r] Z[z]

pde/T[r, z] // Expand
(*R''[r]/R[r] + R''[r]/(r R[r]) + Z''[z]/Z[z] == 0*)
```

Choose the z equation such that it is sinusoidal in z due to the given boundary conditions.

```
zeq = Z''[z]/Z[z] == -a^2

DSolve[zeq, Z[z], z] // Flatten

Z[z_] = Z[z] /. % /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}
(*c1 Cos[a z] + c2 Sin[a z]*)
```

Now the R equation

```
req = R''[r]/R[r] + R'[r]/(r R[r]) == a^2

DSolve[req, R[r], r] // Flatten

R[r_] = (R[r] /. % /. {C[1] -> c3, C[2] -> c4})
(*c3 BesselJ[0, I a r] + c4 BesselY[0, -I a r]*)
```

I don't know why Mathematica always insists on complex solutions for this equation.  Convert by:

```
FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[R[r], r > 0]] // Collect[#, BesselI[0, a r]] &
```

Consolidate constants

```
R[r_] = % /. {Coefficient[%, BesselI[0, a r]] -> c3, Coefficient[%, BesselK[0, a r]] -> c4}
(*c3 BesselI[0, a r] + c4 BesselK[0, a r]*)
```

As usual with the diffusivity equation we don't have enough pieces with separation by multiplication.
Now separate by addition.

```
T[r_, z_] = Rp[r] + Zp[z]

pde
(*Rp''[r] + Rp'[r]/r + Zp''[z] == 0*)

zpeq = Zp''[z] == b

DSolve[zpeq, Zp[z], z] // Flatten

Zp[z_] = Zp[z] /. % /. {C[1] -> c5, C[2] -> c6}
(*(b z^2)/2 + c5 + c6 z*)

rpeq = Rp''[r] + Rp'[r]/r + b == 0

DSolve[rpeq, Rp[r], r] // Flatten

Rp[r_] = Rp[r] /. % /. {C[1] -> c7, C[2] -> 0}
(*c7 Log[r] - (b r^2)/4*)
```

I chose `C[1]` to be zero because we don't need two constant terms.
Put it all together:

```
T[r_, z_] = R[r] Z[z] + Rp[r] + Zp[z]
(c1 Cos[a z] + c2 Sin[a z]) (c3 BesselI[0, a r] + c4 BesselK[0, a r]) - (b r^2)/4 + (b z^2)/2 + c5 + c6 z + c7 Log[r]
```

Check

```
pde // FullSimplify
(*True*)
```

Apply the boundary conditions

```
(D[T[r, z], z] /. z -> 0) == 0
(*a c2 (c3 BesselI[0, a r] + c4 BesselK[0, a r]) + c6 == 0*)
```

so

```
c2 = 0
c6 = 0
```

and consolidate constants

```
c1 = 1

(D[T[r, z], z] /. z -> L) == 0
(*b L - a Sin[a L] (c3 BesselI[0, a r] + c4 BesselK[0, a r]) == 0*)
```

from which

```
b = 0
```

and to make the `Sin` zero:

```
a = (n π)/L
```

with

```
$Assumptions = n ∈ Integers
```

`T` becomes an infinite series in `n`, but we will leave off the sum for now so MMa won't constantly try to evaluate it.

```
(D[T[r, z], r] /. r -> r2) == γ
(*Cos[(π n z)/L] ((π c3 n BesselI[1, (n π r2)/L])/L - (π c4 n BesselK[1, (n π r2)/L])/L) + c7/r2 == γ*)
```

We can satisfy by

```
c4 = c4 /. Solve[Coefficient[%[[1]], Cos[(\[Pi] n z)/L]] == 0, c4][[1]]
(*(c3 BesselI[1, (n π r2)/L])/BesselK[1, (n π r2)/L]*)
```

and

```
c7 = c7 /. Solve[c7/r2 == γ, c7][[1]]
(*γ r2*)

T[r, z] // Collect[#, c3] &
```

Check out the solution when `n = 0`.  `BesselK` is unbounded with zero arguments, so take the limit.

```
Limit[T[r, z], n -> 0]
(*c3 + c5 + γ r2 Log[r]*)
```

Note that `c5` is the equivalent `c3` constant when n = 0 in the Fourier series.
We only need to keep one of them, so for `n = 0`

```
T0[r_, z_] = % /. c3 -> 0
```

For general n

```
Tn[r_, z_] = T[r, z] - T0[r, z] // Simplify
```

Now work on the differential equation for `t`.

```
pdet = (t'[z] + α (t[z] - T[r1, z]) == 0)
```

General n

```
pde2 = (tn'[z] + α (tn[z] - Tn[r1, z]) == 0)

(DSolve[pde2, tn[z], z] // Flatten)

tn[z_] = (tn[z] /. % /. C[1] -> c8)
```

The outputs are getting a little long to show here.

For `n = 0`

```
pde20 = t0'[z] + α (t0[z] - T0[r1, z]) == 0

DSolve[pde20, t0[z], z] // Flatten

t0[z_] = t0[z] /. % /. C[1] -> c80
(*c5 + c80 E^(α (-z)) + γ r2 Log[r1]*)
```

Now apply the initial condition `t[0] == tin`
Do this by setting the part contain n to zero, and set the constant part to tin.

```
c8 = c8 /. Solve[tn[0] == 0, c8][[1]]

c80 = c80 /. Solve[t0[0] == tin, c80][[1]]

tn[z_] = tn[z] // Simplify

t0[z] // Simplify

t[z_] = t0[z] + tn[z]
```

where it is understood that the part containing n is the sum over n from 1 to infinity.
Check the `t` solution.

```
pdet // Simplify
(*True*)
```

Apply the final bc on general n and n = 0 separately using the orthogonality of `Cos[(π n z)/L]`.  The final boundary condition.

```
bcf = (D[T[r, z], r] /. r -> r1) == β (T[r1, z] - t[z])
```

For `n = 0`

```
Limit[bcf[[1]], n -> 0]
(*(γ r2)/r1*)

Limit[bcf[[2]], n -> 0]
(*β E^(α (-z)) (c3 + c5 + γ r2 Log[r1] - tin)*)
```

Again, c5 is just the constant term in the fourier series when `n = 0`, so we don't need both it and `c3`.

```
bcfn0 = % == %% /. c5 + c3 -> c30
(*β E^(α (-z)) (c30 + γ r2 Log[r1] - tin) == (γ r2)/r1*)
```

Use orthogonality

```
Integrate[bcfn0[[1]], {z, 0, L}] == Integrate[bcfn0[[2]], {z, 0, L}]

c5 = c30 /. Solve[%, c30][[1]] // Simplify
```

General n

```
ortheq = Integrate[bcf[[1]]*Cos[(n*Pi*z)/L], {z, 0, L}] == Integrate[bcf[[2]]*Cos[(n*Pi*z)/L], {z, 0, L}]

c3 = c3 /. Solve[%, c3][[1]] // Simplify
```

Simplify everything.

```
t0[z_] = t0[z] // Simplify

tn[z_] = tn[z] // Simplify

T0[r_, z_] = T0[r, z] // Simplify

Tn[r_, z] = Tn[r, z] // Simplify
```

Plug in numbers

```
α = 1/10;
β = 1/10;
γ = 1;
tin = 1;
L = 10;
r1 = 1;
r2 = 2;
```

I am using exact numbers so I can use lots of terms in the Fourier series if necessary.

For calculation, add an additional argument used for the number of terms in the series.

```
T[r_, z_, mm_] := T0[r, z] + Sum[Tn[r, z], {n, 1, mm}]
t[z_, mm_] := t0[z] + Sum[tn[z], {n, 1, mm}]
```

Of course mm should actually be infinity, but we will use a finite series for calculation.

And the derivatives

```
dtdz[Z_, mm_] := (D[t0[z], z] /. z -> Z) + Sum[D[tn[z], z] /. z -> Z, {n, 1, mm}]
dTdr[R_, z_, mm_] := (D[T0[r, z], r] /. r -> R) + Sum[D[Tn[r, z], r] /. r -> R, {n, 1, mm}]
dTdz[r_, Z_, mm_] := (D[T0[r, z], z] /. z -> Z) + Sum[D[Tn[r, z], z] /. z -> Z, {n, 1, mm}]
```

Compiling the expressions will speed up the calculations, but compiling is limited to machine precision values.  For checking I don't want that restriction.

Make some plots.

`T` at a few values of `z`

```
Plot[{Evaluate[T[r, 0, 50]], Evaluate[T[r, L/2, 50]], Evaluate[T[r, L, 50]]}, {r, r1, r2}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[T[r, z, 50]], {r, r1, r2}, {z, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Check

```
t[0] == tin
(*True*)
```

Plot of `t`

```
Plot[Evaluate[t[z, 50]], {z, 0, L}]
```

[image]

The `t` pde

Steps = 200

```
Plot[Evaluate[dtdz[z, Steps] + α (t[z, Steps] - T[r1, z, Steps])], {z, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Pretty close to zero.

The boundary at `r2`.

```
Plot[Evaluate[dTdr[r, z, 20] /. r -> r2] - γ, {z, 0, L}]
```

[image]

The final boundary condition.

```
Plot[{Evaluate[dTdr[r, z, 50] /. r -> r1], 
  Evaluate[β (T[r1, z, 50] - t[z, 50])]}, {z, 0, L}, 
 PlotRange -> {1.5, 2.8}]
```

[image]

All the other checks are good, but these two plots should lie on top of each other.  And while they are not way off, I think the difference is too large to just be numerical error.

I invite anyone with an interest in this type of problem to review this solution for improvement.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate solution. Really appreciate it. I am going through it step by step and would report my queries. Although on a first look it seems you have used an addition form of solution $T(r,z)=Rp(r)+Zp(z)$. This is something new to me. Can you point out any reference/reasoning behind this ? Additionally how did $c_2=0, c_6=0$ after applying the first $z$ boundary condition ?

Comment: In my experience the diffusivity equation generally requires both multiplication and addition forms of variable separation.  You can't get there with just multiplication.  I don't have a reference, but  I've been doing it since the 70's.  Zeroing $c2$ and $c6$ is necessary to make the first boundary condition $True$.

Comment: While using orthogonality for `n=0` on the RHS of `bcf` I could not reproduce the $e^{-\alpha z}$ term that you find. It would be helpful if you could look into it once.

Comment: That comes directly from the contribution of $t0(z)$ in bcf.  You shouldn't have lost that.

Comment: It is possible that your LHS and RHS of the equations could be slightly different from mine.  All the same terms should be there though, and they would solve to the same final results.

Comment: I completed the derivation and used some realistic parameters for the constants in the problem. I have attached the plots of the boundary condition $(5)$ as an edit to the original question and, it seems that the discrepancy you encountered has reduced. Although I am afraid to say that I still did not get the $e^{-\alpha z}$ term on the RHS of `bcf`. So, I manually multiplied it while using the orthogonality condition in the next step. I need to look into that again.

Comment: Interesting that different parameters would get a closer match.  I'm glad it worked out.

Comment: This is not related to this question. It certainly seems you have had a lot of experience solving such practical problems. Can you suggest me any text which discusses advanced boundary value problems in detail. For ex.  Few of the steps you did in your solution, I don't think  I would have figured out on my own. Or is it something which can just come with practice. Thanks again.

Comment: I originally learned from taking electrodynamics in grad school out of J.D. Jackson's "Classical Electrodynamics" book.  It is an excellent reference, but be prepared to spend a lot of time understanding it.  Otherwise, I worked with the diffusivity equation a lot  in the oil field, since the reservoir pressure due to fluid flow in porous media is governed by that equation.  This is the first time I worked the diffusivity equation simultaneously with another differential equation, however.

Comment: Apppreciate your input.

Comment: Hi again. If its not a problem can you have a try at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/two-dimensional-laplacian-coupled-with-another-equation-leading-to-a-bvp-with-in?noredirect=1#comment575387_226092) question which is similar to the one you have answered here but in cartesian coordinates. My apologies if it goes against the MMA SE ethos to request feedback in this way. I tried the problem but couldn't make much headway. Thanks.

Comment: @Indrasis Mitra  I don't have a problem with you contacting me this way.  I have looked at the question you refer to, but I have not thought of a good way to approach the problem. If I think of something useful, I will post it.

Comment: The domain of the problem here and my latest problem are quite similar. They even have the same boundary conditions except the nature of the Laplacian. Hence, I used the same workflow you suggested here on that problem.The limit for the `n=0` term because of the blowup of the Bessel function was not required there. Apart from this everything else worked quite congruently to this problem. The only ambiguity comes when I plotted the final solid temperature `T[x,y]` which instead of showing an increasing trend along the flow length, actually decreased.

Comment: I have added the whole procedure and the plot to the original question as a second attempt.

Comment: @Indrasis Mitra I will look at your procedure

Comment: I will again ask you for help on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226346/three-dimensional-laplacian-insulated-on-lateral-faces-and-convectively-exposed) problem. I have included an attempt to solution lately if you might have seen the question earlier. Hope you find it interesting.