# Two-dimensional Laplacian coupled with another equation leading to a BVP with integral bc(s)

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, modeling, boundary-conditions, heat-equation

I have the two-dimensional Laplacian $(\nabla^2 T(x,y)=0)$ coupled with another equation. The Laplacian is defined over $x\in[0,L], y\in[0,l]$. On manipulating the second equation (which I have described in the **Origins** section of my question) I have managed to reduce the problem to a boundary value problem on the Laplacian subjected to the following boundary conditions

$$\frac{\partial T(0,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial T(L,y)}{\partial x}=0 \tag 1$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,0)}{\partial y}=\gamma \tag 2$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,l)}{\partial y}=\zeta \Bigg[T(x,l)-\Bigg\{\alpha e^{-\alpha x}\Bigg(\int_0^x e^{\alpha s }T(s,y)\mathrm{d}s+\frac{t_{i}}{\alpha}\Bigg)\Bigg\}\Bigg] \tag 3$$

$\gamma, \alpha, \zeta, t_i$ are all constants $>0$. Can anyone suggest a way to solve this problem ?

---

**Origins**

The 3rd boundary condition is actually of the following form:

$$\frac{\partial T(x,l)}{\partial y}=\zeta \Bigg[T(x,l)-t\Bigg] \tag 4$$
The $t$ in $(4)$ is governed by the following equation (this is the *other* equation I mentioned earlier):

$$\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}+\alpha(t-T(x,l))=0 \tag 5$$

where it is known that $t(x=0)=t_i$. To derive $(3)$, I solved $(5)$ using the method of integrating factor and substituted in $(4)$.

*My original problem is the Laplacian coupled with $(5)$*.

---

**Is there a way to solve this analytically in Mathematica considering the integral type boundary conditions at play?**
I will include the equations in the form of *Mathematica* code

```
eq = Laplacian[T[x, y], {x, y}] == 0
bcx = {D[T[x, y], x] == 0 /. x -> 0, D[T[x, y], x] == 0 /. x -> L}
bcy1 = D[T[x, y], y] == γ /. y -> 0
bcy2 = D[T[x, y], y] == ζ (T[x, l] - α E^(-α x) (Integrate[E^(α s) T[s, y], {s, 0, x}] + ti/α))/. y -> l
```

*Physical meaning*

The problem describes the flow of a fluid (with temperature $t$ and described by $(5)$) over a rectangular plate (at $y=l$) heated from the bottom (at $y=0$). The fluid is thermally coupled to the plate temperature $T$ through boundary condition $(3)$ which is the convection or Robin type condition.

---

**Attempt using Finite Fourier transform**

I tired using the finite Fourier sine transform about which I learned from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209913/inverse-laplace-transform-of-this-complicated-function) answer. The definitions required to run the code below can be obtained from xzczd's [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155817/implement-finite-fourier-transforms) post.

```
eq = Laplacian[T[x, y], {x, y}] == 0
bcx = {D[T[x, y], x] == 0 /. x -> 0, D[T[x, y], x] == 0 /. x -> L}
bcy = {D[T[x, y], y] == γ /. y -> 0, D[T[x, y], y] == ζ (T[x, l] - α E^(-α x) (Integrate[E^(α s) T[s, y], {s, 0, x}] + ti/α)) /. y -> l}
rule = finiteFourierSinTransform[a_, __] :> a;
teq = finiteFourierSinTransform[eq, {y, 0, l}, n] /. Rule @@@ Flatten@{bcy, D[bcy, x]} /. rule
tbcx = finiteFourierSinTransform[bcx, {y, 0, l}, n] /. rule
tsol = T[x, y] /. First@DSolve[Simplify[#, n] &@{teq, tbcx}, T[x, y], x]
sol = inverseFiniteFourierSinTransform[tsol, n, {y, 0, l}]
```

The output for `tsol` gives a weird answer:
[image]
which can be inverted but won't evaluate on substituting the value of the constants because of the presence of `True` terms

Some practical values of the constants are

```
γ=15.8346, α=574.866, ζ=4.633, ti=300, L=0.06, l=0.001
```

---

**Attempt 2**
Using Bill Watt's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220608/approach-to-analytically-solve-a-coupled-system-of-pde-in-mathematica-heat-tran/221384?noredirect=1#comment575487_221384)
which desccribes a similar problem but in cylindrical coordinates

**NOTE** The constant $\beta$ used in the code below is the same as $\zeta$ in the preceding part of this question.

```
pde = D[T[x, y], x, x] + D[T[x, y], y, y] == 0
T[x_, y_] = X[x] Y[y]
pde/T[x, y] // Expand
xeq = X''[x]/X[x] == -a^2
DSolve[xeq, X[x], x] // Flatten
X[x_] = X[x] /. % /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}
yeq = Y''[y]/Y[y] == a^2
DSolve[yeq, Y[y], y] // Flatten
Y[y_] = (Y[y] /. % /. {C[1] -> c3, C[2] -> c4})
T[x_, y_] = Xp[x] + Yp[y]
xpeq = Xp''[x] == b
DSolve[xpeq, Xp[x], x] // Flatten
Xp[x_] = Xp[x] /. % /. {C[1] -> c5, C[2] -> c6}
ypeq = Yp''[y] + b == 0
DSolve[ypeq, Yp[y], y] // Flatten
Yp[y_] = Yp[y] /. % /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> c7}
T[x_, y_] = X[x] Y[y] + Xp[x] + Yp[y]
pde // FullSimplify
(D[T[x, y], x] /. x -> 0) == 0
c6 = 0
c2 = 0
c1 = 1
(D[T[x, y], x] /. x -> L) == 0
b = 0
a = (n π)/L
$Assumptions = n \[Element] Integers
(D[T[x, y], y] /. y -> 0) == γ
c4 = c4 /. Solve[Coefficient[%[[1]], Cos[(π n x)/L]] == 0, c4][[1]]
c7 = c7 /. Solve[c7 == γ, c7][[1]]
T[x, y] // Collect[#, c3] &
T[x, y] /. n -> 0
T0[x_, y_] = % /. c3 -> 0
Tn[x_, y_] = T[x, y] - T0[x, y] // Simplify
pdet = (t'[x] + α (t[x] - T[x, l]) == 0)
pde2 = (tn'[x] + α (tn[x] - Tn[x, l]) == 0)
(DSolve[pde2, tn[x], x] // Flatten)
tn[x_] = (tn[x] /. % /. C[1] -> c8)
pde20 = t0'[x] + α (t0[x] - T0[x, l]) == 0
DSolve[pde20, t0[x], x] // Flatten
t0[x_] = t0[x] /. % /. C[1] -> c80
c8 = c8 /. Solve[tn[0] == 0, c8][[1]]
c80 = c80 /. Solve[t0[0] == tin, c80][[1]]
tn[x_] = tn[x] // Simplify
t[x_] = t0[x] + tn[x]
pdet // Simplify
bcf = (D[T[x, y], y] /. y -> l) == β (T[x, l] - t[x])
bcf[[1]] /. n -> 0
bcf[[2]] /. n -> 0 // Simplify
bcfn0 = % == %% /. {2 c3 + c5 -> c30}
Integrate[bcfn0[[1]], {x, 0, L}] == Integrate[bcfn0[[2]], {x, 0, L}]
c5 = c30 /. Solve[%, c30][[1]] // Simplify
ortheq = Integrate[bcf[[1]]*Cos[(n*Pi*x)/L], {x, 0, L}] == Integrate[bcf[[2]]*Cos[(n*Pi*x)/L], {x, 0, L}]
c3 = c3 /. Solve[%, c3][[1]] // Simplify
t0[x_] = t0[x] // Simplify
tn[x_] = tn[x] // Simplify
T0[x_, y_] = T0[x, y] // Simplify
Tn[x_, y_] = Tn[x, y] // Simplify
```

Now using values and doing the summation

```
α = 57.487;
β = 4.6333;
γ = 10.5673;
tin = 300;
L = 0.03;
l = 0.006;
T[x_, y_, mm_] := T0[x, y] + Sum[Tn[x, y], {n, 1, mm}]
t[x_, mm_] := t0[x] + Sum[tn[x], {n, 1, mm}]
```

On plotting `T[x,y]` that is the solid temperature along the flow length at different `y` using `mm=20` Fourier terms using

```
Plot[{Evaluate[T[x, 0, 20]], Evaluate[T[x, l/2, 20]], Evaluate[T[x, l, 20]]}, {x, 0, L}]
```

, I get the following plot

[image]

As can be seen the solid temperature decreases along the length. This is nonphysical since it should increase along the flow length as the wall is getting heated from the bottom ($y=0$). Although interstingly the fluid temperature $t$ shows the correct behaviour as  can be seen from the plot below

[image]

For a different set of constant values corresponding to a steel plate (the one above is for a copper plate) the `T[x,y]` plate shows an increase but weirdly oscillates

```
α = 57.487;
β = 257.313;
γ = 263.643;
tin = 300;
L = 0.06;
l = 0.001;
```

[image]

Comment: You're using finite Fourier transform in wrong way. To understand which type of problem can be solved with finite Fourier transform, please check the properties of finite Fourier transform carefully. However, even if you've used finite Fourier transform correctly, I doubt if the technique will help in this case. In short, eq $(5)$ is on the way.

Comment: @xzczd Appreciate the input. However, I could not understand the last line of your comment. Do you mean to say that due to presence of Eq. $(5)$, Fin.FT cannot be used ? If so, can you suggest a different way to solve the Laplacian coupled with $(5)$ subjected to bcs $(1), (2), (4)$.

Comment: To be precise, finite FT can be used to eliminate derivatives, but the result will be a system consists of 2 equations involving summations and integrals, which is almost useless. Sadly I can't think out a way to solve this problem analytically.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks anyway.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra I don't understand why are you talking about analytical solution while using numerical method with series?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I am pursuing a series solution. In other words, I do not want to use FEM of FDM but get the temperature distributions in the form of fourier series.

Answer (score 4):

To verifier analytical solution we use numerical model:

```
reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {L, l}]; \[Alpha] = 57.487;
\[Zeta] = \[Beta] = 4.6333;
\[Gamma] = 10.5673;
ti = 300;
L = 0.03;
l = 0.006;

Ti[0][x_] := ti;
Do[U[i] = 
  NDSolveValue[-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 
    NeumannValue[- \[Zeta] (u[x, y] - Ti[i - 1][x]) y/
        l + \[Gamma] (1 - y/l), y == 0 || y == l], 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] reg];
 Ti[i] = NDSolveValue[{t'[x] + \[Alpha] (t[x] - U[i][x, l]) == 0, 
    t[0] == ti}, t, {x, 0, L}];
 , {i, 1, 50}]
```

The fluid temperature visualization on last 11 iterations  and on 50 iterations in one point `x=L/2`

```
{Plot[Evaluate[Table[Ti[i][x], {i, 40, 50}]], {x, 0, L}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot[Evaluate[Table[Ti[i][L/2], {i, 1, 50}]], PlotRange -> All]}
```

So 20 iteration could be good to solve this problem. We can check that fluid temperature behaves as an analytical solution.
[image: Figure 1]

Plate temperature visualization

```
{DensityPlot[U[50][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> Automatic], 
 Plot[{U[50][x, l], U[50][x, l/2], U[50][x, 0]}, {x, 0, L}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 Plot[{U[50][0, y], U[50][L/2, y], U[50][L, y]}, {y, 0, l}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

For second set of data we need some mesh and 10 iterations only:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {L, l}];


\[Alpha] = 57.487;
\[Zeta] = \[Beta] = 257.313;
\[Gamma] = 263.643;
tin = 300;
L = 0.06;
l = 0.001;

Ti[0][x_] := ti;
Do[U[i] = 
  NDSolveValue[-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 
    NeumannValue[- \[Zeta] (u[x, y] - Ti[i - 1][x]) y/
        l + \[Gamma] (1 - y/l), y == 0 || y == l], 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] reg];
 Ti[i] = NDSolveValue[{t'[x] + \[Alpha] (t[x] - U[i][x, l]) == 0, 
    t[0] == ti}, t, {x, 0, L}];
 , {i, 1, 10}]

{Plot[Evaluate[Table[Ti[i][x], {i, 1, 10}]], {x, 0, L}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot[Evaluate[Table[Ti[i][L/2], {i, 1, 10}]], PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 3]

```
{DensityPlot[U[10][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] reg, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> Automatic], 
 Plot[{U[10][x, l], U[10][x, l/2], U[10][x, 0]}, {x, 0, L}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 Plot[{U[10][0, y], U[10][L/2, y], U[10][L, y]}, {y, 0, l}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 4]

Comment: Thanks for this. It now seems that the boundary conditions are correctly set because the behavior of the temperatures in the numerical solution seem correct. The wall temperatures rise along the flow direction and the highest wall temperatures can be found at the bottom of the plate (`y=0`). This certainly helped. But I still cannot understand where did I go wrong in my analytical approach as I keep on getting unphysical behaviour there.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra I used method of   iterations . As equivalent method we can use method of false transient with $\partial_t$ in equation (5) to get an analytical solution.

Comment: I am afraid I am not aware of the method of false transient. Is there any chance you can solve this problem using it and post a solution. I am sorry if it is too much to ask.

Answer (score 2):

I executed your code and used your data and I can find nothing wrong, although I get a different plot for `T[x,y]`.

```
Plot[{Evaluate[T[x, 0, 50]], Evaluate[T[x, l/2, 50]], 
  Evaluate[T[x, l, 50]]}, {x, 0, L}]
```

[image]

It is different than your post, but it is with your posted code.  My plot for `t[x]` is the same as yours.

Checking your boundary conditions.

at `x = 0`

```
D[T0[x, y], x] /. x -> 0
D[Tn[x, y], x] /. x -> 0
```

both return 0

at `x = L`

```
dtn = D[Tn[x, y], x] /. x -> L

Table[dtn /. y -> 0, {n, 1, 10}]
{-1.37357*10^-15, 2.30234*10^-16, -1.13824*10^-16, 
 3.15585*10^-17, -1.93063*10^-17, 5.99123*10^-18, -3.93119*10^-18, 
 1.28056*10^-18, -8.7099*10^-19, 2.91729*10^-19}

Table[dtn /. y -> l/2, {n, 1, 10}]
{-1.44192*10^-15, 2.77195*10^-16, -1.68232*10^-16, 
 5.99327*10^-17, -4.84429*10^-17, 2.01841*10^-17, -1.79418*10^-17, 
 7.95632*10^-18, -7.38651*10^-18, 3.3817*10^-18}

Table[dtn /. y -> l, {n, 1, 10}]
{-1.65374*10^-15, 4.37237*10^-16, -3.83469*10^-16, 
 1.96078*10^-16, -2.23798*10^-16, 1.30007*10^-16, -1.5984*10^-16, 
 9.75869*10^-17, -1.24413*10^-16, 7.81094*10^-17}
```

All approximately `0` for machine precision.

At `y = 0`

```
D[T[x, y, 50], y] /. y -> 0
(*10.5673*)
```

which returns γ

and finally at `y = l`

```
Plot[{D[T[x, y, 50], y] /. 
   y -> l, β (T[x, l, 50] - t[x, 50])}, {x, 0, L}]
```

[image]

Since the two curves almost overlay each other, I would say you have a boundary match here too.

So it looks like the differential equations with their b.c.'s have been solved correctly.  If you still think there is something wrong, you may want to check for errors in the boundary conditions themselves.

Comment: Really appreciate this input. It certainly seems now that the equations have been solved correctly given the bc(s) are correct. The constant values I utilized correspond to a copper plate. When I do the same for a steel plate I get a different solid temperature plot which is increasing as expected but shows quite some oscillations. I have added it to my original question, Thanks anyway for taking this effort. You have always been really helpful.

Comment: I will now take a look at my equations. Probably the fluid equation $(5)$ should not have $T(x,l)$ but instead must have some sort of average solid temperature like $\int_o^l \frac{T(x,y)}{l}\mathrm{d}y$

Comment: Looking at Alex Tounev's posted numerical approach, it seems that the bcs and the equations are correctly setup. I think I have made some mistake in my analytical procedure which upends the results

Comment: When I plot the 4th bc as `Plot[{D[U[50][x, y], y] /. 
   y -> l, \[Zeta] (U[50][x, l] - Ti[50][x])}, {x, 0, L}]` the two curves don't match.  In fact, one is the negative of the other, similar to the two solutions.

Comment: yes I re-run the calculation and you are right. Frankly speaking at the risk of sounding ignorant, I am just confused now. None of my problems seem to work out, even the recent one I have posted. That said, thank you for your observations Bill. They do help.

Comment: It still looks like your solution is correct as far as solving the differential equations and the bc's in this case.  The calculated behavior is puzzling though.