# Three dimensional Laplacian insulated on lateral faces and convectively exposed on transverse faces (updated)

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, boundary-conditions, heat-equation

I have the three dimensional Laplacian $\nabla^2 T(x,y,z)=0$ representing temperature distribution in a cuboid shaped wall which is exposed to two fluids flowing perpendicular to each other on either of the $z$ faces i.e. at $z=0$ (ABCD) and $z=w$ (EFGH). Rest all the faces are insulated i.e. $x=0,L$ and $y=0,l$. The following figure depicts the situation.[image]

The boundary conditions on the lateral faces are therefore:

$$-k\frac{\partial T(0,y,z)}{\partial x}=-k\frac{\partial T(L,y,z)}{\partial x}=-k\frac{\partial T(x,0,z)}{\partial y}=-k\frac{\partial T(x,l,z)}{\partial y}=0 \tag 1$$

The bc(s) on the two z-faces are robin type and of the following form:

$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,0)}{\partial z} = p_c\bigg(T(x,y,0)-e^{-b_c y/l}\left[t_{ci} + \frac{b_c}{l}\int_0^y e^{b_c s/l}T(x,s,0)ds\right]\bigg) \tag 2$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,w)}{\partial z} = p_h\bigg(e^{-b_h x/L}\left[t_{hi} + \frac{b_h}{L}\int_0^x e^{b_h s/L}T(x,s,w)ds\right]-T(x,y,w)\bigg) \tag 3$$

$t_{hi}, t_{ci}, b_h, b_c, p_h, p_c, k$ are all constants $>0$.

I have two questions:

**(1)** With the insulated conditions mentioned in $(1)$ does a solution exist for this system?

**(2)** Can someone help in solving this analytically ?
I tried to solve this using the following approach (separation of variables) but encountered the results which I describe below (in short I attain a *trivial solution*):

I will include the codes for help:

```
T[x_, y_, z_] = (C1*E^(γ z) + C2 E^(-γ z))*
  Cos[n π x/L]*Cos[m π y/l] (*Preliminary T based on homogeneous Neumann x,y faces *)

tc[x_, y_] = 
  E^(-bc*y/l)*(tci + (bc/l)*
      Integrate[E^(bc*s/l)*T[x, s, 0], {s, 0, y}]);
bc1 = (D[T[x, y, z], z] /. z -> 0) == pc (T[x, y, 0] - tc[x, y]);
ortheq1 = 
 Integrate[(bc1[[1]] - bc1[[2]])*Cos[n π x/L]*
     Cos[m π y/l], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}, 
    Assumptions -> {L > 0, l > 0, bc > 0, pc > 0, tci > 0, 
      n ∈ Integers && n > 0, 
      m ∈ Integers && m > 0}] == 0 // Simplify

th[x_, y_] = 
  E^(-bh*x/L)*(thi + (bh/L)*
      Integrate[E^(bh*s/L)*T[s, y, w], {s, 0, x}]);
bc2 = (D[T[x, y, z], z] /. z -> w) == ph (th[x, y] - T[x, y, w]);
ortheq2 = 
 Integrate[(bc2[[1]] - bc2[[2]])*Cos[n π x/L]*
     Cos[m π y/l], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}, 
    Assumptions -> {L > 0, l > 0, bc > 0, pc > 0, tci > 0, 
      n ∈ Integers && n > 0, 
      m ∈ Integers && m > 0}] == 0 // Simplify

soln = Solve[{ortheq1, ortheq2}, {C1, C2}];
CC1 = C1 /. soln[[1, 1]];
CC2 = C2 /. soln[[1, 2]];
expression1 := CC1;
c1[n_, m_, L_, l_, bc_, pc_, tci_, bh_, ph_, thi_, w_] := 
  Evaluate[expression1];
expression2 := CC2;
c2[n_, m_, L_, l_, bc_, pc_, tci_, bh_, ph_, thi_, w_] := 
  Evaluate[expression2];

γ1[n_, m_] := Sqrt[(n π/L)^2 + (m π/l)^2];
```

I have used `Cos[n π x/L]*Cos[m π y/l]` considering the homogeneous Neumann condition on the lateral faces i.e. $x$ and $y$ faces.

Declaring some constants and then carrying out the summation:

```
m0 = 30; n0 = 30;
L = 0.025; l = 0.025; w = 0.003; bh = 0.433; bc = 0.433; ph = 65.24; \
pc = 65.24;
thi = 120; tci = 30;
Vn = Sum[(c1[n, m, L, l, bc, pc, tci, bh, ph, thi, w]*
       E^(γ1[n, m]*z) + 
      c2[n, m, L, l, bc, pc, tci, bh, ph, thi, w]*
       E^(-γ1[n, m]*z))*Cos[n π x/L]*Cos[m π y/l], {n, 
    1, n0}, {m, 1, m0}];
```

On executing an plotting at `z=0` using `Plot3D[Vn /. z -> 0, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}]` I get the following:

[image]

which is basically 0. On looking further I found that the constants `c1, c2` evaluate to `0` for any value of `n,m`.

**More specifically I would like to know if some limiting solution could be developed to circumvent the problem of the constants evaluating to zero**

---

**Origins of the b.c.**$2,3$

Actual bc(s): $$\frac{\partial T(x,y,0)}{\partial z}=p_c (T(x,y,0)-t_c) \tag 4$$
$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,w)}{\partial z}=p_h (t_h-T(x,y,w))\tag 5$$

where $t_h,t_c$ are defined in the equation:

$$\frac{\partial t_c}{\partial y}+\frac{b_c}{l}(t_c-T(x,y,0))=0 \tag 6$$
$$\frac{\partial t_h}{\partial x}+\frac{b_h}{L}(t_h-T(x,y,0))=0 \tag 7$$

$$t_h=e^{-b_h x/L}\bigg(t_{hi} + \frac{b_h}{L}\int_0^x e^{b_h s/L}T(x,s,w)ds\bigg) \tag 8$$

$$t_c=e^{-b_c y/l}\bigg(t_{ci} + \frac{b_c}{l}\int_0^y e^{b_c s/l}T(x,s,0)ds\bigg) \tag 9$$

It is known that $t_h(x=0)=t_{hi}$ and $t_c(y=0)=t_{ci}$. I had solved $6,7$ using the method of integrating factors and used the given conditions to reach $8,9$ which were then substituted into the original b.c.(s) $4,5$ to reach $2,3$.

---

**Non-dimensional formulation**
The non-dimensional version of the problem can be written as:

(In this section $x,y,z$ are non-dimensional; $x=x'/L,y=y'/l,z=z'/w, \theta=\frac{t-t_{ci}}{t_{hi}-t_{ci}}$)

Also, $\beta_h=h_h (lL)/C_h, \beta_c=h_c (lL)/C_c$ (However, this information might not be needed)

$$\lambda_h \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial x^2}+\lambda_c \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial y^2}+\lambda_z \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial z^2}=0 \tag A$$

In $(A)$ $\lambda_h=1/L^2, \lambda_c=1/l^2, \lambda_z=1/w^2$

$$\frac{\partial \theta_h}{\partial x}+\beta_h (\theta_h-\theta_w) = 0 \tag B$$

$$\frac{\partial \theta_c}{\partial y} + \beta_c (\theta_c-\theta_w) = 0 \tag C$$

The z-boundary condition then becomes:

$$\frac{\partial \theta_w(x,y,0)}{\partial z}=r_c (\theta_w(x,y,0)-\theta_c) \tag D$$
$$\frac{\partial \theta_w(x,y,w)}{\partial z}=r_h (\theta_h-\theta_w(x,y,w))\tag E$$

$$\theta_h(0,y)=1, \theta_c(x,0)=0$$

Here $r_h,r_c$ are non-dimensional quantities ($r_c=\frac{h_c w}{k}, r_h=\frac{h_h w}{k}$).

Comment: The thing I notice is if you look at the simplified result of `ortheq1`, the only way it can be true is if `C1 + C2 = 0` and `C1 - C2 = 0` which of course means that both must be zero.  It doesn't matter what happens after that, so you might examine the bc going into `ortheq1`

Comment: @BillWatts appreciate the observation. I too had a similar doubt because while solving the system by hand I encountered a `0=0` situation while applying the orthogonality. This happens because of the `Cos[n π x/L]*Cos[m π y/l]` functions in the preliminary `T` distribution. So when we multiply with `Cos[k π x/L]*Cos[j π y/l]` on both sides and integrate the integrals vanish. This makes me doubt my preliminary `T` distribution. Can you comment on whether the form `T[x_, y_, z_] = (C1*E^(γ z) + C2 E^(-γ z))*Cos[n π x/L]*Cos[m π y/l]` is a correct assumption ? I hope I could make myself clear.

Comment: It certainly seems that the system should have a unique solution because the net flux across all the boundaries is zero (homogeneous Neumann on `x,y` faces and energy transferred from one to the other fluid is equal through the `z` faces). Additionally, after reading your comment I tried the problem with swapped signs in the RHS of `bc1` but came to the same result.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra Why you are talking  about analytical solution while try to get numerical solution in the form of series?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Sir, probably my choice of words have been wrong. I was aiming for a solution using the method of separation of variables whose results are in the form of series. In other words, I am aiming to evaluate the three temperature fields $T,t_h,t_c$ in the form of a series solution.

Comment: Your C's have to be different for each piece.  For T00 I used C100 and C200.  For Tm0 I used C1m0 and C2m0 etc.  Just as before when we only a single sum we changed c8 to c80 for the n = 0 case.  Unfortunately when I did it, I still get zeros for all the c's except for T00 and then it doesn't match the bc's.  You might try the Math Stack Exch to see if they have any ideas.

Comment: @BillWatts Thanks a lot for all the effort you put in. Nevertheless, I would still request you to add the code to your answer below. I will try to build on it. Additionally, I actually tried asking on MSE but unfortunately got no response

Comment: @BillWatts Also, i managed to recast this problem in 2 dimensions. Obviously that lead to a more complicated BVP, but I asked it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226562/can-this-boundary-value-problem-leading-to-a-partio-integral-de-be-solved-using). You can have a look if you want. Just if you are interested, these set of equations describe a cross-flow heat exchanger. which I guess you might have figured out.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra  I have, finally, obtaining a formal solution.  Unfortunately, it does not converge well for the parameters I have tried.  What parameters would you like?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you so much! Since I am unsure about which version you used for your solution (dimensional or non-dimensional), may I know which set of parameters I should supply ? Is it `L,l,w,tci,thi,bh,bc,ph,pc` ?

Comment: @IndrasisMitra  Non-dimensional, with all parameters set equal to unity.

Comment: @bbgodfrey You may try with this set `bh=bc=0.433,rc=rh=0.195`. In any case,  I will ask you to still post your solution. It might be more easier to comprehend.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I did not encounter the $\lambda_z$ parameter in my formulation. But you can use these parameter values `λh=λc=0.0118, λz=0.8162`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Another set of parameters can be `bh=bc=2.065, rh=rc=0.861, λx=λy=0.0118, λz=0.8162 `. These parameters correspond to a miniaturized  steel ($k=16W/mK$) wall where $L=l=25 \ mm, w=3 \ mm$ with water ($c_p=4178 \ J/kgK $) flowing on either side with a mass flow rate of 0.9775 gm/sec.The heat transfer  coefficient ($h$) is set to 4590 W/sq. m K.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra  It turned out that the convergence problems I mentioned to you yesterday were due a coding error, now corrected.  So, I set all parameters to unity as my test case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem Statement**

For notational simplicity, use the non-dimensional formulation described near the end of the question.  (Doing so also facilitates comparison with results of a [2D approximation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235979/1063) solved earlier.)  The PDE is given by

```
λh D[θw[x, y, z], x, x] + λc D[θw[x, y, z], y, y] + λz D[θw[x, y, z], z, z] == 0
```

over the domain `{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}`.  Normal derivatives vanish on the `x` and `y` boundaries.  Conditions on the `z` boundaries are given by

```
(D[θw[x, y, z], z] + rh (θw[x, y, z] - θwh[x, y]) == 0) /. z -> 1
(D[θw[x, y, z], z] - rh (θw[x, y, z] - θwc[x, y]) == 0) /. z -> 0
```

with `θwc` and `θwh` specified by

```
D[θwh[x, y], x] + bh (θw[x, y, 1] - θwh[x, y]) == 0
θwh[0, y] == 1
D[θwc[x, y], y] + bc (θw[x, y, 0] - θwh[x, y]) == 0
θwc[x, 0] = 0
```

Although the solution of the PDE itself can be expressed as a sum of trigonometric functions, the `z` boundary conditions couple what otherwise would be separable eigenfunctions.

**Coupling Coefficients**

The coupling coefficients in question are given by

```
DSolveValue[{D[θc[y], y] + b (θc[y] - 1) == 0, θc[0] == 0}, θc[y], y] // Simplify
a00 = Simplify[Integrate[% , {y, 0, 1}]]
an0 = Simplify[Integrate[%% 2 Cos[n π y], {y, 0, 1}], Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers]
(* 1 - E^(-b y) *)
(* (-1 + b + E^-b)/b *)
(* -((2 b E^-b ((-1)^(1 + n) + E^b))/(b^2 + n^2 π^2)) *)

DSolveValue[{D[θc[y], y] + b (θc[y] - Cos[m Pi y]) == 0, θc[0] == 0}, θc[y], y] // Simplify
a0m = Simplify[Integrate[%, {y, 0, 1}], Assumptions -> m ∈ Integers]
amm = Simplify[Integrate[%% 2 Cos[m π y], {y, 0, 1}], Assumptions -> m ∈ Integers]
anm = FullSimplify[Integrate[%%% 2 Cos[n π y], {y, 0, 1}], Assumptions -> (m | n) ∈ Integers]
(* (b (-b E^(-b y) + b Cos[m π y] + m π Sin[m π y]))/(b^2 + m^2 π^2) *)
(* (b ((-1)^(1 + m) + E^-b))/(b^2 + m^2) *) *)
(* (b^2 E^-b (b^2 E^b + 2 b ((-1)^m - E^b) + E^b m^2 π^2))/(b^2 + m^2 π^2)^2 *)
(* (E^-b (2 (-1)^n b^3 (m - n) (m + n) + 2 b E^b (n^2 (b^2 + m^2 π^2) + (-1)^(1 + m + n)
    m^2 (b^2 + n^2 π^2))))/((m - n) (m + n) (b^2 + m^2 π^2) (b^2 + n^2 π^2)) *)

a[nn_?IntegerQ, mm_?IntegerQ] := Which[nn == 0 && mm == 0, a00, mm == 0, an0, nn == 0, a0m, 
    nn == mm, amm, True, anm] /. {n -> nn, m -> mm}
```

**General Solution**

Express the solution as a sum of eigenfunctions in the absence of the `z` boundary conditions.

```
λh D[θw[x, y, z], x, x] + λc D[θw[x, y, z], y, y] + λz D[θw[x, y, z], z, z];
Simplify[(% /. θw -> Function[{x, y, z}, Cos[nh Pi x] Cos[nc Pi y] θwz[z]])/
    (Cos[nh Pi x] Cos[nc Pi y])] /. π^2 (nc^2 λc + nh^2 λh) -> k[nh, nc]^2 λz
Flatten@DSolveValue[% == 0, θwz[z], z] /. {C[1] -> c1[nh, nc], C[2] -> c2[nh, nc]}
(* -λz k[nh, nc]^2 θwz[z] + λz (θwz''[z] *)
(* E^(z k[nh, nc]) c1[nh, nc] + E^(-z k[nh, nc]) c2[nh, nc] *)
```

as expected.  Note that `k[nh, nc] = Sqrt[π^2 (nc^2 λc + nh^2 λh)/λz]` has been introduced for notational simplicity.  Although the result above for `θwz` is correct, rearranging the terms a bit is helpful in what follows.

```
sz = c2[nh, nc] Sinh[k[nh, nc] z]/Cosh[k[nh, nc]] + 
   c1[nh, nc] Sinh[k[nh, nc] (1 - z)]/Sinh[k[nh, nc]];
```

because `sz /. z -> 0`, needed in the `z = 0` boundary condition, reduces to `c1[nh, nc]`.  Next, use that boundary condition to eliminate `c2[nh, nc]`.

```
sθc[nh_?IntegerQ, nc_?IntegerQ] := Sum[a[nc, m] c1[nh, m], {m, 0, maxc}] /. b -> bc;
(D[sz, z] == rc (sz - sθc[nh, nc])) /. z -> 0;
Solve[%, c2[nh, nc]] // Flatten // Apart;
sz1 = Simplify[sz /. %] // Apart
(* (c1[nh, nc] (Cosh[z k[nh, nc]] k[nh, nc] + rc Sinh[z k[nh, nc]]))/k[nh, nc] 
   - (rc Sinh[z k[nh, nc]] sθc[nh, nc])/k[nh, nc] *)
```

Finally, use the `z = 1` boundary condition to produce a matrix equation for `c[nh, nc]`.

```
szθh[nh_?IntegerQ, nc_?IntegerQ] := Evaluate[sz1 /. z -> 1]
sθh[nh_?IntegerQ, nc_?IntegerQ] := Evaluate[Sum[a[nh, m] szθh[m, nc], {m, 0, maxh}]]
eq = Simplify[(D[sz1, z] + rh (sz1 - sθh[nh, nc])) /. z -> 1] -
    rh (DiscreteDelta[nh] - a[nh, 0]) DiscreteDelta[nc]
(* -rh DiscreteDelta[nc] (-a[nh, 0] + DiscreteDelta[nh]) + (1/k[nh, nc])
   (c1[nh, nc] ((rc + rh) Cosh[k[nh, nc]] k[nh, nc] + rc rh Sinh[k[nh, nc]] + 
   k[nh, nc]^2 Sinh[k[nh, nc]]) - rc rh Sinh[k[nh, nc]] sθc[nh, nc] - 
   k[nh, nc] (rc Cosh[k[nh, nc]] sθc[nh, nc] + rh sθh[nh, nc])) *)
```

The source term `rh (DiscreteDelta[nh] - a[nh, 0]) DiscreteDelta[nc]` arises from `θwh[0, y] == 1` instead of equaling zero.

Specific solution for Parameters Set to Unity.

```
maxh = 3; maxc = 3; λh = 1; λc = 1; λz = 1; bh = 1; bc = 1; rh = 1; rc = 1;
ks = Flatten@Table[k[nh, nc] -> Sqrt[π^2 (nc^2 λc + nh^2 λh)/λz], 
    {nh, 0, maxh}, {nc, 0, maxc}]
eql = N[Collect[Flatten@Table[eq /. Sinh[k[0, 0]] -> k[0, 0], {nh, 0, maxh}, {nc, 0, maxc}]
    /. b -> bh, _c1, Simplify] /. ks] /. c1[z1_, z2_] :> Rationalize[c1[z1, z2]];
(* {k[0, 0] -> 0, k[0, 1] -> π, k[0, 2] -> 2 π, k[0, 3] -> 3 π, k[1, 0] -> π, 
    k[1, 1] -> Sqrt[2] π, k[1, 2] -> Sqrt[5] π, k[1, 3] -> Sqrt[10] π, k[2, 0] -> 2 π,
    k[2, 1] -> Sqrt[5] π, k[2, 2] -> 2 Sqrt[2] π, k[2, 3] -> Sqrt[13] π, 
    k[3, 0] -> 3 π, k[3, 1] -> Sqrt[10] π, k[3, 2] -> Sqrt[13] π, k[3, 3] -> 3 Sqrt[2] π} *)
```

`eql` the numericized version of `eq` is too long to reproduce here.  And, trying to solve `eq` itself is far too slow.  Next, compute the `c1` and from them the solution.

```
Union@Cases[eql, _c1, Infinity];
coef = NSolve[Thread[eql == 0], %] // Flatten
sol = Total@Simplify[Flatten@Table[sz1 Cos[nh Pi x] Cos[nc Pi y] /. 
    Sinh[z k[0, 0]] -> z k[0, 0], {nh, 0, maxh}, {nc, 0, maxc}], Trig -> False] /. ks /. %;
(* {c1[0, 0] -> 0.3788, c1[0, 1] -> -0.0234913, c1[0, 2] -> -0.00123552, 
    c1[0, 3] -> -0.00109202, c1[1, 0] -> 0.00168554, c1[1, 1] -> -0.0000775391, 
    c1[1, 2] -> -5.40917*10^-6, c1[1, 3] -> -4.63996*10^-6, c1[2, 0] -> 4.19045*10^-6, 
    c1[2, 1] -> -1.24251*10^-7, c1[2, 2] -> -1.17696*10^-8, c1[2, 3] -> -1.02576*10^-8, 
    c1[3, 0] -> 1.65131*10^-7, c1[3, 1] -> -3.41814*10^-9, c1[3, 2] -> 3.86348*10^-10, 
    c1[3, 3] -> -3.48432*10^-10} *)
```

Here are several plots of the solution, beginning with a 3D contour plot.

```
ContourPlot3D[sol, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, Contours -> {.4, .5, .6}, 
    ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.75], PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.9, .9}], 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Next are slices through the solution at the ends and mid-point in `z`.  The second, at `z = 1/2`, is similar to the seventh plot in the [2D thin slab approximation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235979/1063), even though the calculation here is for a cube.

```
Plot3D[sol /. z -> 0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, "θw(z=0)"}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

```
 Plot3D[sol /. z -> 1/2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, "θw(z=0)"}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

```
 Plot3D[sol /. z -> 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, "θw(z=0)"}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Finally, here are `θwc` and `θwh`, each computed in two distinct ways, by the expansion given above and by direct integration using the expansion of `θw`.  (They differ in that the latter does not employ the `a` matrix.)  The two methods agree very well except at the edges in `y` and `x`, respectively, where convergence of the cosine series is nonuniform.  Increasing the number of modes reduces this modest disagreement but does not change `sol` by more than `10^-4`.

```
Simplify[(sol - D[sol, z]/rc) /. z -> 0, Trig -> False];
DSolveValue[{θwc'[y] + bc (θwc[y] - sol /. z -> 0) == 0, θwc[0] == 0}, 
    θwc[y], {y, 0, 1}] // Chop;
Plot3D[{%, %%}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, θwc}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

```
Simplify[(sol + D[sol, z]/rh) /. z -> 1, Trig -> False];
DSolveValue[{θwh'[x] + bh (θwh[x] - sol /. z -> 1) == 0, θwh[0] == 1}, 
    θwh[x], {x, 0, 1}] // Chop;
 Plot3D[{%, %%}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
     AxesLabel -> {x, y, θwh}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

The computation shown here required only a few minutes on my PC.

Comment: can't appreciate much how elegant this is. I will now go through the solution and revert.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra  I used the three `λ` merely to rescale the dimensions, so that `x`, `y`, and `z` would vary from zero to one.  Note that doing so also required rescaling `rc`,  `rh`, `bc`, and `bh`.  By the way, for some parameters it should be possible to obtain approximate symbolic solutions.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra  Although I do not have time now to run various other cases, I did correct a scaling error in the last two plots.

Comment: Much appreciated. The corrections you made sorted out the problems. Next, when the non-homogeneous b.c. at `z=1` is applied a source term is being added. The `DiscreteDelta[a]` function is being used which attains value `1` only when `a=0`. You use the expression `rh (DiscreteDelta[nh] - a[nh, 0]) DiscreteDelta[nc]` in your code which will attain different values based on `nh` and `nc` (More specifically it equals zero for all cases where `nc` is $\neq 0$). I can use some help in understanding the reason behind why this expression is structured the way it is.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra  The source term is `Exp[-b x]`.  A Fourier Cosine decomposition of this expression yields the expression `rh (DiscreteDelta[nh] - a[nh, 0]) DiscreteDelta[nc]`.  Hope this helps.  By the way, is is good practice to delete comments that no longer contribute to the discussion.  Best wishes.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra  Use `FourierCosSeries[Exp[-b x], x, maxh, FourierParameters -> {1, Pi}] // Simplify`.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra  Compare the two expressions term by term, and you will find that the coefficients are identical.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra  Yes, these are orthogonality relations.  Check any text on discrete Fourier transforms.  The last two plots above are measures of their accuracy.  The series converge, but not uniformly.  The are less accurate at the end points.

Comment: This is very late, I know but how are the index being manipulated in `sθc[nh_?IntegerQ, nc_?IntegerQ] := Sum[a[nc, m] c1[nh, m], {m, 0, maxc}]` and `sθh[nh_?IntegerQ, nc_?IntegerQ] := Evaluate[Sum[a[nh, m] szθh[m, nc], {m, 0, maxh}]]`. I mean for the `sθc` the coupling coeff.(s) run differently and with `sθh` the `nh` come first. How are the orders being determined. Also, `coupling coefficient*fourier coefficient` is the structure utilised to calculte these variables. Is this a general formula for such coupled variables? Sorry, if this sounds ignorant.

Comment: @Avrana  I shall not have time to think about this for a week or so.  Sorry.  If I do not get back to you, please remind me.  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey See my answer with comparison of your method with my method with maximal difference about 2.5 10^-3.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Excellent approach (+1); thanks for sharing.  Thanks, also, for solving the OP's other question (+1 again).  I would not have found time to do so for quite a while.  By the way, my expansion here converges but not uniformly.  I presume that yours does converge uniformly.  Is that so?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you! I have tested my algorithm for 2D and 3D Poisson's equation with known exact solution - see my paper attached to this post https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2457908 .  I will prepare  test for your method as well and continue my answer here.

Comment: @bbgodfrey This is a gentle reminder as per your request. If you are still busy, it is completley understandable. I must re-iterate that your answer is completley fine and works perfectly. It has been my lack of understnading that I want to tackle. Especially, the way the indices are being counted for `sθc` and `sθh`. Are they being written as matrices? Additionally while writing the `sθc, sθh` expressions, they have been written as `coupling*fourier coeff.`.

Comment: Also, upon much search, I have not come across any reference where a non-homogeneous b.c. has been modelled as a source term,as you have done here. This is something I would like to use for other problems. Is there any material available on this ? Please, only answer at your convenience.

Comment: @Avrana  Sorry for the slow response to your two comments.  Non-homogeneous b.c. are treated as source terms in some computations involving Green's Functions, and my solution above uses an analogous approach.  I have not found time to respond to your earlier comment, and it is doubtful that I shall in the near term for health reasons.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Much appreciated your present amswer. Please accept my well wishes for your health. You will be back up to speed soon.

Comment: @bbgodfrey How has your health been Mr. Godfrey ? I hope you have been allright.

Answer (score 5):

We can solve this problem with using method explained in my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262458/unbounded-solution-at-boundaries-with-few-combination-of-values-in-this-bvp-solu/262563?noredirect=1#comment654595_262563) and in my paper attached to this [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2457908). We solve in the unit cube system of equations

```
eq1 = λh D[θw[x, y, z], x, 
     x] + λc D[θw[x, y, z], y, 
     y] + λz D[θw[x, y, z], z, z] == 
  0; bc1 = {(D[θw[x, y, z], z] + 
      rh (θw[x, y, z] - θwh[x, y]) == 0) /. z -> 1,
  (D[θw[x, y, z], z] - 
      rc (θw[x, y, z] - θwc[x, y]) == 0) /. 
   z -> 0}; eq2 = 
 D[θwh[x, y], x] + 
   bh (θw[x, y, 1] - θwh[x, y]) == 0;
bc2 = θwh[0, y] == 1;
eq3 = D[θwc[x, y], y] - 
    bc (θw[x, y, 0] - θwc[x, y]) == 0;
bc3 = θwc[x, 0] == 0;
```

First we generate base functions and solution to the problem as follows

```
E[m_, t_] := Cos[m t] Exp[-m t]
nn = 5;
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; ycol = 
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, 
    nn + 1}]; zcol = ycol; Psijk = 
 Table[UE[n, t1], {n, 0, nn - 1}]; Int1 = Integrate[Psijk, t1];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y; M = nn;
M = nn; U1 = Array[a1, {M, M, M}]; U2 = Array[a2, {M, M, M}]; U3 = 
 Array[a3, {M, M, M}]; B1 = Array[b1, {M, M}]; B2 = 
 Array[b2, {M, M}]; B3 = Array[b3, {M, M}]; G1 = 
 Array[g1, {M, M}]; G2 = Array[g2, {M, M}]; G3 = 
 Array[g3, {M, M}]; G4 = Array[g4, {M, M}]; G5 = Array[g5, {M, M}];
H1 = Array[h1, {M}]; H2 = Array[h2, {M}];

thx[x_, y_] := (Psi[x] . G5 . Psi[y]); 
tcy[x_, y_] := (Psi[x] . G4 . Psi[y]); 
th[x_, y_] := (int1[x] . G5 . Psi[y]) + H2 . Psi[y]; 
tc[x_, y_] := (Psi[x] . G4 . int1[y]) + H1 . Psi[x];

u1[x_, y_, z_] := (int2[x] . U1 . Psi[y]) . Psi[z] + 
  x Psi[y] . G1 . Psi[z] + Psi[y] . B1 . Psi[z]; 
u2[x_, y_, z_] := (Psi[x] . U2 . int2[y]) . Psi[z] + 
  y Psi[x] . G2 . Psi[z] + Psi[x] . B2 . Psi[z]; 
u3[x_, y_, z_] := (Psi[x] . U3 . Psi[y]) . int2[z] + 
  z Psi[x] . G3 . Psi[y] + Psi[x] . B3 . Psi[y]; 
uz[x_, y_, z_] := (Psi[x] . U3 . Psi[y]) . int1[z] + 
  Psi[x] . G3 . Psi[y];
uy[x_, y_, z_] := (Psi[x] . U2 . int1[y]) . Psi[z] + 
   Psi[x] . G2 . Psi[z];
ux[x_, y_, z_] := (int1[x] . U1 . Psi[y]) . Psi[z] + 
   Psi[y] . G1 . Psi[z];
uxx[x_, y_, z_] := (Psi[x] . U1 . Psi[y]) . Psi[z]; 
uyy[x_, y_, z_] := (Psi[x] . U2 . Psi[y]) . Psi[z];
uzz[x_, y_, z_] := (Psi[x] . U3 . Psi[y]) . Psi[z];
```

Parameters of the model, equations on the grid and variables definition

```
(*Another set of parameters can be \
bh=bc=2.065,rh=rc=0.861,\[Lambda]x=\[Lambda]y=0.0118,\[Lambda]z=0.\
8162.These parameters correspond to a miniaturized steel (k=16W/mK) \
wall where L=l=25 mm,w=3 mm with water (cp=4178 J/kgK) flowing on \
either side with a mass flow rate of 0.9775 gm/sec.The heat transfer \
coefficient (h) is set to 4590 W/sq.m K.*)
bh = bc = 2.065; rh = 
 rc = 0.861; λh = λc = 0.0118; λz = 0.8162;

eq = Join[
   Flatten[Table[(λh uxx[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]], 
          zcol[[k]]] + λc uyy[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]], 
          zcol[[k]]] + λz uzz[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]], 
          zcol[[k]]]) == 0, {i, M}, {j, M}, {k, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     u1[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]], zcol[[k]]] - 
       u2[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]], zcol[[k]]] == 0, {i, M}, {j, M}, {k, 
      M}]], Flatten[
    Table[u1[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]], zcol[[k]]] - 
       u3[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]], zcol[[k]]] == 0, {i, M}, {j, M}, {k, 
      M}]], Flatten[
    Table[ux[1, ycol[[i]], zcol[[j]]] == 0, {i, M}, {j, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[uy[xcol[[i]], 1, zcol[[j]]] == 0, {i, M}, {j, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[ux[0, ycol[[i]], zcol[[j]]] == 0, {i, M}, {j, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[uy[xcol[[i]], 0, zcol[[j]]] == 0, {i, M}, {j, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     uz[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]], 1] + 
       rh (u3[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]], 1] - th[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]]) == 
      0, {i, M}, {j, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     uz[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]], 0] - 
       rc (u3[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]], 0] - tc[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]]) == 
      0, {i, M}, {j, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     thx[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - 
       bh (u3[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]], 1] - th[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]]) == 
      0, {i, M}, {j, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     tcy[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - 
       bc (u3[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]], 0] - tc[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]]) == 
      0, {i, M}, {j, M}]], Table[th[0, ycol[[i]]] == 1., {i, M}], 
   Table[tc[xcol[[i]], 0] == 0., {i, M}]];
var = Join[Flatten[U1], Flatten[U2], Flatten[U3], Flatten[B1], 
   Flatten[B2], Flatten[B3], Flatten[G1], Flatten[G2], Flatten[G3], 
   Flatten[G4], Flatten[G5], H1, H2];
```

Solution and visualization

```
{v, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eq, var];

sol1 = LinearSolve[mat, -v];

rul = Table[var[[i]] -> sol1[[i]], {i, Length[var]}];

{Plot3D[Evaluate[tc[x, y] /. rul], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", MeshStyle -> White, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> \[Theta]c], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[th[x, y] /. rul], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", MeshStyle -> White, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> \[Theta]h], 
 Table[Plot3D[Evaluate[u1[x, y, z] /. rul], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", MeshStyle -> White, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> \[Theta]w[z]], {z, 0, 
   1, .2}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

We can compare this code with code developed by bbgodfrey above. But we need to change parameters as well

```
DSolveValue[{D[θc[y], y] + b (θc[y] - 1) == 
     0, θc[0] == 0}, θc[y], y] // Simplify;
a00 = Simplify[Integrate[%, {y, 0, 1}]];
an0 = Simplify[Integrate[%% 2 Cos[n π y], {y, 0, 1}], 
  Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers]; 
DSolveValue[{D[θc[y], y] + b (θc[y] - Cos[m Pi y]) == 
    0, θc[0] == 0}, θc[y], y] // Simplify;
a0m = Simplify[Integrate[%, {y, 0, 1}], 
   Assumptions -> m ∈ Integers];
amm = Simplify[Integrate[%% 2 Cos[m π y], {y, 0, 1}], 
   Assumptions -> m ∈ Integers];
anm = FullSimplify[Integrate[%%% 2 Cos[n π y], {y, 0, 1}], 
   Assumptions -> (m | n) ∈ Integers];
a[nn_?IntegerQ, mm_?IntegerQ] := 
  Which[nn == 0 && mm == 0, a00, mm == 0, an0, nn == 0, a0m, nn == mm,
     amm, True, anm] /. {n -> nn, m -> mm};

λh D[θw[x, y, z], x, 
    x] + λc D[θw[x, y, z], y, 
    y] + λz D[θw[x, y, z], z, z];
Simplify[(% /. θw -> 
       Function[{x, y, z}, 
        Cos[nh Pi x] Cos[nc Pi y] θwz[z]])/(Cos[nh Pi x] Cos[
       nc Pi y])] /. π^2 (nc^2 λc + nh^2 λh) -> 
   k[nh, nc]^2 λz;
Flatten@DSolveValue[% == 0, θwz[z], z] /. {C[1] -> c1[nh, nc], 
   C[2] -> c2[nh, nc]};


sz = c2[nh, nc] Sinh[k[nh, nc] z]/Cosh[k[nh, nc]] + 
  c1[nh, nc] Sinh[k[nh, nc] (1 - z)]/Sinh[k[nh, nc]]; 
sθc[nh_?IntegerQ, nc_?IntegerQ] := 
 Sum[a[nc, m] c1[nh, m], {m, 0, maxc}] /. b -> bc;
(D[sz, z] == rc (sz - sθc[nh, nc])) /. z -> 0;
Solve[%, c2[nh, nc]] // Flatten // Apart;
sz1 = Simplify[sz /. %] // Apart;

szθh[nh_?IntegerQ, nc_?IntegerQ] := Evaluate[sz1 /. z -> 1];
sθh[nh_?IntegerQ, nc_?IntegerQ] := 
  Evaluate[Sum[a[nh, m] szθh[m, nc], {m, 0, maxh}]];
eq = Simplify[(D[sz1, z] + rh (sz1 - sθh[nh, nc])) /. z -> 1] -
    rh (DiscreteDelta[nh] - a[nh, 0]) DiscreteDelta[nc];

maxh = 3; maxc = 3; λh = 1; λc = 1; λz = 1; \
bh = 1; bc = 1; rh = 1; rc = 1;
ks = Flatten@
   Table[k[nh, nc] -> 
     Sqrt[π^2 (nc^2 λc + 
          nh^2 λh)/λz], {nh, 0, maxh}, {nc, 0, maxc}];
eql = N[Collect[
      Flatten@Table[
         eq /. Sinh[k[0, 0]] -> k[0, 0], {nh, 0, maxh}, {nc, 0, 
          maxc}] /. b -> bh, _c1, Simplify] /. ks] /. 
   c1[z1_, z2_] :> Rationalize[c1[z1, z2]];
Union@Cases[eql, _c1, Infinity];
coef = NSolve[Thread[eql == 0], %] // Flatten;
sol = Total@
     Simplify[
      Flatten@Table[
        sz1 Cos[nh Pi x] Cos[nc Pi y] /. 
         Sinh[z k[0, 0]] -> z k[0, 0], {nh, 0, maxh}, {nc, 0, maxc}], 
      Trig -> False] /. ks /. %;
(*{c1[0,0]->0.3788,c1[0,1]->-0.0234913,c1[0,2]->-0.00123552,c1[0,3]->-\
0.00109202,c1[1,0]->0.00168554,c1[1,1]->-0.0000775391,c1[1,2]->-5.\
40917*10^-6,c1[1,3]->-4.63996*10^-6,c1[2,0]->4.19045*10^-6,c1[2,1]->-\
1.24251*10^-7,c1[2,2]->-1.17696*10^-8,c1[2,3]->-1.02576*10^-8,c1[3,0]->\
1.65131*10^-7,c1[3,1]->-3.41814*10^-9,c1[3,2]->3.86348*10^-10,c1[3,3]->\
-3.48432*10^-10}*)
```

Visualization

```
pl1 = Table[
  Plot3D[sol, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y}, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"z = ", z}]], {z, 0, 1, .2}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Numerical table for comparison on the grid

```
tab1 = 
 Table[{x, y, z, sol}, {x, 0, 1, .2}, {y, 0, 1, .2}, {z, 0, 1, .2}]

(*Out[]= {{{{0., 0., 0., 0.354583}, {0., 0., 0.2, 0.416427}, {0., 0., 
    0.4, 0.472633}, {0., 0., 0.6, 0.527367}, {0., 0., 0.8, 
    0.583573}, {0., 0., 1., 0.645417}}, {{0., 0.2, 0., 0.361377}, {0.,
     0.2, 0.2, 0.419296}, {0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.474032}, {0., 0.2, 0.6, 
    0.528107}, {0., 0.2, 0.8, 0.584005}, {0., 0.2, 1., 
    0.645725}}, {{0., 0.4, 0., 0.375098}, {0., 0.4, 0.2, 
    0.426074}, {0., 0.4, 0.4, 0.47755}, {0., 0.4, 0.6, 0.530014}, {0.,
     0.4, 0.8, 0.585128}, {0., 0.4, 1., 0.646529}}, {{0., 0.6, 0., 
    0.387889}, {0., 0.6, 0.2, 0.433593}, {0., 0.6, 0.4, 
    0.481704}, {0., 0.6, 0.6, 0.532322}, {0., 0.6, 0.8, 
    0.586504}, {0., 0.6, 1., 0.647516}}, {{0., 0.8, 0., 
    0.398835}, {0., 0.8, 0.2, 0.439582}, {0., 0.8, 0.4, 
    0.484998}, {0., 0.8, 0.6, 0.534165}, {0., 0.8, 0.8, 
    0.587608}, {0., 0.8, 1., 0.648311}}, {{0., 1., 0., 0.403914}, {0.,
     1., 0.2, 0.441963}, {0., 1., 0.4, 0.486258}, {0., 1., 0.6, 
    0.534865}, {0., 1., 0.8, 0.588028}, {0., 1., 1., 
    0.648613}}}, {{{0.2, 0., 0., 0.354275}, {0.2, 0., 0.2, 
    0.415995}, {0.2, 0., 0.4, 0.471893}, {0.2, 0., 0.6, 
    0.525968}, {0.2, 0., 0.8, 0.580704}, {0.2, 0., 1., 
    0.638623}}, {{0.2, 0.2, 0., 0.361064}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
    0.418862}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.473291}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 
    0.526709}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.581138}, {0.2, 0.2, 1., 
    0.638936}}, {{0.2, 0.4, 0., 0.374776}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 
    0.425637}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.476809}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 
    0.528616}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.582265}, {0.2, 0.4, 1., 
    0.639752}}, {{0.2, 0.6, 0., 0.38756}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 
    0.433153}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.480962}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.6, 
    0.530926}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.583645}, {0.2, 0.6, 1., 
    0.640754}}, {{0.2, 0.8, 0., 0.398498}, {0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 
    0.439139}, {0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 0.484255}, {0.2, 0.8, 0.6, 
    0.532769}, {0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.584753}, {0.2, 0.8, 1., 
    0.641561}}, {{0.2, 1., 0., 0.403574}, {0.2, 1., 0.2, 
    0.441519}, {0.2, 1., 0.4, 0.485515}, {0.2, 1., 0.6, 
    0.53347}, {0.2, 1., 0.8, 0.585174}, {0.2, 1., 1., 
    0.641868}}}, {{{0.4, 0., 0., 0.353471}, {0.4, 0., 0.2, 
    0.414872}, {0.4, 0., 0.4, 0.469986}, {0.4, 0., 0.6, 
    0.52245}, {0.4, 0., 0.8, 0.573926}, {0.4, 0., 1., 
    0.624902}}, {{0.4, 0.2, 0., 0.360248}, {0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 
    0.417735}, {0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.471384}, {0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 
    0.523191}, {0.4, 0.2, 0.8, 0.574363}, {0.4, 0.2, 1., 
    0.625224}}, {{0.4, 0.4, 0., 0.373936}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 
    0.424502}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.474899}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 
    0.525101}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.8, 0.575498}, {0.4, 0.4, 1., 
    0.626064}}, {{0.4, 0.6, 0., 0.3867}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 
    0.432008}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.47905}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 
    0.527413}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.576888}, {0.4, 0.6, 1., 
    0.627096}}, {{0.4, 0.8, 0., 0.397621}, {0.4, 0.8, 0.2, 
    0.437988}, {0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 0.482342}, {0.4, 0.8, 0.6, 
    0.529259}, {0.4, 0.8, 0.8, 0.578005}, {0.4, 0.8, 1., 
    0.627926}}, {{0.4, 1., 0., 0.402688}, {0.4, 1., 0.2, 
    0.440365}, {0.4, 1., 0.4, 0.483601}, {0.4, 1., 0.6, 
    0.52996}, {0.4, 1., 0.8, 0.578429}, {0.4, 1., 1., 
    0.628242}}}, {{{0.6, 0., 0., 0.352484}, {0.6, 0., 0.2, 
    0.413496}, {0.6, 0., 0.4, 0.467678}, {0.6, 0., 0.6, 
    0.518296}, {0.6, 0., 0.8, 0.566407}, {0.6, 0., 1., 
    0.612111}}, {{0.6, 0.2, 0., 0.359246}, {0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 
    0.416355}, {0.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0.469074}, {0.6, 0.2, 0.6, 
    0.519038}, {0.6, 0.2, 0.8, 0.566847}, {0.6, 0.2, 1., 
    0.61244}}, {{0.6, 0.4, 0., 0.372904}, {0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 
    0.423112}, {0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.472587}, {0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 
    0.52095}, {0.6, 0.4, 0.8, 0.567992}, {0.6, 0.4, 1., 
    0.6133}}, {{0.6, 0.6, 0., 0.385643}, {0.6, 0.6, 0.2, 
    0.430607}, {0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.476735}, {0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 
    0.523265}, {0.6, 0.6, 0.8, 0.569393}, {0.6, 0.6, 1., 
    0.614357}}, {{0.6, 0.8, 0., 0.396543}, {0.6, 0.8, 0.2, 
    0.436578}, {0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 0.480024}, {0.6, 0.8, 0.6, 
    0.525113}, {0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 0.570518}, {0.6, 0.8, 1., 
    0.615207}}, {{0.6, 1., 0., 0.4016}, {0.6, 1., 0.2, 
    0.438952}, {0.6, 1., 0.4, 0.481282}, {0.6, 1., 0.6, 
    0.525816}, {0.6, 1., 0.8, 0.570946}, {0.6, 1., 1., 
    0.615531}}}, {{{0.8, 0., 0., 0.351689}, {0.8, 0., 0.2, 
    0.412392}, {0.8, 0., 0.4, 0.465835}, {0.8, 0., 0.6, 
    0.515002}, {0.8, 0., 0.8, 0.560418}, {0.8, 0., 1., 
    0.601165}}, {{0.8, 0.2, 0., 0.358439}, {0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 
    0.415247}, {0.8, 0.2, 0.4, 0.467231}, {0.8, 0.2, 0.6, 
    0.515745}, {0.8, 0.2, 0.8, 0.560861}, {0.8, 0.2, 1., 
    0.601502}}, {{0.8, 0.4, 0., 0.372074}, {0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 
    0.421995}, {0.8, 0.4, 0.4, 0.470741}, {0.8, 0.4, 0.6, 
    0.517658}, {0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.562012}, {0.8, 0.4, 1., 
    0.602379}}, {{0.8, 0.6, 0., 0.384793}, {0.8, 0.6, 0.2, 
    0.429482}, {0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.474887}, {0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 
    0.519976}, {0.8, 0.6, 0.8, 0.563422}, {0.8, 0.6, 1., 
    0.603457}}, {{0.8, 0.8, 0., 0.395675}, {0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 
    0.435447}, {0.8, 0.8, 0.4, 0.478174}, {0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 
    0.521826}, {0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.564553}, {0.8, 0.8, 1., 
    0.604325}}, {{0.8, 1., 0., 0.400723}, {0.8, 1., 0.2, 
    0.437817}, {0.8, 1., 0.4, 0.479432}, {0.8, 1., 0.6, 
    0.522529}, {0.8, 1., 0.8, 0.564984}, {0.8, 1., 1., 
    0.604656}}}, {{{1., 0., 0., 0.351387}, {1., 0., 0.2, 
    0.411972}, {1., 0., 0.4, 0.465135}, {1., 0., 0.6, 0.513742}, {1., 
    0., 0.8, 0.558037}, {1., 0., 1., 0.596086}}, {{1., 0.2, 0., 
    0.358132}, {1., 0.2, 0.2, 0.414826}, {1., 0.2, 0.4, 0.46653}, {1.,
     0.2, 0.6, 0.514485}, {1., 0.2, 0.8, 0.558481}, {1., 0.2, 1., 
    0.596426}}, {{1., 0.4, 0., 0.371758}, {1., 0.4, 0.2, 
    0.421571}, {1., 0.4, 0.4, 0.47004}, {1., 0.4, 0.6, 0.516399}, {1.,
     0.4, 0.8, 0.559635}, {1., 0.4, 1., 0.597312}}, {{1., 0.6, 0., 
    0.384469}, {1., 0.6, 0.2, 0.429054}, {1., 0.6, 0.4, 
    0.474184}, {1., 0.6, 0.6, 0.518718}, {1., 0.6, 0.8, 
    0.561048}, {1., 0.6, 1., 0.5984}}, {{1., 0.8, 0., 0.395344}, {1., 
    0.8, 0.2, 0.435016}, {1., 0.8, 0.4, 0.477471}, {1., 0.8, 0.6, 
    0.520568}, {1., 0.8, 0.8, 0.562183}, {1., 0.8, 1., 
    0.599277}}, {{1., 1., 0., 0.400389}, {1., 1., 0.2, 0.437385}, {1.,
     1., 0.4, 0.478728}, {1., 1., 0.6, 0.521272}, {1., 1., 0.8, 
    0.562615}, {1., 1., 1., 0.599611}}}}*)
```

Results computed with our code for `λh = 1; λc = 1; λz = 1; bh = 1; bc = 1; rh = 1; rc = 1;`
[image: Figure 3]

Numerical table

```
tab2 = 
 Table[{x, y, z, u3[x, y, z] /. rul}, {x, 0, 1, .2}, {y, 0, 
   1, .2}, {z, 0, 1, .2}]

(*Out[]= {{{{0., 0., 0., 0.351913}, {0., 0., 0.2, 0.415671}, {0., 0., 
    0.4, 0.472425}, {0., 0., 0.6, 0.527563}, {0., 0., 0.8, 
    0.584311}, {0., 0., 1., 0.648035}}, {{0., 0.2, 0., 0.362043}, {0.,
     0.2, 0.2, 0.41954}, {0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.474254}, {0., 0.2, 0.6, 
    0.528512}, {0., 0.2, 0.8, 0.584869}, {0., 0.2, 1., 
    0.648406}}, {{0., 0.4, 0., 0.374862}, {0., 0.4, 0.2, 
    0.426163}, {0., 0.4, 0.4, 0.477734}, {0., 0.4, 0.6, 
    0.530404}, {0., 0.4, 0.8, 0.585983}, {0., 0.4, 1., 
    0.649196}}, {{0., 0.6, 0., 0.388098}, {0., 0.6, 0.2, 
    0.433759}, {0., 0.6, 0.4, 0.481916}, {0., 0.6, 0.6, 
    0.532732}, {0., 0.6, 0.8, 0.587369}, {0., 0.6, 1., 
    0.650192}}, {{0., 0.8, 0., 0.398678}, {0., 0.8, 0.2, 
    0.439659}, {0., 0.8, 0.4, 0.485185}, {0., 0.8, 0.6, 
    0.534565}, {0., 0.8, 0.8, 0.588468}, {0., 0.8, 1., 
    0.650978}}, {{0., 1., 0., 0.405092}, {0., 1., 0.2, 0.442489}, {0.,
     1., 0.4, 0.486624}, {0., 1., 0.6, 0.535347}, {0., 1., 0.8, 
    0.588936}, {0., 1., 1., 0.651302}}}, {{{0.2, 0., 0., 
    0.351575}, {0.2, 0., 0.2, 0.415109}, {0.2, 0., 0.4, 
    0.471481}, {0.2, 0., 0.6, 0.525731}, {0.2, 0., 0.8, 
    0.580452}, {0.2, 0., 1., 0.63791}}, {{0.2, 0.2, 0., 
    0.361696}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.418975}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 
    0.47331}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.526681}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 
    0.581013}, {0.2, 0.2, 1., 0.638289}}, {{0.2, 0.4, 0., 
    0.374505}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.425594}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 
    0.476789}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.528573}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 
    0.582132}, {0.2, 0.4, 1., 0.639099}}, {{0.2, 0.6, 0., 
    0.387731}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.433186}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 
    0.48097}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.6, 0.530903}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 
    0.583524}, {0.2, 0.6, 1., 0.640118}}, {{0.2, 0.8, 0., 
    0.398303}, {0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.439083}, {0.2, 0.8, 0.4, 
    0.484238}, {0.2, 0.8, 0.6, 0.532737}, {0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 
    0.584628}, {0.2, 0.8, 1., 0.640923}}, {{0.2, 1., 0., 
    0.404713}, {0.2, 1., 0.2, 0.441912}, {0.2, 1., 0.4, 
    0.485677}, {0.2, 1., 0.6, 0.53352}, {0.2, 1., 0.8, 
    0.585098}, {0.2, 1., 1., 0.641255}}}, {{{0.4, 0., 0., 
    0.350792}, {0.4, 0., 0.2, 0.413998}, {0.4, 0., 0.4, 
    0.469592}, {0.4, 0., 0.6, 0.522253}, {0.4, 0., 0.8, 
    0.573834}, {0.4, 0., 1., 0.625097}}, {{0.4, 0.2, 0., 
    0.360894}, {0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.417859}, {0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 
    0.47142}, {0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.523204}, {0.4, 0.2, 0.8, 
    0.574398}, {0.4, 0.2, 1., 0.625487}}, {{0.4, 0.4, 0., 
    0.373682}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.42447}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
    0.474897}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.525099}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.8, 
    0.575526}, {0.4, 0.4, 1., 0.626319}}, {{0.4, 0.6, 0., 
    0.386887}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 0.432053}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 
    0.479075}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.527431}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 
    0.576928}, {0.4, 0.6, 1., 0.627365}}, {{0.4, 0.8, 0., 
    0.397442}, {0.4, 0.8, 0.2, 0.437944}, {0.4, 0.8, 0.4, 
    0.482342}, {0.4, 0.8, 0.6, 0.529268}, {0.4, 0.8, 0.8, 
    0.57804}, {0.4, 0.8, 1., 0.628191}}, {{0.4, 1., 0., 
    0.403841}, {0.4, 1., 0.2, 0.440769}, {0.4, 1., 0.4, 
    0.48378}, {0.4, 1., 0.6, 0.530052}, {0.4, 1., 0.8, 
    0.578513}, {0.4, 1., 1., 0.628532}}}, {{{0.6, 0., 0., 
    0.349794}, {0.6, 0., 0.2, 0.412617}, {0.6, 0., 0.4, 
    0.467266}, {0.6, 0., 0.6, 0.518075}, {0.6, 0., 0.8, 
    0.56624}, {0.6, 0., 1., 0.611867}}, {{0.6, 0.2, 0., 
    0.359872}, {0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.416471}, {0.6, 0.2, 0.4, 
    0.469092}, {0.6, 0.2, 0.6, 0.519027}, {0.6, 0.2, 0.8, 
    0.566809}, {0.6, 0.2, 1., 0.612267}}, {{0.6, 0.4, 0., 
    0.372633}, {0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0.423072}, {0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 
    0.472566}, {0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.520924}, {0.6, 0.4, 0.8, 
    0.567945}, {0.6, 0.4, 1., 0.613119}}, {{0.6, 0.6, 0., 
    0.385811}, {0.6, 0.6, 0.2, 0.430644}, {0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 
    0.476742}, {0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.523259}, {0.6, 0.6, 0.8, 
    0.569358}, {0.6, 0.6, 1., 0.614192}}, {{0.6, 0.8, 0., 
    0.396346}, {0.6, 0.8, 0.2, 0.436526}, {0.6, 0.8, 0.4, 
    0.480006}, {0.6, 0.8, 0.6, 0.525098}, {0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 
    0.57048}, {0.6, 0.8, 1., 0.615039}}, {{0.6, 1., 0., 
    0.40273}, {0.6, 1., 0.2, 0.439347}, {0.6, 1., 0.4, 
    0.481443}, {0.6, 1., 0.6, 0.525883}, {0.6, 1., 0.8, 
    0.570957}, {0.6, 1., 1., 0.615389}}}, {{{0.8, 0., 0., 
    0.349011}, {0.8, 0., 0.2, 0.411519}, {0.8, 0., 0.4, 
    0.465435}, {0.8, 0., 0.6, 0.514807}, {0.8, 0., 0.8, 
    0.560343}, {0.8, 0., 1., 0.60129}}, {{0.8, 0.2, 0., 
    0.359071}, {0.8, 0.2, 0.2, 0.415368}, {0.8, 0.2, 0.4, 
    0.46726}, {0.8, 0.2, 0.6, 0.51576}, {0.8, 0.2, 0.8, 
    0.560915}, {0.8, 0.2, 1., 0.601699}}, {{0.8, 0.4, 0., 
    0.371809}, {0.8, 0.4, 0.2, 0.421961}, {0.8, 0.4, 0.4, 
    0.470731}, {0.8, 0.4, 0.6, 0.517659}, {0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 
    0.562058}, {0.8, 0.4, 1., 0.602568}}, {{0.8, 0.6, 0., 
    0.384967}, {0.8, 0.6, 0.2, 0.429524}, {0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 
    0.474905}, {0.8, 0.6, 0.6, 0.519996}, {0.8, 0.6, 0.8, 
    0.563479}, {0.8, 0.6, 1., 0.603662}}, {{0.8, 0.8, 0., 
    0.395485}, {0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 0.435399}, {0.8, 0.8, 0.4, 
    0.478168}, {0.8, 0.8, 0.6, 0.521837}, {0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
    0.564608}, {0.8, 0.8, 1., 0.604526}}, {{0.8, 1., 0., 
    0.401858}, {0.8, 1., 0.2, 0.438217}, {0.8, 1., 0.4, 
    0.479604}, {0.8, 1., 0.6, 0.522623}, {0.8, 1., 0.8, 
    0.565087}, {0.8, 1., 1., 0.604883}}}, {{{1., 0., 0., 
    0.348701}, {1., 0., 0.2, 0.41105}, {1., 0., 0.4, 0.464655}, {1., 
    0., 0.6, 0.513367}, {1., 0., 0.8, 0.557517}, {1., 0., 1., 
    0.594879}}, {{1., 0.2, 0., 0.358753}, {1., 0.2, 0.2, 
    0.414897}, {1., 0.2, 0.4, 0.466479}, {1., 0.2, 0.6, 
    0.514321}, {1., 0.2, 0.8, 0.558091}, {1., 0.2, 1., 
    0.595293}}, {{1., 0.4, 0., 0.371483}, {1., 0.4, 0.2, 
    0.421487}, {1., 0.4, 0.4, 0.46995}, {1., 0.4, 0.6, 0.51622}, {1., 
    0.4, 0.8, 0.559237}, {1., 0.4, 1., 0.596173}}, {{1., 0.6, 0., 
    0.384632}, {1., 0.6, 0.2, 0.429046}, {1., 0.6, 0.4, 
    0.474123}, {1., 0.6, 0.6, 0.518559}, {1., 0.6, 0.8, 
    0.560663}, {1., 0.6, 1., 0.597281}}, {{1., 0.8, 0., 
    0.395142}, {1., 0.8, 0.2, 0.434919}, {1., 0.8, 0.4, 
    0.477385}, {1., 0.8, 0.6, 0.5204}, {1., 0.8, 0.8, 0.561795}, {1., 
    0.8, 1., 0.598156}}, {{1., 1., 0., 0.401512}, {1., 1., 0.2, 
    0.437734}, {1., 1., 0.4, 0.478821}, {1., 1., 0.6, 0.521186}, {1., 
    1., 0.8, 0.562276}, {1., 1., 1., 0.598518}}}}*)
{ListPlot[{Flatten[tab1, 2][[All, 4]], Flatten[tab2, 2][[All, 4]]}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"tab1", "tab2"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 ListPlot[Flatten[tab1, 2][[All, 4]] - Flatten[tab2, 2][[All, 4]], 
  PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 4]

Note, that the difference of two methods is about $2\times 10^{-3}$.

Comment: This works neatly. I did check with other configurations and materials to find solution in all cases. I see that you have used trigononetric basis functions with a combination of the wavelets. The pdf document uploaded by you on the wolfra community serves as a useful compendium.

Comment: @Avrana Yes, we can solve this problem with Euler wavelets as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer, but it occurred to me that your solution is incomplete.  You have a double $Cos$ series in $m$ and $n$, and unlike $Sin$ series you should need $m=0$ and $n=0$ terms.

You have computed your $T_{mn}$ series for $(m, n)$ going from $1$ to $\infty$ and it came out to be $0
$.  You need to add a $T_{00}$ term for $(m, n)=0$ and two more series.

Add a $T_{m0}$ series for $n=0$ and $m$ going from $1$ to $\infty$ and a $T_{0n}$ series for $m=0$ and n going from $1$ to $\infty$.

It takes all four pieces to make a complete solution.  I have not tried this on your problem yet, so I don't know if all the pieces will come out to be zero or not, but this will give you something else to try.  Your solution would not be correct without all four pieces anyway.

At the OP's request I will include my code, even though it doesn't work very well.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
$Assumptions = n ∈ Integers && m ∈ Integers
pde = D[T[x, y, z], x, x] + D[T[x, y, z], y, y] + D[T[x, y, z], z, z] == 0
T[x_, y_, z_] = X[x] Y[y] Z[z]
pde = pde/T[x, y, z] // Expand
x0eq = X''[x]/X[x] == 0
DSolve[x0eq, X[x], x] // Flatten
X0 = X[x] /. % /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}
xeq = X''[x]/X[x] == -α1^2
DSolve[xeq, X[x], x] // Flatten
X1 = X[x] /. % /. {C[1] -> c3, C[2] -> c4}
y0eq = Y''[y]/Y[y] == 0
DSolve[y0eq, Y[y], y] // Flatten
Y0 = Y[y] /. % /. {C[1] -> c5, C[2] -> c6}
yeq = Y''[y]/Y[y] == -β1^2
DSolve[yeq, Y[y], y] // Flatten
Y1 = Y[y] /. % /. {C[1] -> c7, C[2] -> c8}
z0eq = pde /. X''[x]/X[x] -> 0 /. Y''[y]/Y[y] -> 0
DSolve[z0eq, Z[z], z] // Flatten
Z0 = Z[z] /. % /. {C[1] -> c9, C[2] -> c10}
zeq = pde /. X''[x]/X[x] -> -α1^2 /. Y''[y]/Y[y] -> -β1^2
DSolve[zeq, Z[z], z] // Flatten
Z1 = Z[z] /. % /. {C[1] -> c11, C[2] -> c12} // ExpToTrig // Collect[#, {Cosh[_], Sinh[_]}] &
Z1 = % /. {c11 - c12 -> c11, c11 + c12 -> c12}
T[x_, y_, z_] = X0 Y0 Z0 + X1 Y1 Z1
(D[T[x, y, z], x] /. x -> 0) == 0
c2 = 0;
c4 = 0;
T[x, y, z]
c1 = 1
c3 = 1
(D[T[x, y, z], x] /. x -> L) == 0
α1 = (n π)/L
(D[T[x, y, z], y] /. y -> 0) == 0
c6 = 0
c8 = 0
T[x, y, z]
c5 = 1
c7 = 1
(D[T[x, y, z], y] /. y -> l) == 0
β1 = (m π)/l
Tmn[x_, y_, z_] = T[x, y, z] /. {c9 -> 0, c10 -> 0}
T00[x_, y_, z_] = T[x, y, z] /. n -> 0 /. m -> 0
T00[x_, y_, z_] = % /. c9 -> 0 /. c12 -> c1200
Tm0[x_, y_, z_] = T[x, y, z] /. n -> 0
Tm0[x_, y_, z_] = % /. {c10 -> 0, c9 -> 0, c11 -> c11m0, c12 -> c12m0} // PowerExpand
T0n[x_, y_, z_] = T[x, y, z] /. m -> 0 // PowerExpand
T0n[x_, y_, z_] = % /. {c9 -> 0, c10 -> 0, c11 -> c110n, c12 -> c120n}
pdetcmn = D[tcmn[x, y], y] + (bc/l)*(tcmn[x, y] - Tmn[x, y, 0]) == 0
DSolve[pdetcmn, tcmn[x, y], {x, y}] // Flatten
tcmn[x_, y_] = tcmn[x, y] /. % /. C[1][x] -> 0
pdetc00 = D[tc00[x, y], y] + (bc/l)*(tc00[x, y] - T00[x, y, 0]) == 0
DSolve[{pdetc00, tc00[x, 0] == tci}, tc00[x, y], {x, y}] // Flatten // Simplify
tc00[x_, y_] = tc00[x, y] /. %
pdetcm0 = D[tcm0[x, y], y] + (bc/l)*(tcm0[x, y] - Tm0[x, y, 0]) == 0
DSolve[pdetcm0, tcm0[x, y], {x, y}] // Flatten
tcm0[x_, y_] = tcm0[x, y] /. % /. C[1][x] -> 0
pdetc0n = D[tc0n[x, y], y] + (bc/l)*(tc0n[x, y] - T0n[x, y, 0]) == 0
DSolve[pdetc0n, tc0n[x, y], {x, y}] // Flatten
tc0n[x_, y_] = tc0n[x, y] /. % /. C[1][x] -> 0
pdethmn = D[thmn[x, y], x] + (bh/L)*(thmn[x, y] - Tmn[x, y, 0]) == 0
DSolve[pdethmn, thmn[x, y], {x, y}] // Flatten
thmn[x_, y_] = thmn[x, y] /. % /. C[1][y] -> 0
pdeth00 = D[th00[x, y], x] + (bh/L)*(th00[x, y] - T00[x, y, 0]) == 0
DSolve[{pdeth00, th00[0, y] == thi}, th00[x, y], {x, y}] // Flatten
th00[x_, y_] = th00[x, y] /. %
pdethm0 = D[thm0[x, y], x] + (bh/L)*(thm0[x, y] - Tm0[x, y, 0]) == 0
DSolve[pdethm0, thm0[x, y], {x, y}] // Flatten
thm0[x_, y_] = thm0[x, y] /. % /. C[1][y] -> 0
pdeth0n = D[th0n[x, y], x] + (bh/L)*(th0n[x, y] - T0n[x, y, 0]) == 0
DSolve[pdeth0n, th0n[x, y], {x, y}] // Flatten
th0n[x_, y_] = th0n[x, y] /. % /. C[1][y] -> 0
bc100 = Simplify[(D[T00[x, y, z], z] /. z -> 0) == pc*(T00[x, y, 0] - tc00[x, y])]
orth100 = Integrate[bc100[[1]], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}] == Integrate[bc100[[2]], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}]
bc200 = Simplify[(D[T00[x, y, z], z] /. z -> w) == ph*(th00[x, y] - T00[x, y, w])]
orth200 = Integrate[bc200[[1]], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}] == Integrate[bc200[[2]], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}]
sol00 = Solve[{orth100, orth200}, {c10, c1200}] // Flatten // Simplify
c10 = c10 /. sol00
c1200 = c1200 /. sol00
T00[x, y, z]
tc00[x, y]
th00[x, y]
bc1m0 = Simplify[(D[Tm0[x, y, z], z] /. z -> 0) == pc*(Tm0[x, y, 0] - tcm0[x, y])]
orth1m0 = Integrate[bc1m0[[1]]*Cos[(m*Pi*y)/l], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}] == Integrate[bc1m0[[2]]*Cos[(m*Pi*y)/l], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}]
bc2m0 = Simplify[(D[Tm0[x, y, z], z] /. z -> w) == ph*(thm0[x, y] - Tm0[x, y, w])]
orth2m0 = Integrate[bc2m0[[1]]*Cos[(m*Pi*y)/l], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}] == Integrate[bc2m0[[2]]*Cos[(m*Pi*y)/l], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}]
solm0 = Solve[{orth1m0, orth2m0}, {c11m0, c12m0}] // Flatten // Simplify
bc10n = (D[T0n[x, y, z], z] /. z -> 0) == pc*(T0n[x, y, 0] - tc0n[x, y])
orth10n = Integrate[bc10n[[1]]*Cos[(Pi*n*x)/L], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}] == Integrate[bc10n[[2]]*Cos[(Pi*n*x)/L], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}]
bc20n = Simplify[(D[T0n[x, y, z], z] /. z -> w) == ph*(th0n[x, y] - T0n[x, y, w])]
orth20n = Integrate[bc20n[[1]]*Cos[(Pi*n*x)/L], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}] == Integrate[bc20n[[2]]*Cos[(Pi*n*x)/L], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}]
sol0n = Solve[{orth10n, orth20n}, {c110n, c120n}] // Flatten // Simplify
bc1mn = (D[Tmn[x, y, z], z] /. z -> 0) == pc*(Tmn[x, y, 0] - tcmn[x, y])
orth1mn = Integrate[bc1mn[[1]]*Cos[(m*Pi*y)/l]*Cos[(Pi*n*x)/L], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}] == Integrate[bc10n[[2]]*Cos[(m*Pi*y)/l]*Cos[(Pi*n*x)/L], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}]
bc2mn = Simplify[(D[Tmn[x, y, z], z] /. z -> w) == ph*(thmn[x, y] - Tmn[x, y, w])]
orth2mn = Integrate[bc2mn[[1]]*Cos[(m*Pi*y)/l]*Cos[(Pi*n*x)/L], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}] == Integrate[bc2mn[[2]]*Cos[(m*Pi*y)/l]*Cos[(Pi*n*x)/L], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}]
solmn = Solve[{orth1mn, orth2mn}, {c11, c12}] // Flatten // Simplify
```

All zeros except T00, and that solution does not satisfy the bc's.  Have fun

**Update for new bc's**
This is too numerically unstable to get to work, but this is what I did.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
pde = D[T[x, y, z], x, x] + D[T[x, y, z], y, y] + D[T[x, y, z], z, z] == 0
$Assumptions = n ∈ Integers && m ∈ Integers && l > 0 && w > 0 && L > 0
```

Case 1

x = 0, T = thi

x = L, dT/dx = 0

y = 0, T = 0

y = l, dT/dy = 0
Use exponential in x, sinusoidal in y and z.  Start with

```
T[x_, y_, z_] = (c1 + c2 x) (c10 z + c9) (c5 + c6 y) + (c3 Cosh[Sqrt[α1^2 + β1^2] x] + 
     c4 Sinh[Sqrt[α1^2 + β1^2] x]) (c7 Cos[α1 y] + c8 Sin[α1 y]) (c11 Sin[β1 z] + c12 Cos[β1 z])
T[0, y, z] == thi
(D[T[x, y, z], x] /. x -> L) == 0
c2 = 0
Solve[(c3 Sqrt[α1^2 + β1^2]Sinh[L Sqrt[α1^2 + β1^2]] + 
     c4 Sqrt[α1^2 + β1^2] Cosh[L Sqrt[α1^2 + β1^2]]) == 0, c4] // Flatten
c4 = c4 /. %
c3 = 1
c1 = 1
```

Manually expand the Tanh and incorporate the (constant) common denominator with the other constants

```
Simplify[Cosh[L*Sqrt[α1^2 + β1^2]]*Cosh[x*Sqrt[α1^2 + β1^2]] - Sinh[L*Sqrt[α1^2 + β1^2]]*Sinh[x*Sqrt[α1^2 + β1^2]]]
T[x_, y_, z_] = T[x, y, z] /. (Cosh[x Sqrt[α1^2 + β1^2]] - 
     Tanh[L Sqrt[α1^2 + β1^2]] Sinh[ x Sqrt[α1^2 + β1^2]]) -> %
T[x, 0, z] == 0
c5 = 0
c7 = 0
c6 = 1
c8 = 1

Simplify[D[T[x, y, z], y] /. y -> l] == 0
c10 = 0
c9 = 0
α1 = ((2 n + 1) π)/(2 l)
```

Set

```
β1 = ((2 m + 1) π)/(2 w)
T1[x_, y_, z_] = T[x, y, z]
```

Case 2

x = 0, T = 0

x = L, dT/dx = 0

y = 0, T = tci

y = l, dT/dy = 0

Use exponential in x, sinusoidal in y and z and flip the y and z terms

```
T2[x_, y_, z_] = 
 Sin[(π (2 n + 1) x)/(2 L)] (c112 Sin[(π (2 m + 1) z)/(2 w)] + 
    c122 Cos[(π (2 m + 1) z)/(2 w)]) Cosh[(l - y) Sqrt[(π^2 (2 n + 1)^2)/(4 L^2) + (π^2 (2 m + 1)^2)/(4 w^2)]]
T[x_, y_, z_] = T1[x, y, z] + T2[x, y, z]
pdeth = D[th[x, y], x] + (bh/L)*(th[x, y] - T[x, y, w]) == 0
DSolve[{pdeth, th[0, y] == thi}, th[x, y], {x, y}] // 
  Flatten // Simplify
th[x_, y_] = th[x, y] /. % // Simplify
pdetc = Simplify[D[tc[x, y], y] + (bc/l)*(tc[x, y] - T[x, y, 0]) == 0]
DSolve[{pdetc, tc[x, 0] == tci}, tc[x, y], {x, y}] // 
  Flatten // Simplify
tc[x_, y_] = tc[x, y] /. %
bc1 = T[0, y, z] == thi
bc2 = T[x, 0, z] == tci
bc3 = Simplify[(D[T[x, y, z], z] /. z -> 0) == pc*(T[x, y, 0] - tc[x, y])]
bc4 = Simplify[(D[T[x, y, z], z] /. z -> w) == ph*(th[x, y] - T[x, y, w])]
bc1eq = Simplify[Integrate[(bc1[[1]] - bc1[[2]])*Sin[(Pi*(2*n + 1)*y)/(2*l)]*Sin[(Pi*(2*m + 1)*z)/(2*w)], {z, 0, w}, {y, 0, l}] == 0]
bc2eq = Simplify[Integrate[(bc2[[1]] - bc2[[2]])*Sin[(Pi*(2*n + 1)*x)/(2*L)]*Sin[(Pi*(2*m + 1)*z)/(2*w)], {z, 0, w}, {x, 0, L}] == 0]
bc3eq = Integrate[bc3[[1]]*Sin[(Pi*(2*n + 1)*y)/(2*l)]*Sin[(Pi*(2*n + 1)*x)/(2*L)], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}] == 0
bc4eq = Integrate[bc4[[1]]*Sin[(Pi*(2*n + 1)*y)/(2*l)]*Sin[(Pi*(2*n + 1)*x)/(2*L)], {y, 0, l}, {x, 0, L}] == 0
Solve[bc1eq, c12] // Flatten // Simplify
c12 = c12 /. %
Solve[bc2eq, c122] // Flatten // Simplify
c122 = c122 /. %
Solve[bc4eq, c112] // Flatten;
c112 = c112 /. %
Solve[bc3eq, c11] // Flatten;
c11 = c11 /. %
values = {L -> 1/40, l -> 1/40, w -> 3/1000, bh -> 433/1000, 
   bc -> 433/1000, ph -> 6524/100, pc -> 6524/100, thi -> 120, tci -> 30};
C11 = Table[c11 /. values, {m, 0, 10}, {n, 0, 10}] // N[#, 50] &
C11 = Re[C11]
```

To get rid of the small imaginary component.  `Chop` wipes out the real part also.

```
C12 = Table[c12 /. values, {m, 0, 11}, {n, 0, 11}] // N[#, 50] &
C12 = Re[C12]
C112 = Table[c112 /. values, {m, 0, 11}, {n, 0, 11}] // N[#, 50] &
C112 = Re[C112]
C122 = Table[c122 /. values, {m, 0, 11}, {n, 0, 11}] // N[#, 50] &
C122 = Re[C122]
```

Put it all together

```
T[x_, y_, z_] := Sum[Sin[(Pi*(2*n + 1)*y)/(2*l)]*(C11[[m + 1,n + 1]]*Sin[(Pi*(2*m + 1)*z)/(2*w)] + C12[[m + 1,n + 1]]*Cos[(Pi*(2*m + 1)*z)/(2*w)])*
     Cosh[(L - x)*Sqrt[(Pi^2*(2*n + 1)^2)/(4*l^2) + (Pi^2*(2*m + 1)^2)/(4*w^2)]] + Sin[(Pi*(2*n + 1)*x)/(2*L)]*
     Cosh[(l - y)*Sqrt[(Pi^2*(2*n + 1)^2)/(4*L^2) + (Pi^2*(2*m + 1)^2)/(4*w^2)]]*(C112[[m + 1,n + 1]]*Sin[(Pi*(2*m + 1)*z)/(2*w)] + 
      C122[[m + 1,n + 1]]*Cos[(Pi*(2*m + 1)*z)/(2*w)]), {m, 0, 10}, {n, 0, 10}]
```

It took my computer days to compute all this and the values are way off. m,n of 10,10 are not enough terms, but I am not going any further. The values are still changing dramatically from m,n 9,10 to 10,10.  Maybe the solution is wrong, or 50 decimals places is not enough, or it will take many more terms and many more days to even test the solution properly.  Maybe your computer can do it faster, but my computer is 4 Ghz Intel i7 processor with 32 GB ram, so it is not a slow computer.  Good luck.

Comment: Oh thanks Bill. I know that I have started my series from `0,0` which would not be a matter if it was a all homogeneous Dirichlet condition leading to a double $\sin$ series. What is bothering me is that how am I going to use orthogonality for the `n=0` and 'm=0` series. I will try your suggestion. But if its not too much to ask, I will request you too to give this a try at a time suitable for you.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and changed my preliminary temperature distribution into a sum of four terms and executed the code. I encountered an error which I have posted as an *Attempt*,  in my original question. But it seems I am doing something wrong. Are these additional series supposed to be solved separately ? I remember in your solution to the heat transfer in cylindrical coordinates you applied orthogonality separatley for a `n=0` term.

Comment: Yes, I did it separately.  I am still examining the problem.  I haven't gotten errors, but the bc's don't match.  I will try some more.

Comment: Thanks Bill. yes everything is 0 and the `T00` term has no `x,y` dependency

Comment: Can you try a solution once for this set of bc(s), $T(0,y,z)=t_{hi}, \frac{\partial T(L,y,z)}{\partial x}=0, T(x,0,z)=t_{ci}, \frac{\partial T(x,l,z)}{\partial y}=0$. The $z$ conditions remain the same. I will myself try it too, but I know I will miss out on some tricks you have up your sleeve.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a shot.

Comment: Awarded you the bounty because this answer pointed out a fundamental mistake in my series solution and suggested a way to circumvent it by writing the series as a sum of four components

Comment: I tried the problem with the new bc(s) by dividing it into three sub-problems and finally adding the solutions together using  principle of superposition. But the final results seemed to be nonphysical. Have you had any success?

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, although I don't really think my answer warrants it.  I am playing around with different combinations of sub problems, but I haven't come up with one I am happy with yet.  It looks like it will take awhile to try them all.

Comment: That's very humble of you to say. I awarded because I learned something new. From my experience when I try to search for analytical solution to Laplacian on the web, I find a lot of documents but few go beyond 2D and those few are sometimes trivial. These answers have filled that gap.

Comment: My equations are so long that Mathematica runs all night and then runs out of memory in computing the c's. I will have to compute them with the numeric values applied before hand and then for each value of m, n separately.  I am still working on it, though  I still don't know if my answer will work yet.

Comment: Oh much appreciated Bill. This was nice to know. Take your time surely.

Comment: Hi Bill. I had a proposal. Just in case, if you are having trouble running the code on your system, I do have access to a high end work station where I can try to execute it. Let me know if I could be of any help.

Comment: Hopefully I will have something to post tomorrow, my time.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra Updated, but not with much success.

Comment: much much appreciated. yes your system is pretty fast, I was wrong there. I will now go through your solution.

Comment: should the value of $\alpha1$ be `α1 = ((2 n + 1) π)/(2 w)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed copying a few lines and have added them that include $\alpha 1$.  But I think the problem won't work anyway, because I can solve for all the constants using bc1 and bc2 alone.  But that will not satisfy the z boundary conditions.  We have too few unknowns for the number of equations and I don't know where to get more.

Comment: I'm going to have to think some more.

Comment: @Hi Bill. I had observed your edit yesterday and ran the updated code.As you had mentioned before it takes a long long time and the coefficients being calculated on the last step just keep running. That is why I refrained from commenting here. Thanks for still sticking with the question and surely take your time. From my end I am working on a two-dimensional approach but have still not reached anything solid. Good day.

Comment: I am redoing it from a different perspective, but it will take a long time.

Comment: A happy new year To you!

Comment: Happy new year to you too.