# Unbounded solution at boundaries with few combination of values in this BVP solution

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, code-review, eigenvalues, boundary-conditions

I had asked a question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235568/three-coupled-pdes-to-be-solved-semi-analytically-analytically) regarding solution to a BVP problem. bbgodfrey provided an excellent answer using the method of integrated least squares.

However, for a few specific set of values of practical interest, the solution becomes unstable, especially at the boundaries.

Values for which the solution works perfectly:

`L = 0.025; l = 0.025; w = 0.002; k = 390; A = 5625 10^-6; h = 3000; bh = 5.375; bc = 4 bh; λc = (1/l) (k w L/(A h/bc)); λh = (1/L) (k w l/(A h/bh)); V = 0.25;`

Values for which the solution behaves wierdly:

`L = 0.025; l = 0.025; w = 0.0001; k = 390; A = 5625 10^-6; h = 3000; bh = 5.375; bc = 4 bh; λc = (1/l) (k w L/(A h/bc)); λh = (1/L) (k w l/(A h/bh)); V = 0.25`

Code

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]]
eq1 = D[θh[x, y], x] + bh (θh[x, y] - θw[x, y]);
eq2 = D[θc[x, y], y] + bc (θc[x, y] - θw[x, y]);
eq3 = λh D[θw[x, y], x, x] + λc V D[θw[x, y], y, y] + bh (θh[x, y] - θw[x, y]) + V bc (θc[x, y] - θw[x, y]);
th = Collect[(eq1 /. {θh -> Function[{x, y}, θhx[x] θhy[y]], θw -> Function[{x, y}, θwx[x] θwy[y]]})/(θhy[y] θwx[x]), {θhx[x], θhx'[x], θwy[y]}, Simplify];
1 == th[[1 ;; 3 ;; 2]];
eq1x = Subtract @@ Simplify[θwx[x] # & /@ %] == 0;
1 == -th[[2]];
eq1y = θhy[y] # & /@ %;
tc = Collect[(eq2 /. {θc -> Function[{x, y}, θcx[x] θcy[y]], θw -> Function[{x, y}, θwx[x] θwy[y]]})/(θcx[x] θwy[y]), {θcy[y], θcy'[y], θwy[y]}, Simplify];
1 == -tc[[1]];
eq2x = θcx[x] # & /@ %;
1 == tc[[2 ;; 3]];
eq2y = Subtract @@ Simplify[θwy[y] # & /@ %] == 0;
tw = Plus @@ ((List @@ Expand[eq3 /. {θh -> Function[{x, y}, θhx[x] θhy[y]], θc -> Function[{x, y}, θcx[x] θcy[y]], θw -> Function[{x, y}, θwx[x] θwy[y]]}])/(θwx[x] θwy[y]) /. Rule @@ eq2x /. Rule @@ eq1y);
sw == -tw[[1 ;; 5 ;; 2]];
eq3x = Subtract @@ Simplify[θwx[x] # & /@ %] == 0;
sw == tw[[2 ;; 6 ;; 2]];
eq3y = -Subtract @@ Simplify[θwy[y] # & /@ %] == 0;
sy = DSolveValue[{eq2y, eq3y, θcy[0] == 0, θwy'[0] == 0}, {θwy[y], θcy[y], θwy'[1]}, {y, 0, 1}] /. C[2] -> 1;
sx = DSolveValue[{eq1x, eq3x, θwx'[0] == 0, θwx'[1] == 0, θhx[0] == 1}, {θwx[x], θhx[x]}, {x, 0, 1}];

L = 0.025; l = 0.025; w = 0.0001; k = 390; A = 5625 10^-6; h = 3000; bh = 5.375; bc = 4 bh; λc = (1/l) (k w L/(A h/bc)); λh = (1/L) (k w l/(A h/bh)); V = 0.25;
disp = sy[[3]];
n = 12;
Plot[disp, {sw, -800, 10}, AxesLabel -> {sw, "disp"}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, ImageSize -> Large]
Partition[Union @@ Cases[%, Line[z_] -> z, Infinity], 2, 1];
Reverse[Cases[%, {{z1_, z3_}, {z2_, z4_}} /; z3 z4 < 0 :> z1]][[1 ;; n]];
tsw = sw /. Table[FindRoot[disp, {sw, sw0}], {sw0, %}];
syn = ComplexExpand@Replace[bh sy[[1]] /. C[2] -> 1, {sw -> #} & /@ tsw, Infinity] //Chop // Chop;
Integrate[Expand[(1 - Array[c, n].syn)^2], {y, 0, 1}] // Chop // Chop;
coef = NArgMin[%, Array[c, n]]
Plot[coef.syn - 1, {y, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {y, err}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large]
solw = coef.ComplexExpand@Replace[sy[[1]] sx[[1]], {sw -> #} & /@ tsw, Infinity];
solh = coef.ComplexExpand@Replace[bh sy[[1]] sx[[2]], {sw -> #} & /@ tsw, Infinity];
solc = coef.ComplexExpand@Replace[bc sy[[2]] sx[[1]], {sw -> #} & /@ tsw, Infinity];
cavg = Integrate[solc, {x, 0, 1}] // Chop;
havg = Integrate[solh, {y, 0, 1}] // Chop;
{cavg /. y -> 1, havg /. x -> 1}

{Plot3D[solc, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}], Plot3D[solh, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]}
```

It is pretty much evident that the problem occurs due to very closely spaced roots (eigen-values) for the second set of constants. However, I am not sure if I am catching it correctly.

Comment: Do you try to solve PVP or to make research about stability of least squares algorithm?

Comment: @AlexTrounev My objective was to solve this BVP using an anlytical/semi-analytical approach. The linked question has the original answer which proposed integrated least squares as an alternative to do this. The parameter sets I have written here are just describing two different flow configurations. Stability of least squares algorith is not my area of research or interest.

Comment: I have solution for first and second set of parameters based on Euler wavelets. For the first set the difference between my solution and yours is about 10^-4. In a case of second set of parameters solution looks same as for the first case. So, I don't understand why we can't compute this solution with the least squares algorithm.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thankyou for the effort Alex. However, I am afraid I am unfamiliar with the method of Euler wavelets. Please post your solution if possible. Also, were you able to get  a well-behaving solution at the boundaries with my code ? Additionally, the parameter `k=390` represents copper (thermal conductivity). However, when I switch to steel, i.e. `k=16`, my method always behaves unbounded at the boundaries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can solve this problem with using numerical method developed in our recent [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/10/3/165) and based on Euler wavelets. First we define wavelets and all functions to be computed

```
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t]
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 4; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 var1 = Flatten[Table[c[n, m], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]];
nn = Length[var1];
dx = 1/(nn);  xl = Table[ l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; ycol = 
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y; 
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y; M = nn;

U1 = Array[a1, {M, M}]; U2 = Array[a2, {M, M}]; U3 = 
 Array[a3, {M, M}]; U4 = Array[a4, {M, M}]; G1 = Array[g1, {M}]; G2 = 
 Array[g2, {M}]; G3 = Array[g3, {M}]; G4 = Array[g4, {M}]; F1 = 
 Array[f1, {M}]; F2 = Array[f2, {M}];


u1[x_, y_] := int2[x] . U1 . Psi[y] + x G1 . Psi[y] + F1 . Psi[y]; 
u2[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U2 . int2[y] + y G2 . Psi[x] + F2 . Psi[x];
uy[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U2 . int1[y] + G2 . Psi[x];
ux[x_, y_] := int1[x] . U1 . Psi[y] + G1 . Psi[y];
uxx[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U1 . Psi[y];
uyy[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U2 . Psi[y];
tehx[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U3 . Psi[y]; 
tecy[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U4 . Psi[y]; 
teh[x_, y_] := int1[x] . U3 . Psi[y] + G3 . Psi[y]; 
tec[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U4 . int1[y] + G4 . Psi[x];
```

Please, note, that we solve system of equations `eq1 = D[θh[x, y], x] + bh (θh[x, y] - θw[x, y]); eq2 = D[θc[x, y], y] + bc (θc[x, y] - θw[x, y]); eq3 = λh D[θw[x, y], x, x] + λc V D[θw[x, y], y, y] + bh (θh[x, y] - θw[x, y]) + V bc (θc[x, y] - θw[x, y]);`, and `u1, teh, tec` are `θw, θh, θc` consequently. Second step, we define system of equations and variables on the grid for `k=16, w=0.0001`. Test 1:

```
L = 0.025; l = 0.025; w = 0.0001; k = 16; A = 
 5625 10^-6; h = 3000; bh = 5.375; bc = 
 4 bh; \[Lambda]c = (1/l) (k w L/(A h/bc)); \[Lambda]h = (1/
    L) (k w l/(A h/bh)); V = 0.25; var = 
 Join[Flatten[U1], Flatten[U2], G1, G2, F1, F2, Flatten[U3], 
  Flatten[U4], G3, G4]; eq = 
 Join[Flatten[
   Table[\[Lambda]h*uxx[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] + \[Lambda]c*V*
       uyy[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - tehx[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - 
      V*tecy[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] == 0, {i, M}, {j, M}]], 
  Flatten[Table[
    tehx[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] + 
      bh (teh[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - u1[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]]) == 
     0, {i, M}, {j, M}]], 
  Flatten[Table[
    tecy[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] + 
      bc (tec[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]]) == 
     0, {i, M}, {j, M}]], 
  Flatten[Table[
    u1[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] == 0, {i, 
     M}, {j, M}]], 
  Flatten[Table[{ux[1, ycol[[j]]] == 0, ux[0, ycol[[j]]] == 0, 
     uy[xcol[[j]], 0] == 0, uy[xcol[[j]], 1] == 0, 
     teh[0, ycol[[j]]] == 1, tec[xcol[[j]], 0] == 0}, {j, M}]]];
```

Finally we calculate and visualize numerical solution as follows

```
sol = FindRoot[eq, Table[{var[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[var]}], 
   MaxIterations -> 1000];

{Plot3D[Evaluate[teh[x, y] /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> \[Theta]h, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", MeshStyle -> White], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[tec[x, y] /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> \[Theta]c, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", MeshStyle -> White], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[u1[x, y] /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> \[Theta]w, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", MeshStyle -> White]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Test 2. We compute solution for `w = 0.0001; k = 390;`
[image: Figure 2]

Test 3. We compute solution for `w = 0.002; k = 390;`. In this case we can compare solution computed with wavelets - Figure 3 and with least squares algorithm - Figure 4. In the last picture shown difference two solutions `θw` on the grid
[image: Figure 3]
[image: Figure 4]

Update 1. Implementation of list squares method as it explained in the paper LEAST SQUARES FOURIER SERIES SOLUTIONS TO BOUNDARY VALUE PROBLEMS by ROBERT B. KELMAN. Definitions of base function and solution

```
UE[m_, t_] := Cos[m t] Exp[-m t]
nn = 5;
dx = 1/(nn);  xl = Table[ l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; ycol = 
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 Table[UE[n , t1], {n, 0, nn - 1}]; Int1 = Integrate[Psijk, t1];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y; 
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y; M = nn;

U1 = Array[a1, {M, M}]; U2 = Array[a2, {M, M}]; U3 = 
 Array[a3, {M, M}]; U4 = Array[a4, {M, M}]; G1 = Array[g1, {M}]; G2 = 
 Array[g2, {M}]; G3 = Array[g3, {M}]; G4 = Array[g4, {M}]; F1 = 
 Array[f1, {M}]; F2 = Array[f2, {M}];


u1[x_, y_] := int2[x] . U1 . Psi[y] + x G1 . Psi[y] + F1 . Psi[y]; 
u2[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U2 . int2[y] + y G2 . Psi[x] + F2 . Psi[x];
uy[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U2 . int1[y] + G2 . Psi[x];
ux[x_, y_] := int1[x] . U1 . Psi[y] + G1 . Psi[y];
uxx[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U1 . Psi[y];
uyy[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U2 . Psi[y];
tehx[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U3 . Psi[y]; 
tecy[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U4 . Psi[y]; 
teh[x_, y_] := int1[x] . U3 . Psi[y] + G3 . Psi[y]; 
tec[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U4 . int1[y] + G4 . Psi[x];
```

We solve system of equations `eq1 = D[θh[x, y], x] + bh (θh[x, y] - θw[x, y]); eq2 = D[θc[x, y], y] + bc (θc[x, y] - θw[x, y]); eq3 = λh D[θw[x, y], x, x] + λc V D[θw[x, y], y, y] + bh (θh[x, y] - θw[x, y]) + V bc (θc[x, y] - θw[x, y]);`, and `u1, teh, tec` are `θw, θh, θc` consequently. Definitions system of equations and variables on the grid for `k=16, w=0.0001`. Test 1:

```
L = 0.025; l = 0.025; w = 0.0001; k = 16; A = 
 5625 10^-6; h = 3000; bh = 5.375; bc = 
 4 bh; \[Lambda]c = (1/l) (k w L/(A h/bc)); \[Lambda]h = (1/
    L) (k w l/(A h/bh)); V = 0.25; var = 
 Join[Flatten[U1], Flatten[U2], G1, G2, F1, F2, Flatten[U3], 
  Flatten[U4], G3, G4]; eq = 
 Join[Flatten[
   Table[\[Lambda]h*uxx[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] + \[Lambda]c*V*
       uyy[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - tehx[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - 
      V*tecy[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] == 0, {i, M}, {j, M}]], 
  Flatten[Table[
    tehx[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] + 
      bh (teh[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - u1[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]]) == 
     0, {i, M}, {j, M}]], 
  Flatten[Table[
    tecy[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] + 
      bc (tec[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]]) == 
     0, {i, M}, {j, M}]], 
  Flatten[Table[
    u1[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] == 0, {i, 
     M}, {j, M}]], 
  Flatten[Table[{ux[1, ycol[[j]]] == 0, ux[0, ycol[[j]]] == 0, 
     uy[xcol[[j]], 0] == 0, uy[xcol[[j]], 1] == 0, 
     teh[0, ycol[[j]]] == 1, tec[xcol[[j]], 0] == 0}, {j, M}]]];
```

Finally we calculate and visualize numerical solution

```
{bvec, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eq, var];

sol = LinearSolve[mat, -bvec];

rul = Table[var[[i]] -> sol[[i]], {i, Length[var]}];

{Plot3D[Evaluate[teh[x, y] /. rul], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> \[Theta]h, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", MeshStyle -> White], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[tec[x, y] /. rul], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> \[Theta]c, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", MeshStyle -> White], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[u1[x, y] /. rul], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> \[Theta]w, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", MeshStyle -> White]}
```

[image: Figure 5]

Update 2. We always can solve this problem as an optimization (minimization) problem as follows

```
UE[m_, t_] := Cos[m t] Exp[-m t]
nn = 5;
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; ycol = 
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 Table[UE[n, t1], {n, 0, nn - 1}]; Int1 = Integrate[Psijk, t1];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y; M = nn;

U1 = Array[a1, {M, M}]; U2 = Array[a2, {M, M}]; U3 = 
 Array[a3, {M, M}]; U4 = Array[a4, {M, M}]; G1 = Array[g1, {M}]; G2 = 
 Array[g2, {M}]; G3 = Array[g3, {M}]; G4 = Array[g4, {M}]; F1 = 
 Array[f1, {M}]; F2 = Array[f2, {M}];


u1[x_, y_] := int2[x] . U1 . Psi[y] + x G1 . Psi[y] + F1 . Psi[y];
u2[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U2 . int2[y] + y G2 . Psi[x] + F2 . Psi[x];
uy[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U2 . int1[y] + G2 . Psi[x];
ux[x_, y_] := int1[x] . U1 . Psi[y] + G1 . Psi[y];
uxx[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U1 . Psi[y];
uyy[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U2 . Psi[y];
tehx[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U3 . Psi[y];
tecy[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U4 . Psi[y];
teh[x_, y_] := int1[x] . U3 . Psi[y] + G3 . Psi[y];
tec[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U4 . int1[y] + G4 . Psi[x];
L = 0.025; l = 0.025; w = 0.0001; k = 16; A = 
 5625 10^-6; h = 3000; bh = 5.375; bc = 
 4 bh; \[Lambda]c = (1/l) (k w L/(A h/bc)); \[Lambda]h = (1/
    L) (k w l/(A h/bh)); V = 0.25; var = 
 Join[Flatten[U1], Flatten[U2], G1, G2, F1, F2, Flatten[U3], 
  Flatten[U4], G3, G4]; eq = 
 Join[Flatten[
   Table[\[Lambda]h*uxx[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] + \[Lambda]c*V*
      uyy[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - tehx[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - 
     V*tecy[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]], {i, M}, {j, M}]], 
  Flatten[Table[
    tehx[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] + 
     bh (teh[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - u1[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]]), {i, 
     M}, {j, M}]], 
  Flatten[Table[
    tecy[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] + 
     bc (tec[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]]), {i, 
     M}, {j, M}]], 
  Flatten[Table[
    u1[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]], {i, M}, {j, 
     M}]]]; bc = 
 Flatten[Table[{ux[1, ycol[[j]]] == 0, ux[0, ycol[[j]]] == 0, 
    uy[xcol[[j]], 0] == 0, uy[xcol[[j]], 1] == 0, 
    teh[0, ycol[[j]]] == 1, tec[xcol[[j]], 0] == 0}, {j, M}]];

sol = NMinimize[{eq . eq, bc}, var]
```

Visualization

```
{Plot3D[Evaluate[teh[x, y] /. sol[[2]]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> \[Theta]h, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", MeshStyle -> White], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[tec[x, y] /. sol[[2]]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> \[Theta]c, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", MeshStyle -> White], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[u1[x, y] /. sol[[2]]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> \[Theta]w, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", MeshStyle -> White]}
```

[image: Figure 6]

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. I will initially go through the attached paper to get some idea about the method and come back to this answer, to properly understand it.

Comment: The referred paper is excellent (absolute errors are basicallly null with the method). Although, I still need to read more to properly understand this approach. However, I have checked that the code works for all material (k=16, k=390) and operating conditions (different bh,bc, lambdac, lambdah, V). Hence, I will mark this answer as accepted. Although, I still do not understand why the least squares code could not converge properly for `k=16` configurations. Any questions, I have regarding your paper, hopefully, I can enquire along this thread.

Comment: @Avrana We can extend this method for 3D case as well that is not discussed in the paper linked. Also we can improve code proposed by  bbgodfrey to make it more stable in desired parameters range.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I did try to improve the least squares code by including `WorkingPrecision->30` in the `FindRoot` and `coeff` commands, but it did not help. I also tried with large `n` value but failed for all cases with `k=16`.

Comment: @Avrana I have developed the code with implementation of list squares method as it explained in the paper linked. It works in all ranges of parameters and very fast. Basically it looks like may code above.

Comment: Thanks for all the extra update. However, I have a feq questions (1) I understand that the basis functions have been taken to be trigonometric in this approach. Although, I fail to understand the definition of `Psi, Int`. The Kelman paper does mention `Psi` but does not explicitly defines it. However, they have been defined in your Euler wavelet paper. So, is your update a combination of the appraoch by Kelman and your own paper ?

Comment: (2) I am confused, as to where exactly the minimization of least squares is happening? I mean, in bbgodfrey's code there was a `NArgMin` command which did this job. Have you used then the equations (2.2), (2.3), (2.4) (which are also result of least squares minimization) from Kelman's paper ? (3) In the definition of `var`, I could discern the three governing equations of thetaw, thetah, thetac and their respective boundary conditions as coloumn vectors. However, what does the command `Flatten[Table[u1[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] == 0, {i, M}, {j, M}]]` signifies ?

Comment: @Avrana We always can solve this problem as minimization problem, but there is no fast solver for numerical minimization, and it is why we use   `LinearSolve`. See Update 2 with `NMinimize` as solver. Equation `u1=u2`  on the grid means that $\int(\int u_{xx}dx)dx=\int(\int u_{yy}dy)dy$. Yes, I have my code with wavelets as a step to develop last code.

Comment: Much much thanks. Much more clarity now. I just have one final inquiry, which is regarding the definitions of `uxx, uyy,ux,uy` and especially `u1,u2` (As per your last comment they should be the same function, basically `thetaw`). Your paper defines these derivatives in the form of the `Psi` functions. Is there some other paper or reference by you which elaborates them more ?

Comment: @Avrana See my post on https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2457908

Comment: The linked post and attached paper to that post are very helpful and essential for a novice like me. Much grateful for all the effort.

Comment: @Avrana I have developed code for 3D steel plate with water flow discussed on  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226346/three-dimensional-laplacian-insulated-on-lateral-faces-and-convectively-exposed/237287#237287

Comment: Thats great and much gratitude. You can post your solution as an additional answer to the three-dimensional model question. It will be a good generalization and validation for that model. Additionally, I have another question I have been working on which I will post by tomorrow or day after regarding reciprocating flow (thus time-dependent) and heat transfer (I have been using commercial CFD for it but that has been too time consuming, so a reduced-order model will be beneficial). Maybe your developed method will be the best candidiate for that problem too.

Comment: @Avrana Ok! I have uploaded my answer on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226346/three-dimensional-laplacian-insulated-on-lateral-faces-and-convectively-exposed/262857#262857

Comment: I have posted a coupled fluid flow and heat transfer problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262999/reciprocating-flow-in-a-channel-over-a-heated-surface), about which I mentioned in one of the earlier comments. I have found that you have developed a two-dimensional fluid code [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064). Can this be applied to the new problem ? Please have a look at your time.

Comment: I have started a bounty to reward this answer. However, I can award only after 23 hours as per the rules, which I shall do.