# Some conceptual doubts about steady and transient solvers of the NS + energy equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method, modeling

Recently, I have been solving some transient and steady, flow and heat transfer problems in Mathematica. The transient problem is essentially the reciprocating (i.e., fully reversing) flow of a fluid over a thick heated block until the system reaches a cyclic steady-state (i.e., the system temperature oscillates around a mean when this point is reached). I received help regarding this in one of my earlier [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262999/reciprocating-flow-in-a-channel-over-a-heated-surface) on this site. Following is the code:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

{f = 0.5; L = 0.040, d = 0.003, e = 0.005, kf = 0.026499, ks = 16, 
 rho = 1.1492, rhos = 7860, mu = 18.923*10^-6, cp = 1.0069*10^3, 
 cps = 502.4}; u0 = 3; nu = mu/rho; om = 2 Pi f;
tflow = 100;
t0 = .3;
NV = 2 f tflow;
nn = Round[NV \[Pi]/(om t0)]
Ti = 307; q = 1000/Ti;

reg1 = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= L && 0 <= y <= d, {x, y}]; reg2 = 
 ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= L && -e <= y <= d, {x, y}];
UX[0][x_, y_] := 0;
VY[0][x_, y_] := 0;
P[0][x_, y_] := 0;
Tfs[0][x_, y_] := 307/Ti; appro = 
 With[{k = 2. 10^6}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];
ade[y_] := (ks + (kf - ks) appro[y])
rde[y_] := (cps rhos + (cp rho - cps rhos) appro[y]);

Monitor[Do[{UX[i], VY[i], P[i]} = 
    NDSolveValue[{{Inactive[
            Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
              u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], x] + 
          UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[u[x, y], x] + 
          VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[u[x, y], y] + (u[x, y] - UX[i - 1][x, y])/
           t0, Inactive[
            
            Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
              v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], y] + 
          UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[v[x, y], x] + 
          VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[v[x, y], y] + (v[x, y] - VY[i - 1][x, y])/
           t0, D[u[x, y], x] + D[v[x, y], y]} == {0, 0, 0} /. \[Mu] ->
         nu, {DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == u0*Sin[om*i*t0], 
         v[x, y] == 0}, 
        x == L (1 - Sign[Sin[om*i*t0]])/2 && 0 < y < d], 
       DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, 
        y == 0 || y == d]}, 
      DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0, 
       x == L (1 + Sign[Sin[om*i*t0]])/2 && 0 < y < d]}, {u, v, 
      p}, {x, y} \[Element] reg1, 
     Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}, 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0000005}}];
   ux = If[y <= 0, 0, UX[i][x, y]]; vy = If[y <= 0, 0, VY[i][x, y]];
   Tfs[i] = 
    NDSolveValue[{rde[
           y] ((ux*D[T[x, y], x] + 
              vy*D[T[x, y], y]) + (T[x, y] - Tfs[i - 1][x, y])/t0) - 
         Inactive[Div][
          ade[y]*Inactive[Grad][T[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 
        NeumannValue[q, y == -e], 
       DirichletCondition[{T[x, y] == 1}, 
        x == L (1 - Sign[Sin[om*i*t0]])/2 && 0 <= y <= d]}, 
      T, {x, y} \[Element] reg2, 
      Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {T -> 2}, 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0000001}}] // 
     Quiet;, {i, 1, nn}],ProgressIndicator[i,{1,nn}]]; // AbsoluteTiming

ListLinePlot[
 Table[{i t0, Tfs[i][0.5*L, -e/2]*Ti - 273.16}, {i, 0, nn}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"t(s)", "T(K)"}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

The above code runs the simulation for 100s flow-time for a flow oscillating with a frequency of 0.5Hz using the velocity profile $u = 3\sin(2*\pi*0.5*t)$. As can be seen in the above code the `Do` loop marches forward in time. Inside the loop the flow and temperature field is being solved at each iteration `nn`.

I modified the above code for a uni-directional flow, i.e., find a steady-state solution for a flow from left to right over the heated block. I removed the time-dependent terms inside the loop and the `nn`, instead of a time-stepper becomes an iterator to reach a converged solution. The code is:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

{f = 0.5; L = 0.040, d = 0.003, e = 0.005, kf = 0.026499, ks = 16, 
 rho = 1.1492, rhos = 7860, mu = 18.923*10^-6, cp = 1.0069*10^3, 
 cps = 502.4}; u0 = 3; nu = mu/rho; om = 2 Pi f;
Ti = 307; q = 1000/Ti;
uavg = (1/(Pi/om)) Integrate[u0*Sin[om*t], {t, 0, Pi/om}] // N
nn = 10;

reg1 = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= L && 0 <= y <= d, {x, y}]; reg2 = 
 ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= L && -e <= y <= d, {x, y}];
UX[0][x_, y_] := 0;
VY[0][x_, y_] := 0;
P[0][x_, y_] := 0;
Tfs[0][x_, y_] := 307/Ti; appro = 
 With[{k = 2. 10^6}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];
ade[y_] := (ks + (kf - ks) appro[y])
rde[y_] := (cps rhos + (cp rho - cps rhos) appro[y]);

Do[{UX[i], VY[i], P[i]} = 
    NDSolveValue[{{Inactive[
            Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
              u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], x] + 
          UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[u[x, y], x] + 
          VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[u[x, y], y], 
         Inactive[
            Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
              v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], y] + 
          UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[v[x, y], x] + 
          VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[v[x, y], y], 
         D[u[x, y], x] + D[v[x, y], y]} == {0, 0, 0} /. \[Mu] -> 
        nu, {DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == uavg, v[x, y] == 0}, 
        x == 0 && 0 < y < d], 
       DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, 
        y == 0 || y == d]}, 
      DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0, x == L && 0 < y < d]}, {u, v, 
      p}, {x, y} \[Element] reg1, 
     Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}, 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0000005}}];
   ux = If[y <= 0, 0, UX[i][x, y]]; vy = If[y <= 0, 0, VY[i][x, y]];
   Tfs[i] = 
    NDSolveValue[{rde[y] ((ux*D[T[x, y], x] + vy*D[T[x, y], y])) - 
         Inactive[Div][
          ade[y]*Inactive[Grad][T[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 
        NeumannValue[q, y == -e], 
       DirichletCondition[{T[x, y] == 1}, x == 0 && 0 <= y <= d]}, 
      T, {x, y} \[Element] reg2, 
      Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {T -> 2}, 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0000001}}] // 
     Quiet;, {i, 1, nn}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

*My question is*:

Why do we need an iterator to reach a steady-state solution?

In other words, the time-dependent code solved for the flow and temperature field at each time-step (but within each time-step there seemed to be no need for further iterations to reach a converged solution). Going by that logic, `NDSolve` should have been able to directly solve for the steady-state solution (i.e, without the time-dependent terms), but it cannot as I tried below:

```
{U, V, P} = 
 NDSolveValue[{{Inactive[
         Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
           u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], x] + 
       u[x, y]*D[u[x, y], x] + v[x, y]*D[u[x, y], y], 
      Inactive[
         Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
           v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], y] + 
       u[x, y]*D[v[x, y], x] + v[x, y]*D[v[x, y], y], 
      D[u[x, y], x] + D[v[x, y], y]} == {0, 0, 0} /. \[Mu] -> 
     nu, {DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == uavg, v[x, y] == 0}, 
     x == 0 && 0 < y < d], 
    DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, 
     y == 0 || y == d]}, 
   DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0, x == L && 0 < y < d]}, {u, v, 
   p}, {x, y} \[Element] reg1, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}, 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0000005}
```

I would like to have a descriptive explanation of this difference between modelling a transient system and a steady-state solution? In essence, why within each time-step in the transient solver there is no need of iteration ? However, a steady-state solution requires one to iterate. I hope I could clearly explain my query.

Comment: Please, pay attention, that in my code with `UX[i], VY[i], P[i]` we solve on every step the linear system of equations, while in your code with `{U, V, P}`  you try to solve nonlinear system. This is a big difference for `NDSolve`, since we use FEM.

Comment: Thankyou for your comment Alex. I do understand that in my last code block, I try to directly solve a highly non-linear system with significant convective terms. However, when I modified your original code to solve for the steady-problem (by removing the time terms, i.e., the second code block), it worked fine. Hence, I wanted to understand this basic difference between modelling a steady-state and a time-dependent system. It seems my understanding is flawed.

Comment: In my code the false transient method is implemented, it is why numerical solution converges to steady state in a case of the time term elimination - see explanation on  https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1433064?p_p_auth=4O8xgpur

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thankyou for the answer. I went to the link and found some helpful notes. One of your codes there on square driven lid cavity used the method of false transients, which is helpful. I have one other request. Can you run the first code block (i.e., reciprocating flow) for these parameter values `f=1, t0=0.15, tflow=700` (Other parameters remain same). I have seen that whenever I am giving a large `tflow`, the calculation stops midway with a kernel error, although I am running the calculation on a system with 16GB of memory.

Comment: Yes, you are right,  there are some unstably solutions. In your case just put `t0=0.3` to compute solution. Regardless your method at $t0\rightarrow \infty$, this is also nice method for some cases.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thankyou for verifying that the problem actually exists. Now, let me try to explain why I cannot keep `t0=0.3`. If my flow is oscillating/reciprocating at $1Hz$, that means the time period is $1s$, which implies that the flow changes direction every $0.5s$. Hence, to resolve this change in flow direction, I need to keep my step-size $<0.5s$. Keeping it `t0=0.3`, obviously satisfies this criterion but it means that I am only calculating at one time-step in each half-cycle, which is not a very good resolution. I will prefer at least $2$ time-steps, which `t0=0.15` achieves.

Comment: In any case, if my flow oscillates at $f=2Hz$, I will need a `t0=0.1` to properly resolve the flow reversal. The problem is, I need to run these calculations till a large `tflow`, until the system reaches a cyclic steady state, i.e., the temperature of the system (for ex. any point in the solid domain) oscillates around a mean value. And this `tflow` can get quite large if my heat input, i.e., `q` increases.

Comment: My modifications for $t0\rightarrow \infty$, was for a situation, where there is no flow oscillation at all. Instead, the flow just occurs from $x=0$ to $x=L$. And I was aiming for a steady-state temperature distribution. Do you think, there can be a way by which one can directly calculate the cyclic-steady state, when the flow velocity is oscillating, instead of marching forward through the entire transient period ? Should these be asked as a separate question ?

Comment: In your last code parameter `uavg` is not defined.

Comment: You can take `uavg=1.91`.

Comment: Ok, your code working with `uavg=1.91`. What about your question?

Comment: I have posted a separate question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277210/conjugate-heat-transfer-modelling-of-reciprocating-flow-crashes-for-long-flow-ti). Have a look. And thankyou for your help here.