# Refining mesh size leads to absurd results for a coupled heat transfer FEM model

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh, modeling, fluid-dynamics

I have been recently solving a conjugate heat transfer problem, which involves fully-reversing or reciprocating flow of fluid over a heated block of solid. The problem is 2D and the temperature field is being evaluated for both the solid and the fluid. The following code (courtesy Alex) uses the finite-element approach:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
{f = 8;
 L = 0.040, d = 0.003, e = 0.005, kf = 0.026499, ks = 16, 
 rho = 1.1492, rhos = 7860, mu = 18.923*10^-6, cp = 1.069*10^3, 
 cps = 502.4}; u0 = 3.0; nu = mu/rho; om = 2 Pi f;
tflow = 0.125;
t0 = tflow/100;
NV = 2 f tflow;
nn = Round[NV \[Pi]/(om t0)]
Ti = 307.0; q = 5000.0/Ti;

reg1 = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= L && 0 <= y <= d, {x, y}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= L && -e <= y <= d, {x, y}];

mesh = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{0, L}, {0, d}}, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-7];
mesh1 = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{0, L}, {-e, d}}, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-7];
UX[0][x_, y_] := 0;
VY[0][x_, y_] := 0;
P[0][x_, y_] := 0;
Tfs[0][x_, y_] := 307/Ti; appro = 
 With[{k = 2. 10^6}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];
ade[y_] := (ks + (kf - ks) appro[y])
rde[y_] := (cps rhos + (cp rho - cps rhos) appro[y]);
eqs = {Inactive[
      Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
        u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], x] + 
    UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[u[x, y], x] + 
    VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[u[x, y], y] + (u[x, y] - UX[i - 1][x, y])/t0, 
   Inactive[
      Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
        v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], y] + 
    UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[v[x, y], x] + 
    VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[v[x, y], y] + (v[x, y] - VY[i - 1][x, y])/t0, 
   D[u[x, y], x] + D[v[x, y], y]};
bc[i_] := {DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == u0*Sin[om*i*t0], 
     v[x, y] == 0}, x == L (1 - Sign[Sin[om*i*t0]])/2 && 0 < y < d], 
   DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, y == 0 || y == d],
    DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0, 
    x == L (1 + Sign[Sin[om*i*t0]])/2 && 0 < y < d]};

Monitor[Do[{UX[i], VY[i], P[i]} = 
      NDSolveValue[{eqs == {0, 0, 0} /. \[Mu] -> nu, bc[i]}, {u, v, 
        p}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
       Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
         "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}];, {i, 1, 
     nn}], ProgressIndicator[i, {1, nn}]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Monitor[Do[ux = If[y <= 0, 0, UX[i][x, y]];
   vy = If[y <= 0, 0, VY[i][x, y]];
   Tfs[i] = 
    NDSolveValue[{rde[y] ((ux*D[T[x, y], x] + vy*D[T[x, y], y])) - 
         Inactive[Div][
          ade[y]*Inactive[Grad][T[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 
        NeumannValue[q, y == -e], 
       DirichletCondition[{T[x, y] == 1}, 
        x == L (1 - Sign[Sin[om*i*t0]])/2 && 0 <= y <= d]}, 
      T, {x, y} \[Element] mesh1, 
      Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {T -> 2}}] //
      Quiet;, {i, 1, nn}], 
  ProgressIndicator[i, {1, nn}]] // AbsoluteTiming

Tsm[x_] = nn^-1 Sum[Tfs[i][x, -e/2]*Ti - 273.16, {i, 1, nn}];
Plot[Tsm[x], {x, 0, L}, PlotRange -> Full, GridLines -> Automatic]

Tfm[y_] = (1/nn) Sum[Tfs[i][L/2, y]*Ti - 273.16, {i, 1, nn}];
Plot[{ Tfm[y]}, {y, -e, d}, PlotRange -> Full, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

`Tsm[x]` and `Tfm[x]` are the cyclic average temperature profile in the solid (along the line `y=-e/2`, i.e., streamwise direction) and the cyclic average temperature profile at a particular cross-section (`x=L/2`), respectively. The above code works properly for the given mesh settings in the above code i.e., `MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-7`. However, when I attempt a grid-independence test, i.e., run the simulation for a finer mesh like `MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-8`, the results become absurd. Following are the plots for `Tsm[x]` and `Tfm[x]` at the finer mesh settings:

[image: Tsm[x]]
[image: Tfm[x]]

As can be seen, the values are absurdly high. For the coarser mesh, we get reasonable plots, like the following:

[image: Tsm[x]_CoarseMesh]
[image: Tfm[x]_CoarseMesh]

I think, that with a finer mesh, the results should stay same or get more accurate. I have tried with a smaller time step, i.e., `t0=tflow/500` with `MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-8`, but that did not help. How can this problem be resolved ?

**For Bounty**

The singularities have been removed by the accepted answer, by creating mesh in the non-dimensional space. However, problems arise when I conduct a grid-independence test, even using the modified code. The solutions `Tsm[x]` and `Tfm[x]` seem to converge to a particular solution up until `MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-3`. However, when the mesh size is reduced further using `MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-4`, they again diverge (although not absurdly).

These results have been summarized in excel sheets [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rOqq461CFlDPZ9XUT-bvXwnBhCxU50l4?usp=share_link). In these sheets Grid 1-4 refer to `MaxCellMeasure -> 5*10^-3`, `10^-3`, `5*10^-4` and `10^-4`, respectively. I do understand now that some numerical methods diverge when $h \rightarrow 0$, but converge until $h \rightarrow h_{min}$. My question is, if I would have started my calculation directly using `MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-4`, and then refined further, I would not be able to identify the optimum Mesh size where the solution is diverging. How can in such a scenario, one be assured that the solution is mesh independent ?

---

I tried accommodating the suggestions of @user21. I have used the following non-dimensionalisation scheme $u=U/u_0, x=X/d, y=Y/d, p=\frac{P}{\rho u_0^{2}}, \tau = \omega t$. $\omega=2\pi f$ is the flow reciprocation angular frequency, where $f$ is the frequency in Hz. Using this non-dimensional time allows us to march in time by $\pi$ intervals (at `pi` the b.c. are to be switched). With this scheme I have the following equations:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0$$

$$\frac{\omega d}{u_0}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau} + u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + v\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{Re}\big(\nabla^2 u\big)=0$$

$$\frac{\omega d}{u_0}\frac{\partial v}{\partial \tau} + u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + v\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}-\frac{1}{Re}\big(\nabla^2 v\big)=0$$

$$\omega d^2 \frac{\partial T}{\partial \tau}+u_0 d\big(u\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} + v\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\big)-\frac{k}{\rho c_p}\big(\nabla^2 T\big)=0$$

The temperature is kept in the dimensional form.

In the non-dimensional space, the initial condition then becomes $T(0,x,y)=0, u(0,x,y)=0, v(0,x,y)=0, p(0,x,y)=0$, while the boundary condition becomes, $u(\tau, 0, y)=\sin(t)$ and $-\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}=\frac{qd}{k_s}$ at $y=-e/d$. The fluid thermal boundary conditions then become $T(\tau, 0, y)=0, T(\tau+\pi, L/d, y)=0$. Utilizing the contributions from Oleksii's answer (which was solved for a different form of non-dimensionalized equation of the same problem), I have utilized the monolithic approach of adding a momentum sink term to the momentum equations and modelling both the solid and fluid domains in one go. Following is the modified code:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Needs["MeshTools`"]

L = 0.040 ;(*length of the channel*)
d = 0.003;(*depth of the fluid*)
e = 0.005;(*depth of the solid*)
l = L/d;(*dimensionless length*)
rhof = 1.1492;(*fluid density*)
rhos = 7860;(*density of solid*)
mu = 18.923*10^-6;(*dynamic viscosity*)
nu = mu/rhof;(*kinematic viscosity*)
ks = 16;(*conductivity of solid*)
kf = 0.026499;(*conductivity of liquid*)
cf = 1069;(*heat capacity of fluid*)
cs = 502.4;(*heat capacity of solid*)
AlphaF = kf/(cf*rhof);(*thermal diffusivity of fluid*)
AlphaS = ks/(cs*rhos);(*thermal diffusivity of solid*)
f = 2.0;(*flow oscillation frequency*)
period = 1/f;(*period*)
omega = 2*Pi/period;(*circular frequency*)
u0 = 1.;(*inflow velocity*)
q = 5000;(*heat flux density*)
Ti = 307;
re = d u0/(nu);
Pr = nu/AlphaF;
gamma = If[ElementMarker == 0, AlphaF/AlphaS, 1];
Nx = 30;(*number of elements in x-direction*)
NyF = 15;(*number of elements in y-direction in fluid*)
NyS = 5;(*number of elements in y-direction in solid*)
hy = 1./NyF;(*linear dimension of element in fluid*)

raster = {{{0, 0}, {l, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {l, 1}}};
MeshFluid = StructuredMesh[raster, {Nx, NyF}];

raster = {{{0, -e/d}, {l, -e/d}}, {{0, 0}, {l, 0}}};
MeshSolid = StructuredMesh[raster, {Nx, NyS}];

mesh = MergeMesh[MeshSolid, MeshFluid];
nodes = mesh["Coordinates"];
quads = mesh["MeshElements"][[1]][[1]];

mark = Table[z = Mean[nodes[[quads[[i]]]]][[2]];
   If[z < 0, 0, 1], {i, 1, Length[quads]}];
MeshTotal1 = 
  ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> nodes, 
   "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[quads, mark]}];
MeshTotal2 = MeshOrderAlteration[MeshTotal1, 2];
Clear[TopWall, BottomWall, reference, HeatInpBC, op, c, rampFunction, 
  sf, UinfProfile, Profile];

rampFunction[min_, max_, c_, r_] := 
 Function[t, (min*Exp[c*r] + max*Exp[r*t])/(Exp[c*r] + Exp[r*t])]
sf = rampFunction[0, 1, 0.25, 100];

Profile = 
  Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {hy, 1}, {1 - hy, 1}, {1, 0}}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Uc = 1/NIntegrate[Profile[y], {y, 0, 1}];(*calibration coefficient*)
UinfProfile[y_] := Uc*Profile[y];(*inflow velocity profile*)

appro = With[{k = 2. 10^6}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];
ade[y_] := (ks + (kf - ks) appro[y])
rde[y_] := (cs rhos + (cf rhof - cs rhos) appro[y]);

c = If[ElementMarker == 0, 10^6, 
  0];(*define the constant in momentum sink term*)op = {{{u[t, x, y], 
      v[t, x, y]}}.Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][({{-(1/re), 0}, {0, -(1/re)}}.Inactive[Grad][
       u[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({x}\)]\(p[t, x, y]\)\) + 
   c u[t, x, y] + (omega d/u0) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({t}\)]\(u[t, x, 
      y]\)\), {{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}}.Inactive[Grad][
     v[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][({{-(1/re), 0}, {0, -(1/re)}}.Inactive[Grad][
       v[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({y}\)]\(p[t, x, y]\)\) + 
   c v[t, x, y] + (omega d/u0) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({t}\)]\(v[t, x, y]\)\), \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({x}\)]\(u[t, x, y]\)\) + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({y}\)]\(v[t, x, 
     y]\)\), (u0 d) ({u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][
       T[t, x, y], {x, y}]) - 
   Inactive[
     Div][((ade[y]/rde[y]) Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
     y}] + (omega d^2) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({t}\)]\(T[t, x, y]\)\)};

TopWall = 
  DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, y == 1];
BottomWall = 
  DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, y <= 0];
(*setting pressure value in single node*)
reference = DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0., x == 0 && y == 0];

HeatInpBC = NeumannValue[(d q)/(ks Ti), y == -e/d];

Clear[UxLast, UyLast, TLast, PLast];
UxLast[x_, y_] := 0;
UyLast[x_, y_] := 0;
TLast[x_, y_] := 0;
PLast[x_, y_] := 0;
SolutData = {};
SolutData1 = {};
SolutData2 = {};
K = 10;(*number of half-periods considered*)
Monitor[Do[Clear[u, v, p, t, HeatDBC];
  ti = (k - 1)*Pi;
  tf = ti + Pi;
  Clear[HeatDBC, Inflow, Outflow, bcs, ic, UxFun, UyFun, pressure, 
   TFun];
  If[k == 1, 
   Inflow = 
    DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == sf[t]*Sin[t]*UinfProfile[y], 
      v[t, x, y] == 0}, x == 0 && y > 0 && y < 1];
   Outflow = 
    DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == sf[t]*Sin[t]*UinfProfile[y], 
      v[t, x, y] == 0}, x == l && y > 0 && y < 1], 
   Inflow = 
    DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == Sin[t]*UinfProfile[y], 
      v[t, x, y] == 0}, x == 0 && y > 0 && y < 1];
   Outflow = 
    DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == Sin[t]*UinfProfile[y], 
      v[t, x, y] == 0}, x == l && y > 0 && y < 1]];
  If[OddQ[k] == True, 
   HeatDBC = 
    DirichletCondition[T[t, x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y >= 0 && y <= 1], 
   HeatDBC = 
    DirichletCondition[T[t, x, y] == 0, x == l && y >= 0 && y <= 1]];
  ic = {u[ti, x, y] == UxLast[x, y], v[ti, x, y] == UyLast[x, y], 
    p[ti, x, y] == PLast[x, y], T[ti, x, y] == TLast[x, y]};
  bcs = {TopWall, BottomWall, Inflow, Outflow, reference, HeatDBC};
  {UxFun, UyFun, pressure, TFun} = 
   NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0, HeatInpBC}, bcs, ic}, {u, v, p, 
     T}, {x, y} \[Element] MeshTotal2, {t, ti, tf}, 
    MaxStepSize -> 8.37*10^-2, 
    Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"IDA", 
        "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 2}, 
      "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
          "PDESolveOptions" -> {"LinearSolver" -> "Pardiso"}, 
          "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}}}}];
  UxLast = 
   ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal2}, Last[UxFun["ValuesOnGrid"]]];
  UyLast = 
   ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal2}, Last[UyFun["ValuesOnGrid"]]];
  TLast = 
   ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal2}, Last[TFun["ValuesOnGrid"]]];
  PLast = 
   ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal1}, 
    Last[pressure["ValuesOnGrid"]]];
  n = Length[TFun["ValuesOnGrid"]];
  n1 = Length[UxFun["ValuesOnGrid"]];
  n2 = Length[UyFun["ValuesOnGrid"]];
  m = If[k < K, n - 1, n];
  AppendTo[SolutData, 
   Take[Transpose[{TFun[[3]][[1]], TFun["ValuesOnGrid"]}], {1, m, 
     10}]];
  m1 = If[k < K, n1 - 1, n1];
  AppendTo[SolutData1, 
   Take[Transpose[{UxFun[[3]][[1]], UxFun["ValuesOnGrid"]}], {1, m1, 
     10}]];
  m2 = If[k < K, n2 - 1, n2];
  AppendTo[SolutData2, 
   Take[Transpose[{UyFun[[3]][[1]], UyFun["ValuesOnGrid"]}], {1, m2, 
     10}]];, {k, 1, K}], ProgressIndicator[k, {1, K}]]

Clear[TsolVec, TFun]
TsolVec = 
  Interpolation[Flatten[SolutData, 1], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
TFun[t_?NumericQ] := 
 ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal2}, TsolVec[t]]

Plot[TFun[t][0.5 l, -e/(2 d)]*Ti, {t, 0, K*Pi}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full]
```

The last line plots the solid temperature (dimensional) at a point for the simulated non-dimensional time.

[image]

However, as can be seen the temperature values are considerably blown up.

Comment: What makes you believe that the messages you hit with Quiet is not the root of the issue?

Comment: You **never** needs to specify Interpolation order for single dependent variable  equations.

Comment: Why do you use two different meshes?

Comment: I would avoid using the iterative approach for the Navier-Stokes equation but solve the equation in one go. That will be more efficient. If you need to ramp up the inflow velocity, you should use ParametricNDSolve for that. With your code you have made some choices that miss an explanation in the text. To really answer your second question you'd need to get this FEM solver in a more standard form to perform experiments, I think.

Comment: @user21 Thankyou for the comments. If I understand correctly, I should be solving the Navier-Stokes equation without the `(u[x, y] - UX[i - 1][x, y])/t0` but instead use  `D[u[t,x,y],t]` and leave the time-stepping to `NDSolve` by using the `MaxStepSize` command ? In that case, the iterator `i` should only control the switching of the boundary conditions at the end of each half-period to execute the flow reciprocation, right ? Also, the energy equation still needs to be solved separately or that too should be in conjunction with the momentum and continuity ?

Comment: Two different meshes are used to solve the flow and energy equation separately as the flow occurs only in $x \in [0,L]$ and $y \in [0,d]$, while the energy equation is being solved for both the solid and the fluid across $x \in [0,L]$ and $y \in [-e,d]$.

Comment: On solving the energy equation without the `//Quiet` command, there is a warning like `InterpolatingFunction::femdmval`. The full text reads `InterpolatingFunction::femdmval: Input value {0.,-1.66667} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function.`

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Have a look in the documentation [SolvingPDEwithFEM](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1405680271) in the fluid flow section.

Comment: @user21 I tried applying your suggestions, by non-dimensionalizing the equations again and attempting with a monolithic approach. However, my temperature values are significantly blown up. Have a look at the added section after the line. I am guessing, there might be some problem with the way I am specifying the Neumann heat flux condition at the base.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a typical numerical instability due to FEM matrix inversion. On the fine mesh there are big numbers in Navier-Stokes equation of about $1/h^2$, therefore at $h\rightarrow 0$ we have singular matrix to be inverted. If we plot velocity

```
DensityPlot[UX[41][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> False, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

we will see singular like point with value of about $\pm 10^6$.
To avoid singularity we can increase $h$ by mapping `reg1, reg2` to

```
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= L/d && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= L/d && -e/d <= y <= 1, {x, y}];
```

Then option `MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-8` with `QuadElement` number of about 12000 in `mesh` can be replaced by option `MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-3` with `QuadElement` number of  13504. Hence we can make research with new numerical model as follows

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
{f = 8;
 L = 0.040, d = 0.003, e = 0.005, kf = 0.026499, ks = 16, 
 rho = 1.1492, rhos = 7860, mu = 18.923*10^-6, cp = 1.069*10^3, 
 cps = 502.4}; u0 = 3.0; nu = mu/rho; om = 2 Pi f;
tflow = 0.125;
t0 = tflow/100;
NV = 2 f tflow;
nn = Round[NV \[Pi]/(om t0)]
Ti = 307.0; q = 5000.0/Ti;

reg1 = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= L/d && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= L/d && -e/d <= y <= 1, {x, y}];


mesh = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{0, L/d}, {0, 1}}, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-3]
mesh1 = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{0, L/d}, {-e/d, 1}}, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-3]

re = d u0/nu; re1 = 1/re

UX[0][x_, y_] := 0;
VY[0][x_, y_] := 0;
P[0][x_, y_] := 0;

eqs = {Inactive[
      Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}} . 
       Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], x] + 
    UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[u[x, y], x] + 
    VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[u[x, y], y] + (u[x, y] - UX[i - 1][x, y])/t0, 
   Inactive[
      Div][({{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}} . 
       Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + D[p[x, y], y] + 
    UX[i - 1][x, y]*D[v[x, y], x] + 
    VY[i - 1][x, y]*D[v[x, y], y] + (v[x, y] - VY[i - 1][x, y])/t0, 
   D[u[x, y], x] + D[v[x, y], y]};
bc[i_] := {DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == Sin[om*i*t0], v[x, y] == 0},
     x == L /d (1 - Sign[Sin[om*i*t0]])/2 && 0 < y < 1], 
   DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, y == 0 || y == 1],
    DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0, 
    x == L /d (1 + Sign[Sin[om*i*t0]])/2 && 0 < y < 1]};


Monitor[Do[{UX[i], VY[i], P[i]} = 
      NDSolveValue[{eqs == {0, 0, 0} /. \[Mu] -> re1, bc[i]}, {u, v, 
        p}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
       Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
         "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}];, {i, 1, 
     nn}], ProgressIndicator[i, {1, nn}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Let check velocity in the central point of channel

```
ListPlot[Table[UX[i][L/d/2, 1/2], {i, 100}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 1]

It looks fine, therefore we can compute temperature as well

```
Tfs[0][x_, y_] := 307/Ti; appro = 
 With[{k = 2. 10^6}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];
ade[y_] := (ks + (kf - ks) appro[y])/(d u0)
rde[y_] := (cps rhos + (cp rho - cps rhos) appro[y]);

Monitor[Do[ux = If[y <= 0, 0, UX[i][x, y]];
   vy = If[y <= 0, 0, VY[i][x, y]];
   Tfs[i] = 
    NDSolveValue[{rde[y] ((ux*D[T[x, y], x] + vy*D[T[x, y], y])) - 
         Inactive[Div][
          ade[y]*Inactive[Grad][T[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 
        NeumannValue[q/(u0 ), y == -e/d], 
       DirichletCondition[{T[x, y] == 1}, 
        x == L/d (1 - Sign[Sin[om*i*t0]])/2 && 0 <= y <= 1]}, 
      T, {x, y} \[Element] mesh1, 
      Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {T -> 2}}] //
      Quiet;, {i, 1, nn}], 
  ProgressIndicator[i, {1, nn}]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Visualization

```
Tsm[x_] = nn^-1 Sum[Tfs[i][x, -e/d/2]*Ti - 273.16, {i, 1, nn}];
Plot[Tsm[x], {x, 0, L/d}, PlotRange -> Full, GridLines -> Automatic]

Tfm[y_] = (1/nn) Sum[Tfs[i][L/d/2, y]*Ti - 273.16, {i, 1, nn}];
Plot[{Tfm[y]}, {y, -e/d, 1}, PlotRange -> Full, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Really appreciate this detailed analysis. So you have now created the mesh in non-dimensional space, which allows for finer grid but with larger numbers, right ? In this scheme, the non-dimensionalisation is done as $u=u'/u0$, so the flux is $q/u0$ ?

Comment: @Avrana Yes it is, in this case we use nondimensional equations for velocity with scale `u0, d`. Please note, that `re` is the Reynolds number, and `1/re= 0.00182958`.

Comment: I tried this new modified code and ran a mesh independence test. I started from `MaxCellMeasure -> 5*10^-3` and went down till `MaxCellMeasure -> 5*10^-4`. The results of `Tsm[x]` and `Tfm[y]` converging down till this refinement. However, when I tried `MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-4`, the profiles showed a different behaviour (although not unphysical like the old code). Since, these calculations take a long time, I am attaching my results in the form of an excel sheet [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rOqq461CFlDPZ9XUT-bvXwnBhCxU50l4?usp=share_link).

Comment: Please have a look. You will see that Grid 1 to 3 are decreasing but Grid 4 suddenly goes in the reverse direction.

Comment: @Avrana Could you show velocity as well?

Comment: I will post the density plot Alex, but i need to rerun with `MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-4` as the kernel is closed now. But the plot for `ListPlot[Table[UX[i][L/d/2, 1/2], {i, 100}], PlotRange -> All]` was similar to what you posted in the answer.

Comment: @Avrana Is velocity similar or differ for different grids?

Comment: I will post the results in some time

Comment: I have updated the results with velocity grid independence tests [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rOqq461CFlDPZ9XUT-bvXwnBhCxU50l4?usp=share_link). It seems there is no singularity in the velocity field.

Comment: We should note that some numerical methods diverge at $h \rightarrow 0$, and converge at  $h \rightarrow h_{min}>0$.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mean to say that I should refine the mesh size only till it is converging to a particular solution. If further refinement leads to a different solution, it is indicative that the solution is diverging and such refinement should be avoided ?

Comment: Yes, it is. See, for instance, https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40219/different-sources-of-error-in-finite-element-computations

Comment: @AlexTounev Will the time-marching version of this scaled energy equation look like this ? `rde[y] ((ux*D[T[x, y], x] +  vy*D[T[x, y], y]) + (T[x, y] - Tfs[i - 1][x, y])/t0) - 
  Inactive[Div][ade[y]*Inactive[Grad][T[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 
 NeumannValue[q/(u0), y == -e/d], DirichletCondition[{T[x, y] == 1}, 
 x == L/d (1 - Sign[Sin[om*i*t0]])/2 && 0 <= y <= 1]` . Just the time -dependent term will be added ?

Comment: Yes it is. But scaled `t0` should be `u0 t0/L` to compare with unscaled version.

Comment: Thankyou. Also, it seems I might have found the answer for the bounty question. It seems that the Courant (or the CFL number) with the time-step I used earlier was $>>1$. It was almost $40$. However, we want $C<1$. To achieve a $C=0.5$, we can decide on a time step to as $t_o=C∗\delta x/u_0$, where $\delta x $ is the element length in the x− direction. I will post some results when calculations are over

Comment: I have awarded the bounty to your answer as this still solves the original problem. I did not post any further results about which I mentioned in my last comment because the problem reappeared after certain grid refinement even with the CFL approach.

Comment: @Avrana This is FEM matrix inversion problem.  Note, that problem coming from large value `rde[y]`.  We can avoid this problem just using appropriate normalization, for example,  ade[y_] := (ks + (kf - ks) appro[y])/(d u0 cps rhos ); rde[y_] := (1 + (cp rho /(cps rhos-1) appro[y]);` and `q/(u0  cps rhos)`.

Comment: Thankyou for the  comment Alex. I tested the normalized approach by using the new functions. Also I changed the flux boundary condition suitably to `q/(u0  cps rhos)`. However, the problem still persists. You can find the details [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rOqq461CFlDPZ9XUT-bvXwnBhCxU50l4?usp=share_link). This is a CFL based test where I change grid size but simultaneously refine step-size to maintain a CFL=0.5. The problem occurs for Set 5 and Set 6, as highlighted in the sheets. Also, I apologize for being too bothering.

Comment: @Avrana Could you increase number of element with options `MaxCellMeasure ->5 10^-4` and `MaxCellMeasure ->2 10^-4`?

Comment: Do you mean to say that I should rerun calculations with these mesh settings for f=2, u0=0.05? With `MaxCellMeasure ->5 10^-4`, (which leads to 26865 elements in the fluid domain) to maintain a CFL=0.5, I will need a `t0=6.7*10^-4`. I have run a calculation.

Comment: Hi Alex, the calculation for `MaxCellMeasure ->5 10^-4` is complete and that for `2 10^-4` is running from the last day as `t0` is very small. I will update the results, when its done. Meanwhile, I have tried another attempt by non-dimension. the equations again. I wanted to ask, is there some special way of defining the `NeumannValue` b.c. for NDSolve? I have observed that you define it as `q/u0` in your codes and change it as you change the definition of rde[y].  I tried this for these new gov. equations and it gave reasonable temp field but all multiplied by `10^7`.

Comment: @Avrana It could be better to ask a new question in a new topic.

Comment: I have asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278446/modelling-heat-transfer-in-periodically-reversing-flow)