# Modelling heat transfer in periodically reversing flow

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, modeling, heat-equation

This is a heat transfer problem, which involves reciprocating (fully-reversing) fluid flow over a heated block of solid. The objective is to determine the temperature field in the solid and the fluid as the system reaches a quasi-steady state (i.e., temperature oscillates around a mean). I have asked a version of this question before [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262999/reciprocating-flow-in-a-channel-over-a-heated-surface/263402?noredirect=1#comment694808_263402) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277743/refining-mesh-size-leads-to-absurd-results-for-a-coupled-heat-transfer-fem-model), and I have received excellent answers by Alex and Oleksii. However, I had some problems with grid-independence tests and less than expected temperature values, so I decieded to go ahead from the scratch and non-dimensionalize the equations:

The domain is $X \in [0, L], Y \in [-e, d]$ with heat flux $q$ applied at $Y=-e$. The solid extends from $Y \in [-e, 0]$, while the fluid domain is $Y \in [0,d]$. The fluid oscillates with $U = U_0 \sin(\omega t)$, where $\omega = 2 \pi f$. The dimensional temperature $T^*$ is non-dimensionalised as:

$$T = \frac{T^* - T^*_{inlet}}{\alpha}$$
where $\alpha =\frac{qd}{k_s}$. It must be noted that fresh fluid at some temperature $T_{inlet} = 0$ enters the domain in each half-cycle. For some simplicity, this $T_{inlet}$ can be assumed to be equal to the initial temperature $T_{initial} = 0$ of the system.

Now I want to solve a different set of non-dimensional equations describing the same problem. The non-dimensional scheme I used is $u=U/u_0, x=X/d, y=Y/d, p=\frac{P}{\rho u_0^{2}}, \tau = \omega t$, $Re=\frac{\rho U_0 d}{\mu}$.

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0 \tag 1$$

$$\frac{\omega d}{u_0}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau} + u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + v\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{Re}\big(\nabla^2 u\big)=0 \tag 2$$

$$\frac{\omega d}{u_0}\frac{\partial v}{\partial \tau} + u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}-\frac{1}{Re}\big(\nabla^2 v\big)=0 \tag 3$$

$$\omega d^2 \frac{\partial T}{\partial \tau}+u_0 d\big(u\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} + v\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\big)-\frac{k}{\rho c_p}\big(\nabla^2 T\big)=0 \tag 4$$

The b.c. becomes:

$$u(\tau)= \sin(\tau) \tag 5$$ at $x=0$ and $-\frac{\partial T}{\partial y} = 1 \tag 6$ at $y=-e/d$.

Using the previous answers I received, I have tried to solve the above set of equations using the following code. I acknowledge that this framework of implementation was proposed by Oleksii, which I have modified. I have also borrowed concepts from Alex's answers:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Needs["MeshTools`"]

L = 0.040 ;(*length of the channel*)
d = 0.003;(*depth of the fluid*)
e = 0.005;(*depth of the solid*)
l = L/d;(*dimensionless length*)
rhof = 1.1492;(*fluid density*)
rhos = 7860;(*density of solid*)
mu = 18.923*10^-6;(*dynamic viscosity*)
nu = mu/rhof;(*kinematic viscosity*)
ks = 16;(*conductivity of solid*)
kf = 0.026499;(*conductivity of liquid*)
cf = 1069;(*heat capacity of fluid*)
cs = 502.4;(*heat capacity of solid*)
AlphaF = kf/(cf*rhof);(*thermal diffusivity of fluid*)
AlphaS = ks/(cs*rhos);(*thermal diffusivity of solid*)
f = 1.0;(*flow oscillation frequency*)
period = 1/f;(*period*)
omega = 2*Pi/period;(*circular frequency*)
u0 = 0.5;(*inflow velocity*)
q = 5000;(*heat flux density*)
Ti = 307;
re = d u0/(nu);
Pr = nu/AlphaF;(*Pandtl number*)

gamma = If[ElementMarker == 0, AlphaF/AlphaS, 1];
sigma = kf/ks;

(*Meshing*)
Nx = 30;(*number of elements in x-direction*)
NyF = 15;(*number of elements in y-direction in fluid*)
NyS = 5;(*number of elements in y-direction in solid*)
hy = 1./NyF;(*linear dimension of element in fluid*)
raster = {{{0, 0}, {l, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {l, 1}}};
MeshFluid = StructuredMesh[raster, {Nx, NyF}];(*FE mesh in fluid*)

raster = {{{0, -e/d}, {l, -e/d}}, {{0, 0}, {l, 0}}};
MeshSolid = StructuredMesh[raster, {Nx, NyS}];(*FE mesh in solid*)

mesh = MergeMesh[MeshSolid, MeshFluid];
nodes = mesh["Coordinates"];
quads = mesh["MeshElements"][[1]][[1]];
mark = Table[z = Mean[nodes[[quads[[i]]]]][[2]];
   If[z < 0, 0, 1], {i, 1, Length[quads]}];
MeshTotal1 = 
  ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> nodes, 
   "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[quads, mark]}];
MeshTotal2 = MeshOrderAlteration[MeshTotal1, 2];

(*Incident veolcity profile*)
Clear[TopWall, BottomWall, reference, HeatInpBC, op, c, rampFunction, 
  sf, UinfProfile, Profile];

rampFunction[min_, max_, c_, r_] := 
 Function[t, (min*Exp[c*r] + max*Exp[r*t])/(Exp[c*r] + Exp[r*t])]
sf = rampFunction[0, 1, 0.25, 100];

Profile = 
  Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {hy, 1}, {1 - hy, 1}, {1, 0}}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Uc = 1/NIntegrate[Profile[y], {y, 0, 1}];(*calibration coefficient*)
UinfProfile[y_] := Uc*Profile[y];(*inflow velocity profile*)

(*Functions defining thermo-physical properties of solid and fluid. This allows solving a single energy equation*)
appro = With[{k = 2. 10^6}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];
ade[y_] := (ks + (kf - ks) appro[y])
rde[y_] := (cs rhos + (cf rhof - cs rhos) appro[y]);

(*PDE operator definitions. Sink term added to momentum equations to make velocity zero in the solid domain, which is supplied to the energy equation*)
c = If[ElementMarker == 0, 10^6, 
  0]; op = {{{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}}.Inactive[Grad][
     u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][({{-(1/re), 0}, {0, -(1/re)}}.Inactive[Grad][
       u[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({x}\)]\(p[t, x, y]\)\) + 
   c u[t, x, y] + ((omega d) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({t}\)]\(u[t, x, y]\)\))/
   u0, {{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}}.Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}] +
    Inactive[
     Div][({{-(1/re), 0}, {0, -(1/re)}}.Inactive[Grad][
       v[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({y}\)]\(p[t, x, y]\)\) + 
   c v[t, x, y] + ((omega d) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({t}\)]\(v[t, x, y]\)\))/u0, \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({x}\)]\(u[t, x, y]\)\) + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({y}\)]\(v[t, x, 
     y]\)\), (u0 d) {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][
      T[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
   Inactive[Div][(ade[y] Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}])/
    rde[y], {x, y}] + (omega d^2) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({t}\)]\(T[t, x, y]\)\)};

(*Boundary conditions*)
TopWall = 
  DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, y == 1];
BottomWall = 
  DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, y <= 0];
reference = DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0., x == 0 && y == 0];
HeatInpBC = NeumannValue[(q d)/(ks), y == -(e/d)]
```

Assuming an initial and fluid inlet temperature of $0$, the following solves for the velocity and temperature fields:

```
Clear[UxLast, UyLast, TLast, PLast];
UxLast[x_, y_] := 0;
UyLast[x_, y_] := 0;
TLast[x_, y_] := 0;
PLast[x_, y_] := 0;
SolutData = {};
SolutData1 = {};
SolutData2 = {};
K = 10;(*number of half-periods considered*)
Monitor[Do[Clear[u, v, p, t, HeatDBC];
  ti = (k - 1)*Pi;
  tf = ti + Pi;
  Clear[HeatDBC, Inflow, Outflow, bcs, ic, UxFun, UyFun, pressure, 
   TFun];
  If[k == 1, 
   Inflow = 
    DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == sf[t]*Sin[t]*UinfProfile[y], 
      v[t, x, y] == 0}, x == 0 && y > 0 && y < 1];
   Outflow = 
    DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == sf[t]*Sin[t]*UinfProfile[y], 
      v[t, x, y] == 0}, x == l && y > 0 && y < 1], 
   Inflow = 
    DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == Sin[t]*UinfProfile[y], 
      v[t, x, y] == 0}, x == 0 && y > 0 && y < 1];
   Outflow = 
    DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == Sin[t]*UinfProfile[y], 
      v[t, x, y] == 0}, x == l && y > 0 && y < 1]];
  If[OddQ[k] == True,
   HeatDBC = 
    DirichletCondition[T[t, x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y >= 0 && y <= 1],
   HeatDBC = 
    DirichletCondition[T[t, x, y] == 0, x == l && y >= 0 && y <= 1]];
  
  ic = {u[ti, x, y] == UxLast[x, y], v[ti, x, y] == UyLast[x, y], 
    p[ti, x, y] == PLast[x, y], T[ti, x, y] == TLast[x, y]};
  
  bcs = {TopWall, BottomWall, Inflow, Outflow, reference, HeatDBC};
  
  {UxFun, UyFun, pressure, TFun} = 
   NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0, HeatInpBC}, bcs, ic}, {u, v, p, 
     T}, {x, y} \[Element] MeshTotal2, {t, ti, tf}, 
    MaxStepSize -> 1*10^-2, 
    Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"IDA", 
        "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 2}, 
      "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
          "PDESolveOptions" -> {"LinearSolver" -> "Pardiso"}, 
          "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}}}}];
  
  UxLast = 
   ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal2}, Last[UxFun["ValuesOnGrid"]]];
  UyLast = 
   ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal2}, Last[UyFun["ValuesOnGrid"]]];
  TLast = 
   ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal2}, Last[TFun["ValuesOnGrid"]]];
  PLast = 
   ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal1}, 
    Last[pressure["ValuesOnGrid"]]];
  n = Length[TFun["ValuesOnGrid"]];
  n1 = Length[UxFun["ValuesOnGrid"]];
  n2 = Length[UyFun["ValuesOnGrid"]];
  m = If[k < K, n - 1, n];
  AppendTo[SolutData, 
   Take[Transpose[{TFun[[3]][[1]], TFun["ValuesOnGrid"]}], {1, m, 
     10}]];
  m1 = If[k < K, n1 - 1, n1];
  AppendTo[SolutData1, 
   Take[Transpose[{UxFun[[3]][[1]], UxFun["ValuesOnGrid"]}], {1, m1, 
     10}]];
  m2 = If[k < K, n2 - 1, n2];
  AppendTo[SolutData2, 
   Take[Transpose[{UyFun[[3]][[1]], UyFun["ValuesOnGrid"]}], {1, m2, 
     10}]];, {k, 1, K}], ProgressIndicator[k, {1, K}]]

(*Generating solution functions*)
Clear[TsolVec, TFun]
TsolVec = 
  Interpolation[Flatten[SolutData, 1], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
TFun[t_?NumericQ] := 
 ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal2}, TsolVec[t]]

Clear[UxsolVec, UxFun]
UxsolVec = 
  Interpolation[Flatten[SolutData1, 1], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
UXFun[t_?NumericQ] := 
 ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal2}, UxsolVec[t]]

Clear[UysolVec, UyFun]
UysolVec = 
  Interpolation[Flatten[SolutData2, 1], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
UYFun[t_?NumericQ] := 
 ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal2}, UysolVec[t]]
```

I then plotted the temperature history at a point in the solid and temperature profile in the solid. **These results look qualitatively correct but their magnitudes are far blown up**:

1. Temperature history for 70 half-periods

```
Plot[(TFun[t][0.5 l, -e/(2 d)]), {t, 0, K*Pi}, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Temperature history of a point inside solid for 35 oscillation cycles]

2. Cyclic average temperature profile in the solid

```
Tsm[x_] = (2 π)^-1 (Sum[TFun[t][x, -e/d/2], {t, (K - 2) π, K π}]);
Plot[Tsm[x], {x, 0, L/d}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Cyclic average temperature profile in the solid]

3. I plotted the time variation of the $x-$velocity at the channel mid and found no unreasonable values

```
Plot[{UXFun[t][l/2, 1/2]}, {t, (K - 2) Pi, K Pi}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: time variation of the x-velocity at the channel mid]

This implies that there must be something wrong with the way I am implementing the energy equation and its boundary conditions. However, I have not been able to figure out what.

Comment: Code consists of several typos. I can't reproduce solution. But it looks like you need to make this correction  `HeatInpBC = NeumannValue[(q d)/(cs rhos), y == -(e/d)];`

Comment: Have edited code, you can try now. Will try this edit suggested by you. However, as per the derivation $-k_s \frac{\partial T}{\partial y} = q$, then how is the Neumann value $\frac{qd}{c_s \rho_s}$ ?

Comment: @Avrana I will try to figure out tomorrow in this code. It is blackout in my city now. It seems that something wrong in coefficients

Comment: @Avrana Please, look at your equation for `T` where you use `Inactive[Div][(ade[y] Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}])/rde[y], {x, y}]`. In FEM algorithm it generates bc as `-ade[-e]/rde[-e] D[T,y]=qd/ks`, and it is why you have temperature about 10^6. Normally it should be `-D[T,y]=qd/ks`, To equalize sides you need to multiply on `ade[-e]/rde[-e]=ks/(cs rhos)`.

Comment: If you suspect an issue with the heat equation you could use `HeatTransferPDEComponent` in stead or to double check what you have. But if the scale is wrong, does not not suggest an error in the non dimensionalization?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have now non-dimensioanlized the energy equation using a new scheme, which I have added in the OP. With this nd, the b.c. at the base becomes $\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}=1$ at $y=-e/d$. So in FEM it becomes `NeumannValue[(ks)/(cs rhos), y == -(e/d)]`. With these settings, it works and I am running tests now.

Comment: @OleksiiSemenov Thanks, give it a try at your convenience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's the velocity, temperature and pressure are measured in units $u_0,\, dq/k_s,\, \rho u_0^2$ respectively, time and space coordinates are measured in units $d/u_0$ and $d$. In this case the governing equations in dimensionless form are as follows:

Navier-Stokes equations:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial t}+ (\vec{V}\cdot\nabla)\vec{V}=-\nabla P+\frac{1}{Re}\Delta \vec{V}-C\cdot\vec{V}     
 \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\nabla\cdot \vec{V}=0     
 \end{equation}

Energy conservation:

\begin{equation}
\gamma Pe\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+(\vec{V}\cdot\nabla)T \right)=\nabla\cdot\left(\gamma\nabla T\right)     
 \end{equation}

where $Re=u_0d/\nu$ is the Reinolds number, $Pe$ is the variable in space Peclet number
\begin{equation}
  Pe=\begin{cases}
   u_0d/\alpha_s, & \{x,y\}\in solid \\
   u_0d/\alpha_f, & \{x,y\}\in fluid \\      
  \end{cases} 
\end{equation}
Coefficient $C$ in penalty term is as follows:
\begin{equation}
  C=\begin{cases}
   10^6, & \{x,y\}\in solid \\
   0, & \{x,y\}\in fluid \\      
  \end{cases} 
\end{equation}
Coefficient $\gamma$:

\begin{equation}
  \gamma=\begin{cases}
   1, & \{x,y\}\in solid \\
   k_f/k_s, & \{x,y\}\in fluid \\      
  \end{cases} 
\end{equation}

Equations contain variable in space coefficients. Solution of such PDE are described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#938383864). In OP the temperature on inflow boundary is changed rapidly at the beginning of every half-period. The boundary conditions at this moment are not consistent with initial conditions here and calculated temperature on inlet can differ from $0$. I propose to change the temperature on inlet gradually up to 0 during the time which is small compared with period of oscillation.

**Input parameters and mesh generation:**

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Needs["MeshTools`"]

L = 0.040;(*length of the channel*)
d = 0.003;(*depth of the fluid*)
e = 0.005;(*depth of the solid*)
l = L/d;(*dimensionless length*)
rhof = 1.1492;(*fluid density*)
rhos = 7860;(*density of solid*)
mu = 18.923*10^-6;(*dynamic viscosity*)
nu = mu/rhof;(*kinematic viscosity*)
ks = 16;(*conductivity of solid*)
kf = 0.026499;(*conductivity of liquid*)
cf = 1069;(*heat capacity of fluid*)
cs = 502.4;(*heat capacity of solid*)
AlphaF = kf/(cf*rhof);(*thermal diffusivity of fluid*)
AlphaS = ks/(cs*rhos);(*thermal diffusivity of solid*)
f = 1.0;(*flow oscillation frequency*)
period = 1/f;(*period*)
omega = 2*Pi/period;(*circular frequency*)
u0 = 0.5;(*inflow velocity*)
q = 5000;(*heat flux density*)
Ti = 307; (*inflow temperature*)
re = d *u0/nu; (*reinolds number*)
gamma = If[y < 0, 1, kf/ks]; (*relation of conductivities*)
Pe = If[y < 0, u0*d/AlphaS, u0*d/AlphaF];  (*Peclet number*)
c = If[y < 0, 10^6, 0];(*constant in momentum sink term*)

Nx = 50;(*number of elements in x-direction *)
NyF = 5;(*number of elements in y-direction in fluid*)
NyS = 5;(*number of elements in y-direction in solid*)
hy = 1./NyF;(*linear dimension of element in fluid*)
raster = {
   {{0, 0}, {l, 0}},
   {{0, 1}, {l, 1}}
   };
MeshFluid = StructuredMesh[raster, {Nx, NyF}];(*FE mesh in fluid*)
raster = {
   {{0, -e/d}, {l, -e/d}},
   {{0, 0}, {l, 0}}
   };
MeshSolid = StructuredMesh[raster, {Nx, NyS}];(*FE mesh in solid*)
MeshTotal1 = MergeMesh[MeshSolid, MeshFluid];
MeshTotal2 = MeshOrderAlteration[MeshTotal1, 2];
Show[MeshTotal2["Wireframe"], ImageSize -> 600]
```

**Implementation of PDE and BC**

```
Clear[TopWall, BottomWall, reference, HeatInpBC, op, rampFunction, sf,
   UinfProfile, Profile, x, y, t];
rampFunction[min_, max_, c_, r_] := 
 Function[t, (min*Exp[c*r] + max*Exp[r*t])/(Exp[c*r] + Exp[r*t])]
sf = rampFunction[0, 1, 0.25, 50];
Profile = 
 Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {hy, 1}, {1 - hy, 1}, {1, 0}}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1]
UinfProfile[y_] := Profile[y]/NIntegrate[Profile[y], {y, 0, 1}]

op = {
   D[u[t, x, y], t] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][({{-1/re, 0}, {0, -1/re}} . 
       Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
      y}] + {{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}} . 
     Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + D[p[t, x, y], x] + 
    c*u[t, x, y], 
   D[v[t, x, y], t] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][({{-1/re, 0}, {0, -1/re}} . 
       Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
      y}] + {{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}} . 
     Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}] + D[p[t, x, y], y] + 
    c*v[t, x, y], D[u[t, x, y], x] + D[v[t, x, y], y],
   Pe*gamma*D[T[t, x, y], t] + 
    Pe*gamma*{{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}} . 
      Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
    Inactive[Div][{{-gamma, 0}, {0, -gamma}} . 
      Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]
   
       };

TopWall = 
  DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, y == 1];
BottomWall = 
  DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, y <= 0];
(*setting the pressure value in single node*)
reference = DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0., x == 0 && y == 0];
HeatInpBC = NeumannValue[1, y == -e/d];
```

**Solution of PDE**

Here only 25 periods are considered

```
Clear[UxLast, UyLast, TLast, PLast];
UxLast[x_, y_] := 0;
UyLast[x_, y_] := 0;
TLast[x_, y_] := 0.;
PLast[x_, y_] := 0;
SolutData = {};
K = 50;(*number of half period considered*)

Do[
      Clear[u, v, p, t, HeatDBC];
  ti = (k - 1)*0.5 period*u0/d;
  tf = ti + 0.5 period*u0/d;    
 
 Clear[HeatDBC, Inflow, Outflow, bcs, ic, UxFun, UyFun, pressure, 
  TFun];
 If[k == 1,
     Inflow = 
   DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 
      sf[t*d/u0]*Sin[t*(omega*d)/u0]*UinfProfile[y], v[t, x, y] == 0},
     x == 0 && y > 0 && y < 1];
     Outflow = 
   DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 
      sf[t*d/u0]*Sin[t*(omega*d)/u0]*UinfProfile[y], v[t, x, y] == 0},
     x == l && y > 0 && y < 1],
  
     Inflow = 
   DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 
      Sin[t*(omega*d)/u0]*UinfProfile[y], v[t, x, y] == 0}, 
    x == 0 && y > 0 && y < 1];
     Outflow = 
   DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 
      Sin[t*(omega*d)/u0]*UinfProfile[y], v[t, x, y] == 0}, 
    x == l && y > 0 && y < 1]
    ];
 
 (*temperature on inlet changes gradually up to 0 during dt*)
 dt = 0.01*0.5 period*u0/d;
 If[OddQ[k] == True,
      HeatDBC = 
   DirichletCondition[
    T[t, x, y] == 
     If[t <= ti + dt, TLast[0, y] - TLast[0, y]*(t - ti)/dt, 0], 
    x == 0 && y > 0 && y <= 1],
      HeatDBC = 
   DirichletCondition[
    T[t, x, y] == 
     If[t <= ti + dt, TLast[l, y] - TLast[l, y]*(t - ti)/dt, 0], 
    x == l && y > 0 && y <= 1]
     ];
 
    ic = {u[ti, x, y] == UxLast[x, y], v[ti, x, y] == UyLast[x, y], 
   p[ti, x, y] == PLast[x, y], T[ti, x, y] == TLast[x, y]};
    bcs = {TopWall, BottomWall, Inflow, Outflow, reference, HeatDBC};
 
 Monitor[
  {UxFun, UyFun, pressure, TFun} = 
   NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0, HeatInpBC}, bcs, ic}, {u, v, p, 
     T}, {x, y} \[Element] MeshTotal2, {t, ti, tf},
    
    MaxStepSize -> 5*10^-3*0.5 period*u0/d,
    Method -> {
      
      "TimeIntegration" -> {"IDA", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 2},
      
      "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines",
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
          "PDESolveOptions" -> {"LinearSolver" -> "Pardiso"}, 
          "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}}}}
    , EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])]
  , currentTime];
 
   UxLast = 
  ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal2}, Last[UxFun["ValuesOnGrid"]] ];
   UyLast = 
  ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal2}, 
   Last[UyFun["ValuesOnGrid"]]];
   TLast = 
  ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal2}, Last[TFun["ValuesOnGrid"]]  ];
   PLast = 
  ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal1}, 
   Last[pressure["ValuesOnGrid"]]  ];
 
 n = Length[TFun["ValuesOnGrid"]]; 
 m = If[k < K, n - 1, n];
  AppendTo[SolutData,
                      
  Take[Transpose[{TFun[[3]][[1]], TFun["ValuesOnGrid"]}], {1, m, 10}]
                    ]
 
     , {k, 1, K} 
     ]
```

**Postprocessing**

```
Clear[TsolVec, TFun]
TsolVec = 
  Interpolation[Flatten[SolutData, 1], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
TFun[t_?NumericQ] := 
 ElementMeshInterpolation[{MeshTotal2}, TsolVec[t]]
```

Dynamics of temperature in point $\{L/2,d/2\}$ looks as follows:

```
pic1=Plot[Ti + (d*q)/ks TFun[t*u0/d][l/2, 0.5], {t, 0,K*0.5*period}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.003], RGBColor[0, 0, 0]}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"time", "Temperature"}, 
   FrameStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0], BaseStyle -> 14, ImageSize -> 500,
    LabelStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0]];
```

[image]

Let's look at temperature dynamics in points $\{0,d/2\}$ and $\{L,d/2\}$ during first 5 periods:

```
pic2 = Plot[{Ti + (d*q)/ks TFun[t*u0/d][0, 0.5], 
   Ti + (d*q)/ks TFun[t*u0/d][l, 0.5]}, {t, 0, 5*period}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.003], 
     RGBColor[0, 0, 0]}, {Thickness[0.003], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"time [s]", "Temperature"}, 
  FrameStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0], BaseStyle -> 14, ImageSize -> 500, 
  LabelStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0], 
  PlotLegends -> {"{0,0.5d}", "{L,0.5d}"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for the well explained answer. I see that you have managed to remove the discrepancy regarding the Inflow b.c. in this version. I will go through the solution diligently and get back.

Comment: I have run the code and will be running some more tests. It certainly satisfies the b.c.(s) in each period. Meanwhile, I have some queries. $(1)$ I see that you have set up the non-dimensional equations using the $Pe$ number, which is treated as a space variable coefficient (SVC). As a result, you had to introduce $\gamma$, which again is a SVC. Why could we just not use $\frac{k}{\rho c_p}$ as the SVC ?

Comment: $(2)$ This is just for my understanding. The flux b.c. from derivation is $-\frac{\partial T}{\partial y} = 1$, but as per FEM algorithm of MMA it is `gamma*D[T,y]=gamma*1`, but since $\gamma$ is 1 in solid, the RHS remains 1, right? $(3)$ While defining the `Inflow` boundary condition, you have used dimensional time. However, the step size given in dimensionless time. Why has this been done ? $(4)$ To slowly let the temperature at inlet reach the b.c., you have used `T[t,0,y]==TLast[t,0, y] - TLast[t,0, y]*(t - ti)/dt`. (This is great!) Is this using the slope of the temperature-time curve ?

Comment: As to (1),(2) your questions. There are many ways to non-dimensionalize these PDEs. As to me, it's the most convenient way to introduce $Re, Pe$ numbers. These numbers have clear physical meaning. It this case we have BC for heat flux as follows: $-\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}|_{y=-e/d}=1$. And this BC should be implemented by `NeumannValue[1, y == -e/d]`. Also dimentionless parameter $\gamma=k/k_s$ arises which is variable in space.

Comment: (3) In the MMA implementation all the variables are non-dimensional, including time. The non-dimensional time is measured in units $d/u_0$. Therefore the time step used in numerical solution is also non-dimensional.

Comment: I set maximum non-dimensional time step which corresponds to $5\cdot 10^{-4}\cdot period$ sec.I did not studied what time step is optimal for this problem

Comment: (4) Yes, exactly. At the beginning of every half-period the temperature decreases linearly from `Tlast[t,0,y]` to 0 during time $0.01period\cdot d/u_0$ which corrsponds to 0.01* period sec. This allows to make consistency between BC and i.c on inlet.

Comment: Thankyou for the clarifications. It would be of interest to you that there is considerable difference in results of this modified approach and earlier results (from earlier I dont mean your earlier answer, but my implementation of your code as posted in this question, i.e. after the suggested correction in the comments). You can find the comparison [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-y2Ia4-18paeHyAmNswvRltF4ykBqkyF/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: I made some observations. I built an exactly similar model in the COMSOL simulation environment. You were right about the need of b.c. being satisfied in each period. COMSOL too does that, as can be seen in the snapshot attached [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ilMRgrOtQvKG_c72A7zOl3Onk8Dtm3bJ/view?usp=share_link). Have a look at points `(2.5,6.5) and (37.5,6.5)`, which represents the inlet and outlets in the COMSOL model. They drop down to exactly 307 K (the specified inlet temperature), in each half-period, as you have succeeded in achieving in this answer.

Comment: However, the main issue is overall temperature evolution. This profile is very different between COMSOL and Mathematica model for similar heat input, geometry, materials and `u0=1., f=0.25 Hz`. You can find a comparison (for a point inside the solid domain) [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pIQQ1Qe-DJ67cZbDCrz4qAABVZGkAlPm/view?usp=share_link). As can be seen, the MMA model almost reaches a quasi-steady state within 400s, while the COMSOL model is still showing an increase even after 2000s. Please note that I have even kept the thermo-physical properties equivalent for both SS and air.

Comment: An additional point to note is that although I am solving a 2D model in COMSOL, it requires the user to supply a depth in the out-of-plane, i.e., %z-$ direction. By default, it is set to 1.0 m, and I have left it so, because I think even our MMA model assumes a unit 1 m depth as we supply all dimensions in m.

Comment: Yes, significant difference

Comment: I have checked that energy balance is satisfied in your proposed solution.First I calculated the average temperature at left and right end using `Tfm1[t_?NumericQ] := (1/1) NIntegrate[TFun[t][0, y], {y, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 12];` and `Tfm2[t_?NumericQ] :=  MaxRecursion -> 12];`. Then I calculated the energy flowing out of domain in one time period. So I used $\frac{1}{0.5 period}\int_t^{t+\frac{period}{2}} c_p \rho (1\dot d) u(t) T_{avg}(0) \mathrm{d}t$ for `x=0` end and  $\frac{1}{0.5 period}\int_{t+\frac{period}{2}}^{t+period} c_p \rho (1\dot d) u(t) T_{avg}(l) \mathrm{d}t$ for `x=l` end

Comment: In code, these become `(1/(0.5)) NIntegrate[rhof (1 d) u0 cf Sin[ t*omega] (q d/ks Tfm1[t*u0/d]), {t, (K - 1)*0.5*period, K*0.5*period}, MaxRecursion -> 20]` and `(1/(0.5)) NIntegrate[rhof (1 d) u0 cf Sin[t*omega] (q d/ks Tfm2[t*u0/d]), {t, (K - 2)*0.5*
period, (K - 1)*0.5*period}, MaxRecursion -> 20]`. For `f=0.5, u0=0.05`, these lead to `-0.336504` and `0.336504`, which add up to `0`. This corresponds very well with the physics of the system that says, the net energy inflow/outflow should be `0` in the cyclic steady-state

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It satisfies properly all boundary conditions, initial conditions, and energy conservation. It is also detailed and well-explained. Hence, I accept  it. I will try to look into the COMSOL issue separately.

Comment: I have changed a little bit the code.

Comment: Yes I saw the edits. But still have not run the updated version because I am on phone. Do they offer speed up ?

Comment: No, I have just simplified the code. I did not studied the optimal time step. The computations of course are time consuming

Comment: Hi, How have you been? I know this is too late, but I have been trying to rerun this code for cases with $f>1 Hz$, especially I tried with `f = 2.0, u0=1.75`. Even with much refined mesh and a smaller time step, it seems I cannot go beyond the first half-period, i.e., K=1. The code remains stuck for quite some time and throws the error `NDSolveValue::indexss: The DAE solver failed at t = 145.8333. The solver is intended for index 1 DAE systems and structural analysis indicates that the DAE is structurally singular`. If possible for you, have a look into it. Good day.

Comment: Please note that `t=145.833` is the exact non-dimensional time at which flow reversal takes place. This is how I know the problem occurs at just the end of the first half-period.

Comment: @Avrana Hello! I will look tomorrow

Comment: @Avrana Yes, there is a problem with given input parameters. I can not propose right now how to overcome this.

Comment: Thankyou for looking into and running the problem. Give it a try at your own time. Its good that the error could be reproduced. I am trying to solve the issue myself too. I think the high flow velocity requires small time step to ensure Courant number $< 0.5$, according to the relation $C=u*\frac{\delta t}{\delta x}$, where $\delta x$ is the mesh element length in the flow domain and $\delta t$ is the time-step. That leads to a step-size of the order of $10^{-4}$. However, this too somehow did not work.