# Meshing an irregular domain using quads to solve conjugate heat transfer problem

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh, heat-equation

I am trying to mesh the following domain to solve a heat transfer + fluid flow problem:

[image: computational domain]

The continuity+momentum equations are to be solved in $ABGH$, while the energy equation is to be solved across the entire domain, i.e., $ABCDEFGH$ (basically line $CF$ is the solid-fluid interface). To generate mesh for $ABGH$, I used the following:

```
Needs["MeshTools`"]
L = 0.050, d = 0.003, e = 0.005, delta = 0.010, l = L/d + 2 delta/d
mesh = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{0, l}, {0, 1}}, MaxCellMeasure -> 8 10^-3];

(*ElementMesh[{{0., 23.3333}, {0., 1.}}, {QuadElement["<" 3132 ">"]}]*)
```

which produces the following:

[image: ABGH mesh]

Now, to mesh the entire domain, I use the tool `StructuredMesh` in the following code (about which I learned from the various answers on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137479/how-to-generate-a-mesh-with-quadrilateral-elements) post):

```
raster = {{{0, 0}, {delta/d, 0}, {delta/d, -e/d}, {delta/d + L/d, -e/d}, {delta/d + L/d, 0}, {l, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {delta/d, 1}, {delta + L/(3 d), 1}, {delta + (2 L/(3 d)), 1}, {delta/d + L/d, 1}, {l, 1}}}
mesh2 = StructuredMesh[raster, {200, 20}]
mesh2["Wireframe"]
(*ElementMesh[{{0., 23.3333}, {-1.66667, 1.}}, {QuadElement["<" 4000 ">"]}]*)
```

This produces the following:

[image: ABCDEFGH mesh]

To produce this, I have basically defined the domain using two lines, each having six points  through the `raster` command. However, as visible the mesh quality is pretty bad.

**How should the $ABCDEFGH$ domain be meshed to achieve a smooth quad mesh as $ABGH$? Also, it will be beneficial if I can have the same number of elements in the ABGH portion, while meshing ABCDEFGH as it had when it was individually meshed.**

Also, this leads me to think, can both these sub-domains be meshed separetly and then joined?

**Update 1**
Upon recommendations in the comment, I tried the following:

`MergeMesh` for different size domains work on `BoundaryMesh` type object. Atleast, that is what I found in the documentation.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Needs["MeshTools`"]
{L = 0.050, d = 0.003, e = 0.005, delta = 0.010, l = L/d + 2 delta/d};
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= l && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[
   delta/d <= x <= l - delta/d && -e/d <= y <= 0, {x, y}];
reg3 = RegionUnion[reg1, reg2];

bm1 = ToBoundaryMesh[reg1]
bm2 = ToBoundaryMesh[reg2]
bm3 = MergeMesh[{bm1, bm2}]
meshfluid = ToElementMesh[bm1, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01]["Wireframe"]
meshenergy = ToElementMesh[bm3, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01]["Wireframe"]
(*meshsolid = ToElementMesh[bm2, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01]["Wireframe"]*)
```

This leads to the following:

[image: meshenergy_triangular]

However, this is a triangular mesh. `TriangleToQuadMesh` does not work on `meshenergy` object. Also if you see the image above closely, the refinement at the interface (i.e., internal boundary) is localised to a few regions. Also `MeshCellCount` does not work when I try it on `meshenergy`, `meshfluid` or `meshsolid`.

**Update 2**

*A comparison among tri and quad mesh results*

I used the answer given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278446/modelling-heat-transfer-in-periodically-reversing-flow) by Oleksii, to solve the problem of conjugate heat transfer (reciprocating flow over a heated block). Obviously, I have utlised the domain described in this question. Both the cases have been run for a flow time of `5` seconds, with similar `MaxStepSize` setting

> **Triangular mesh results**

Created using the Update 1 in this question.

Please note that `ToElementMesh` creates a 2nd order mesh. To interpolate the `p` which is supplied with `p->1` in `NDSolve`, I had to create a 1st order mesh using `MeshOrderAlteration`

> > 1. Mesh statistics

[image]

> > 2. Solid temperature variation at point `((delta+L)/d/2,-e/d/2)`

[image]

> > 3. Fluid temperature variation at both the inlets of the fluid domain

[image]

> **Quad mesh results**

Mesh generated using Oleksii's answer in this question

Similar number of elements in y-direction in the fluid domain (compared to trimesh) could be achieved with the setting `NyF`. Hence, total number of elements is lesser than trimesh.

> > 1. Mesh statistics

[image]

> > 2. Solid temperature variation at point `((delta+L)/d/2,-e/d/2)`

[image]

> > 3. Fluid temperature variation at both the inlets of the fluid domain

[image]

In conclusion, the results seem fairly simialr. I will run these tests for longer flow times and report if there are any discrepancies that arise. However, it seems quadmesh allows more control over element size in such regular domains (thus leading to lesser total element count).

**Addendum to Update 2**
The following contour plots, show the difference in solution between the quad and triangle mesh (at the same flow time). Please note that the triangle mesh is generated using the answer of @user21.

> > Solid temperature

[image]

> > Fluid temperature
> > Have replaced `AspectRatio->Automatic` to `AspectRatio->1/2`, as the fluid region is thin.

[image]

Note: Total elements for triangle mesh: 3246
Total elements for quad mesh:  1248

Comment: You can try to build uniform meshes separately for fluid and solid domains and then to join them by `MergeMesh` from `MeshTools`

Comment: @OleksiiSemenov I gave it a try.  See Update.

Comment: Great. A few comments. You should not use the mesh from update 1 - this already looks bad and I suspect it has holes or some such. For the triangular mesh use the mesh that I used for the quad mesh generation.

Comment: If you want to put in the work, what would be much more informative is to plot the difference between the solutions. But again, for this type of problem I would not expect much of a difference in the solution. Triangle elements are typically a bit more efficient to evaluate.

Comment: @user21 Thankyou for the comments. See "Addendum to Update 2". The fluid domain shows considerable difference it seems.

Comment: @user21 On another note, (this is in context to the [linked](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278446/modelling-heat-transfer-in-periodically-reversing-flow) question, where the problem is described) I had to put an insulated region before the heated length `0` to `delta/d`, to circumvent the issue of pinning that happens if a constant Dirichlet condition (fluid inlet) shares a node with a Neumann condition (solid edge). For such scenarios COMSOL uses an `Inflow` boundary condition, which models the fluid inlet as a flux condition.

Comment: You can read about the description of the `Inflow` condition [here](https://www.comsol.com/blogs/using-the-inflow-boundary-condition-in-nonisothermal-flow-simulations/). Can such b.c. be implemented as part of Mathematica `NDSolve`  in future? This becomes important when conduction heat transfer near the inlet is not dominated by advective heat transfer., i.e., Low Re flows and small dimensions.

Comment: @Avrana, I had  quick look at the link, which of the equations (number) are you interested in? To me it looks like they are variants of NeuamnnValues and it should be possible to do this today; if I have understood things correctly. One other thing you might want to do is add your requests (a thickness parameter for the heat equation and/or this inflow condition) [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199163/future-enhancements-for-the-finite-element-method).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function `MergeMesh` from [MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) package allows to join separate meshes. Let's take advantage of this useful function for this problem.

```
Needs["MeshTools`"]
L = 0.050; d = 0.003; e = 0.005; delta = 0.010; 
l = L/d + 2 delta/d;

NxS = 40;
NyS = 10;
MeshSolid = 
  RectangleMesh[{delta/d, -e/d}, {(L + delta)/d, 0}, {NxS, NyS}];

NxF = 10;
NyF = 10;
MeshFluid1 = RectangleMesh[{0, 0}, {delta/d, 1}, {NxF, NyF}];
MeshFluid2 = RectangleMesh[{(delta + L)/d, 0}, {l, 1}, {NxF, NyF}];
MeshFluid3 = RectangleMesh[{(delta)/d, 0}, {(L + delta)/d, 1}, {NxS, NyF}];
MeshFluid = MergeMesh[MergeMesh[MeshFluid1, MeshFluid3], MeshFluid2]

MeshTotal = MergeMesh[MeshFluid, MeshSolid];
MeshTotal["Wireframe"]
```

[image: FEmesh]

Comment: Much much thanks. This is exactly what I wanted. I wasnt aware of the `RectangleMesh` function too. Keeping similar `NxS` probably helped. I would also like to ask, if such rectangle meshes are better for fluid flow problems ?

Comment: @Avrana, it would be interesting to hear what you find when you use this mesh in place of a triangulated region. I doubt it is going to make much of a difference, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Avrana I will respond on your question about tri mesh vs quads mesh a little bit later. It is blackout in my city now and I am on smartphone

Comment: @user21 I will post some results in some time. On move right now.

Comment: @Avrana about tri mesh vs quad mesh in cfd. It is popular debatable issue. And as far as I know the choice of proper mesh depends on particular problem in question. May be this work https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339311266_Mesh_Assessment_Quality_Issues will be interesting for you. As concerns the problem you are working on, I think you should carry out the computational experiments with different meshes and then make a choice. Interesting to look at these results.

Comment: @Avrana The points $\{\frac{\delta}{d},0\}$ and $\{\frac{L+\delta}{d},0\}$ are certainly the trouble spots where the large temperature gradients appears. And it would be better to make gradual mesh refinement there.

Comment: @OleksiiSemenov Thankyou for the comments. I have been away, so could not review them earlier. Please look at Update 2 in my question, presenting a comparison among tri and quad mesh results using your last answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278446/modelling-heat-transfer-in-periodically-reversing-flow). You can see, I have added an insulated portion before the heated length. This is to resolve the problem of pinning in the previous domain shape, where the Dirichlet boundary (fluid) had shared nodes with Neumann boundary (solid edge).

Comment: I will go through the reference you have suggested. Thank you.

Comment: @user21 I have updated the question with a comparison between tri and quad mesh results, as requested. Have a look.

Answer (score 4):

A different approach might be to use `ToQuadMesh`:

```
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
L = 0.050; d = 0.003; e = 0.005; delta = 0.010; l = L/d + 2 delta/d;
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0, 0}, {delta/d, 
      0}, {delta/d, -e/d}, {delta/d + L/d, -e/d}, {delta/d + L/d, 
      0}, {2*delta/d + L/d, 0}, {L/d + 2*delta/d, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 1}, {2, 5}}]}];
bmesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
quadMesh = ToQuadMesh[mesh];
quadMesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Not, quite what you were looking for but perhaps an alternative option. Note, that the internal boundary is not respected by `ToQuadMesh`. If you specify region markers then it works:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{{L/2, 0.9}, 1, 1}, {{L/2, 0.1}, 1, 2}}];
quadMesh = ToQuadMesh[mesh];
quadMesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for this. I will test this mesh too. I hope the `RegionMarker` can be used to assign separate properties to each zone?

Comment: The `RegionMarker` can indeed do this. The documentation gives some pretty good examples of use cases.