# Implementation of FEM to steady-state coupled fluid flow and heat transfer

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, modeling, heat-equation, fluid-dynamics

This is a steady-state conjugate heat transfer problem (the time-independent version of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278446/modelling-heat-transfer-in-periodically-reversing-flow) problem). The problem is conjugate as the energy equation is being solved in thermally connected solid and fluid domain. It describes 2D-flow of fluid over a heated solid block. I presumed it would be straightforward with the `NDSolve` `fem` option, but alas I ran into errors:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Needs["MeshTools`"]

L = 0.040 ;(*length of the channel*)
d = 0.003;(*depth of the fluid*)
e = 0.005;(*depth of the solid*)
l = L/d;(*dimensionless length*)
rhof = 1.1492;(*fluid density*)
rhos = 7860;(*density of solid*)
mu = 18.923*10^-6;(*dynamic viscosity*)
nu = mu/rhof;(*kinematic viscosity*)
ks = 16;(*conductivity of solid*)
kf = 0.026499;(*conductivity of liquid*)
cf = 1069;(*heat capacity of fluid*)
cs = 502.4;(*heat capacity of solid*)
AlphaF = kf/(cf*rhof);(*thermal diffusivity of fluid*)
AlphaS = ks/(cs*rhos);(*thermal diffusivity of solid*)
f = 1.0;(*flow oscillation frequency*)
period = 1/f;(*period*)
omega = 2*Pi/period;(*circular frequency*)
u0 = 0.05;(*inflow velocity*)
q = 5000;(*heat flux density*)

uavg = N[\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), FractionBox[\(π\), \(omega\)]]\(u0\ Sin[omega\ t] \[DifferentialD]t\)\)/(π/omega)];
re = d uavg/(nu);

(*Meshing*)
Nx = 70;(*number of elements in x-direction*)
NyF = 50;(*number of elements in y-direction in fluid*)
NyS = 40;(*number of elements in y-direction in solid*)
hy = 1./NyF;(*linear dimension of element in fluid*)
raster = {{{0, 0}, {l, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {l, 1}}};
MeshFluid = StructuredMesh[raster, {Nx, NyF}];(*FE mesh in fluid*)
raster = {{{0, -e/d}, {l, -e/d}}, {{0, 0}, {l, 0}}};
MeshSolid = StructuredMesh[raster, {Nx, NyS}];(*FE mesh in solid*)
mesh = MergeMesh[MeshSolid, MeshFluid];
nodes = mesh["Coordinates"];
quads = mesh["MeshElements"][[1]][[1]];
mark = Table[z = Mean[nodes[[quads[[i]]]]][[2]];
      If[z < 0, 0, 1], {i, 1, Length[quads]}];
MeshTotal1 = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> nodes, "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[quads, mark]}];
MeshTotal2 = MeshOrderAlteration[MeshTotal1, 2];

(*Fluid inflow profile*)
Clear[TopWall, BottomWall, reference, HeatInpBC, op, c, rampFunction, 
Profile = 
  Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {hy, 1}, {1 - hy, 1}, {1, 0}}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Uc = 1/NIntegrate[Profile[y], {y, 0, 1}];(*calibration coefficient*)
UinfProfile[y_] := Uc*Profile[y];(*inflow velocity profile*)

(*Material property switching function*)
appro = With[{k = 2. 10^6}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];
ade[y_] := (ks + (kf - ks) appro[y])
rde[y_] := (cs rhos + (cf rhof - cs rhos) appro[y]);

(*Stationary momentum, continuity and energy operator*)
c = If[ElementMarker == 0, 10^6, 
  0]; op = {{{u[x, y], v[x, y]}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][({{-(1/re), 0}, {0, -(1/re)}}.Inactive[Grad][
       u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \({x}\)]\(p[x, y]\)\) + 
   c u[x, y], {{u[x, y], v[x, y]}}.Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][({{-(1/re), 0}, {0, -(1/re)}}.Inactive[Grad][
       v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \({y}\)]\(p[x, y]\)\) + c v[x, y], \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \({x}\)]\(u[x, y]\)\) + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \({y}\)]\(v[x, y]\)\), {u[x, y], 
     v[x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][(u0 d) T[x, y], {x, y}] - 
   Inactive[Div][(ade[y] Inactive[Grad][T[x, y], {x, y}])/
    rde[y], {x, y}]};

(*Boundary conditions*)
TopWall = DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, y == 1];
BottomWall = DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, y <= 0];
HeatInpBC = NeumannValue[(ks)/(cs rhos), y == -(e/d)];
reference = DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0., x == l && y == 0];Clear[u, v, p, t, HeatDBC];
Clear[HeatDBC, Inflow, Outflow, bcs, UxFun, UyFun, pressure, TFun];
Inflow = DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 1, v[x, y] == 0}, 
   x == 0 && y > 0 && y < 1];
Outflow = 
  DirichletCondition[{p[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, 
   x == l && y > 0 && y < 1];
HeatDBC = DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y >= 0 && y <= 1];
bcs = {TopWall, BottomWall, Inflow, Outflow, reference, HeatDBC};

(*Solution*)
{UxFun, UyFun, pressure, TFun} = 
  NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0, HeatInpBC}, bcs}, {u, v, p, 
    T}, {x, y} \[Element] MeshTotal2, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}, 
   InitialSeeding -> {u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0, T[x,y]==0}];
```

On solving this leads to the following error:
[image: error screenshot]

It reads

> FindRoot::nosol: Linear equation encountered that has no solution.
> FindRoot::sszero: The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the function value is still greater than the tolerance prescribed by the AccuracyGoal option.

As can be seen in code, I have also tried to provide an initial seed for the system `InitialSeeding -> {u[x, y] == 1, v[x, y] == 0, T[x,y]==0}`, but to no avail. Also, I have kept the fluid velocity low `u0=0.05` (`uavg` is lower actually), which should be rendering the non-linearity to be low. What should be changed to find a stationary solution to this problem ?

**Update**

If the energy equation is non-dimensionalised as $T=\frac{T^*}{\frac{qd}{k_s}}, u =\frac{u^*}{u_{avg}}, v =\frac{v^*}{u_{avg}}$, it becomes:

$$u_{avg} d \rho c_p \bigg(u \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\bigg) -k \nabla^2 T=0$$
with the boundary condition $-\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}=1$ at $y=-e/d$.

> Then for MMA FEM, the boundary conditon should become `NeumannValue[ks, y==-e/d]`

After some recommendations in the comments, I have updated my approach. Please copy code till the definition of `re` from the already posted code.

```
Ti = 307.;
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= L/d && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= L/d && -e <= y <= 1, {x, y}];

mesh = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{0, L/d}, {0, 1}}, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 5 10^-4];
mesh1 = ToElementMesh[FullRegion[2], {{0, L/d}, {-e/d, 1}}, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 5 10^-4];

op = {{{u[x, y], v[x, y]}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][({{-(1/re), 0}, {0, -(1/re)}}.Inactive[Grad][
        u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \({x}\)]\(p[x, 
      y]\)\), {{u[x, y], v[x, y]}}.Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][({{-(1/re), 0}, {0, -(1/re)}}.Inactive[Grad][
        v[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \({y}\)]\(p[x, y]\)\), \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \({x}\)]\(u[x, y]\)\) + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \({y}\)]\(v[x, y]\)\)};
TopWall = DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, y == 1];
BottomWall = DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, y <= 0];
reference = DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0., x == l && y == 0];

Clear[u, v, p, t];
Inflow = DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 1, v[x, y] == 0}, 
   x == 0 && y > 0 && y < 1];
Outflow = 
  DirichletCondition[{p[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, 
   x == l && y > 0 && y < 1];
bcs = {TopWall, BottomWall, reference, Inflow, Outflow};

{UxFun, UyFun, pressure} = 
  NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0}, bcs}, {u, v, p}, {x, y} ∈ 
    mesh, Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}];
DensityPlot[UxFun[x, y], {x, 0, l}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> Automatic]
appro = With[{k = 2. 10^6}, ArcTan[#1 k]/\[Pi] + 1/2 &];
ade[y_] := (ks + (kf - ks) appro[y])
rde[y_] := (cs rhos + (cf rhof - cs rhos) appro[y]);

ux = If[y <= 0, 0, UxFun[x, y]];
vy = If[y <= 0, 0, UyFun[x, y]];

T = NDSolveValue[{ uavg d rde[y] (ux \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({x}\)]\(T[x, y]\)\) + vy \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({y}\)]\(T[x, y]\)\)) - 
      Inactive[Div][(ade[y] Inactive[Grad][T[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
        y}] == NeumannValue[ks , y == (-e/d)], 
    DirichletCondition[{T[x, y] == 0}, x == 0 && 0 <= y <= 1]}, 
   T, {x, y} \[Element] mesh1, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {T -> 2}}];

DensityPlot[T[x, y], {x, 0, l}, {y, -e/d, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]

DensityPlot[T[x, y], {x, 0, l}, {y, -e/d, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]

Plot[{Ti + T[x, -e/d/2]*(q d/ks), Ti + T[x, 1/4]*(q d/ks)}, {x, 0, l}]
```

The solid (at $y=\frac{-e/d}{2}$) and fluid (at $y=\frac{1}{4}$) temperature profiles are:

[image: Solid Fluid temperature profiles]

Some issues:

1. While solving the energy equation, the following warnings are delivered:

[image: Warnings]

Are these serious?

2. If I want to calculate the average solid temperature (line-integrated along its height, i.e., $y-$ direction), what should be the way? Basically, I want to calculate:

$$T_{s,avg}(x) = \frac{1}{e/d}\int_{-e/d}^0 T(x,y)\mathrm{d}y$$

Currently I tried using:

`T1[x_] = (1/(e/d)) NIntegrate[Ti + T[x, y]*(q d/ks), {y, -e/d, 0}]`

3. Let us assume from experiments, I know the length, width of a block to be $L,W$ (in m) to which some $Q$ (in W) heat is supplied. Now imagine, I am modelling this system in 2D (in Mathematica), where my model only has the length ($L$) feature and not the width ($W$). In this scenario, I have to emulate the heat input as a flux ($q′′$, `q` in this question) condition (Neumann value). How should I calculate this flux, to replicate the experiment ? Should it be $q = \frac{experimetal \space Q}{L∗1}$ or $q = \frac{experimental \space Q}{L∗W}$? Similar argument also follows for deciding the `uavg` value for the simulation as volumetric flow rate is known from experiments. Should it be $\frac{experimental \space flowate}{d*1}$ or $\frac{experimental \space flowate}{d*W}$ for the simulation.

**Bounty**

Let us look at the energy balance scenario. Let us assume that the width of the block is 1 (in $z-$ direction). In that case, analytical considerations say that the fluid outlet temperature can be calculated using `Solve[q L 1 == rhof uavg cf d 1 (x - Ti), x]`, i.e., $q*L*1 = \rho (d*1) u_{avg} c_p (T_{outlet} - T_i)$, which results in

```
{{x -> 363.828}}
```

However, using this MMA model (in the Update section), we get

`T2[x]` is the average fluid temperature along the outlet boundary

```
T2[x_?NumericQ] := (1/1) NIntegrate[T[x, y], {y, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 12];
Ti + Evaluate[T2[l]]*(q d/ks)

323.395
```

*So there seems to be huge energy imbalance*. Interstingly, I have seen that as the flow velocity, i.e., `u0` is decreased, the amount of this discrepancy grows even further (hinting at diffusion being the main culprit). *With increasing flow velcoity, this imbalance reduces*.

Comment: Could you explain what do you use `MeshTools`?

Comment: In this code it is used to make structured mesh in fluid and the solid domain. Then it is merged together. Finally element marker is used to turn the momentum sink term `c` active in the solid domain (making velocity os solid part =0).

Comment: Why not to solve fluid flow first and then used it as it done in my solution on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277743/refining-mesh-size-leads-to-absurd-results-for-a-coupled-heat-transfer-fem-model/277764#277764

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion Alex. So I should solve the momentum and continuity simultaneously first, but without using any iterator right ? Just like `{UxFun, UyFun, pressure} = NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0}, bcs}, {u, v, p}, {x, y} \[Element] MeshTotal2, Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}}];`. And then substitute `UxFun, UyFun` to the energy equation and solve for `TFun` ?

Comment: Yes, this is right. Please, remove `c` from your code, use `MeshFluid` only for fluid flow simulation, and then extend velocity field as  `ux = If[y <= 0, 0, UxFun[x, y]];
   vy = If[y <= 0, 0, VyFun[x, y]]`.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Multiphysics/ModelCollection/HeatExchanger.html) and to a lesser degree [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Multiphysics/ModelCollection/ThermalDecomposition.html)?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have posted an update after following your recommendations. Please have a look at my `NeumannValue` which I have adjusted in MMA as per the FEM algorithm, folloiwng your suggestion in a comment for a different question. Also I had some warnings and a query regarding integration of the `NDSolve` output. Have a look at your convenience.

Comment: @user21 Thankyou for the links. These seem to be directed exactly at the types of problems I deal with, i.e., transport problems. Meanwhile, I have managed to reach a solution for the current posted problem. See the update. Also, it would be better to have a way to check the sanity (correctnedd) of the results.

Comment: @Avrana Interpolating function warnings coming when we use mesh and exact coordinates together like in your code.  Use `T1[x_?NumericQ] := (1/(e/d)) NIntegrate[
   Ti + T[x, y]*(q d/ks), {y, -e/d, 0}]; Plot[Evaluate[T1[x]], {x, 0, L/d}]`

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thankyou. The Integrate now works, however, Ti and conversion to dimensional temperature have to be done inside the `Plot` command, otherwise it is being ignored. Please also have a look at a conceptual doubt I am having about replicating experimental phenomena in Mathematica 2D modelling, especially the flux and fluid inflow velocity value.

Comment: See [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransferVerificationTests.html) for verification. You should be using [HeatTransferPDEComponent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeatTransferPDEComponent.html)

Comment: The Interpolation issue is serious you should take care of this. Look at the message ref page for more information

Comment: For boundary integrals have a look at [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Multiphysics/ModelCollection/JouleHeating.html).

Comment: @Avrana In a case of $q=q(x,y,z)$ with $0\le z \le W$ we can use, for instance,  mean value $qm(x,y)=\int_0^W q(x,y,z)dz/W$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [this code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278446/modelling-heat-transfer-in-periodically-reversing-flow/278570#278570) for the case when inflow velocity is constant in time. The flow and temperature field in this system will to come to equilibrium after some period. The non-dimentional governing equations are solved here. Dimensional temperature and fluxes are than recalculated.

**Input parameters and mesh generation:**

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Needs["MeshTools`"]

L = 0.040;(*length of the channel*)
d = 0.003;(*depth of the fluid*)
e = 0.005;(*depth of the solid*)
l = L/d;(*dimensionless length*)
rhof = 1.1492;(*fluid density*)
rhos = 7860;(*density of solid*)
mu = 18.923*10^-6;(*dynamic viscosity*)
nu = mu/rhof;(*kinematic viscosity*)
ks = 16;(*conductivity of solid*)
kf = 0.026499;(*conductivity of liquid*)
cf = 1069;(*heat capacity of fluid*)
cs = 502.4;(*heat capacity of solid*)
AlphaF = kf/(cf*rhof);(*thermal diffusivity of fluid*)
AlphaS = ks/(cs*rhos);(*thermal diffusivity of solid*)
f = 1.0;(*flow oscillation frequency*)
period = 1/f;(*period*)
omega = 2*Pi/period;(*circular frequency*)
u0 = 0.5;(*inflow velocity*)
q = 5000;(*heat flux density*)
Ti = 307; (*inflow temperature*)
re = d *u0/nu; (*reinolds number*)
gamma = If[y < 0, 1, kf/ks]; (*relation of conductivities*)
Pe = If[y < 0, u0*d/AlphaS, u0*d/AlphaF];  (*Peclet number*)
c = If[y < 0, 10^6, 0];(*constant in momentum sink term*)

Nx = 100;(*number of elements in x-direction *)
NyF = 20;(*number of elements in y-direction in fluid*)
NyS = 10;(*number of elements in y-direction in solid*)

hy = 1./NyF;(*linear dimension of element in fluid*)
raster = {
   {{0, 0}, {l, 0}},
   {{0, 1}, {l, 1}}
   };
MeshFluid = StructuredMesh[raster, {Nx, NyF}];(*FE mesh in fluid*)
raster = {
   {{0, -e/d}, {l, -e/d}},
   {{0, 0}, {l, 0}}
   };
MeshSolid = StructuredMesh[raster, {Nx, NyS}];(*FE mesh in solid*)
MeshTotal = MeshOrderAlteration[MergeMesh[MeshSolid, MeshFluid], 2];
```

**Solution of PDE:**

```
Clear[TopWall, BottomWall, reference, HeatInpBC, op, rampFunction, sf,
   UinfProfile, Profile, x, y, t];
rampFunction[min_, max_, c_, r_] := 
 Function[t, 
  If[t < 2 c, (min*Exp[c*r] + max*Exp[r*t])/(Exp[c*r] + Exp[r*t]), 
   1]]
sf = rampFunction[0, 1, 0.25, 50];
Profile = 
 Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {hy, 1}, {1 - hy, 1}, {1, 0}}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1]
UinfProfile[y_] := Profile[y]/NIntegrate[Profile[y], {y, 0, 1}]


op = {
   D[u[t, x, y], t] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][({{-1/re, 0}, {0, -1/re}} . 
       Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
      y}] + {{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}} . 
     Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + D[p[t, x, y], x] + 
    c*u[t, x, y], 
   D[v[t, x, y], t] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][({{-1/re, 0}, {0, -1/re}} . 
       Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, 
      y}] + {{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}} . 
     Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}] + D[p[t, x, y], y] + 
    c*v[t, x, y], D[u[t, x, y], x] + D[v[t, x, y], y],
   Pe*gamma*D[T[t, x, y], t] + 
    Pe*gamma*{{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}} . 
      Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
    Inactive[Div][{{-gamma, 0}, {0, -gamma}} . 
      Inactive[Grad][T[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]
   
       };

    TopWall = 
      DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, y == 1];
    BottomWall = 
      DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == 0, v[t, x, y] == 0}, y <= 0];
    reference = DirichletCondition[p[t, x, y] == 0., x == 0 && y == 0];
    HeatInpBC = NeumannValue[1, y == -e/d];
     Inflow = 
      DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == sf[t*d/u0]*UinfProfile[y], 
        v[t, x, y] == 0}, x == 0 && y > 0 && y < 1];
    Outflow = 
      DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y] == sf[t*d/u0]*UinfProfile[y], 
        v[t, x, y] == 0}, x == l && y > 0 && y < 1];
     HeatDBC = 
      DirichletCondition[T[t, x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y > 0 && y <= 1];
    
      ic = {u[0, x, y] == 0, v[ti, x, y] == 0, p[ti, x, y] == 0, 
       T[ti, x, y] == 0};
       bcs = {TopWall, BottomWall, Inflow, Outflow, HeatDBC, reference};

 

    ti = 0;
     tf = 10000 u0/d;
    Clear[UxFun, UyFun, pressure, TFun];
    
    
    Monitor[
      {UxFun, UyFun, pressure, TFun} = 
       NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0, 0, HeatInpBC}, bcs, ic}, {u, v, p, 
         T}, {x, y} \[Element] MeshTotal, {t, ti, tf},
        
        Method -> {
          
          "TimeIntegration" -> {"IDA", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 2},
          
          "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines",
            "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
              "PDESolveOptions" -> {"LinearSolver" -> "Pardiso"}, 
              "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1, T -> 2}}}}
        , EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])]
      , currentTime];
```

**Visualization**

Temperature hystory in point $\{0.5L,0.5d\}$ looks as follows:

```
pic1 = Plot[Ti + (d*q)/ks TFun[t*u0/d, l/2, 0.5], {t, 0, tf*d/u0}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.003], RGBColor[0, 0, 0]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"time [s]", "Temperature"}, 
  FrameStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0], BaseStyle -> 14, ImageSize -> 400, 
  LabelStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0]]
```

[image]

Temperature distributions along channel center line and in central cross section at equilibrium are as follows:

```
pic2 = Plot[Ti + (d*q)/ks TFun[tf, x/d, 0.5], {x, 0, L}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.003], RGBColor[0, 0, 0]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x [m]", "Temperature"}, 
  FrameStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0], BaseStyle -> 14, ImageSize -> 300, 
  LabelStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0]]

pic3 = Plot[Ti + (d*q)/ks TFun[tf, 0.5, y/d], {y, -e, d}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.003], RGBColor[0, 0, 0]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"y [m]", "Temperature"}, 
  FrameStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0], BaseStyle -> 14, ImageSize -> 300, 
  LabelStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0]]
```

[image]
[image]

**Integral heat balance check**

Let's write the integral heat balance for stationary sate:

\begin{equation}
c_f\rho_f\int_0^d\left(T(L,y)u_x(L,y)-T(0,y)u_x(0,y) \right)dy=\int_{\partial \Omega}k\frac{\partial T}{\partial n}ds
\end{equation}

@user21 gave useful [link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Multiphysics/ModelCollection/JouleHeating.html) where similar surface integrals are calculated. Let's take advantage of this approach.

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[MeshTotal];
tolerance = 10^-2 hy;
leftSurfFluid[x_, y_] := If[Abs[x] <= tolerance && y >= 0, 1, 0]
rightSurfFluid[x_, y_] := If[Abs[x - l] <= tolerance && y >= 0, 1, 0]
leftSurfSolid[x_, y_] := If[Abs[x] <= tolerance && y < 0, 1, 0]
rightSurfSolid[x_, y_] := If[Abs[x - l] <= tolerance && y < 0, 1, 0]
bottomSurf[x_, y_] := If[Abs[y + e/d] <= tolerance && y < 0, 1, 0]
topSurf[x_, y_] := If[Abs[y - 1] <= tolerance && y < 0, 1, 0]

GradX = Derivative[0, 1, 0][TFun];
GradY = Derivative[0, 0, 1][TFun];
```

Calculation of terms in right hand side of balance equation

```
Q1 = -q*d*(kf/ks)*
  NIntegrate[
   leftSurfFluid[x, y]*GradX[tf, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] bmesh]
Q2 = q*d*kf/
  ks NIntegrate[
   rightSurfFluid[x, y]*GradX[tf, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] bmesh]
Q3 = -q*d*
  NIntegrate[
   leftSurfSolid[x, y]*GradX[tf, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] bmesh]
Q4 = q*d*
  NIntegrate[
   rightSurfSolid[x, y]*GradX[tf, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] bmesh]
Q5 = -q*d*
  NIntegrate[bottomSurf[x, y]*GradY[tf, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] bmesh]
Q6 = q*d*
  NIntegrate[topSurf[x, y]*GradY[tf, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] bmesh]
```

gives

```
-2.49716

-0.0133357

-5.72554

-0.0324436

200.

0.
```

Right hand side equals to **191.732** W/m

```
Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4 + Q5 + Q6
```

Calculation of left hand side gives **192.601** W/m:

```
deltaQ = (NIntegrate[
     rightSurfFluid[x, y]*UxFun[tf, x, y]*
      TFun[tf, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] bmesh] - 
    NIntegrate[
     leftSurfFluid[x, y]*UxFun[tf, x, y]*
      TFun[tf, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] bmesh])*(d^2*q*u0/ks)*rhof*cf
```

The exact value of supplied heat flux at $y=-e$ equals to $q\cdot L$=**200** W/m. As we can see the heat balance discrepancy is not so large. In addition it depends on FE mesh used.

**Update**

By using previous FE mesh we obtained numerically heat flux `Q3`=$\int_0^dk_s\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}|_{x=0}dy=-5.72$ W/m which is not equals to 0. It's confuses a little bit. However in the vicinity of point {0,0} the large temperature gradients appear and more fine FE mesh is required in this region for better approximation. Let's try the refined mesh:

```
NyS = 10; (*number of elements in solid*)
NyF = 20; (*number of elements in fluid*)
NxS = 100; (*number of elements in x-direction*)
hyMin = 1/40; (*linear dimension of the smallest element*)
hxMin = hyMin;
hy = 1./NyF;(*linear dimension of element in fluid*)

meshX1d = 
  ToGradedMesh[
   Line[{{0}, {l}}], <| "Alignment" -> "Left", 
    "ElementCount" -> NxS,  "MinimalDistance" -> hyMin|>];
meshY1d = MergeMesh[
   ToGradedMesh[
    Line[{{-e/d}, {0}}], <| "Alignment" -> "Right", 
     "ElementCount" -> NyS,  "MinimalDistance" -> hyMin|>],
   ToGradedMesh[
    Line[{{0}, {1}}], <| "Alignment" -> "Left", 
     "ElementCount" -> NyF,  "MinimalDistance" -> hyMin|>]
               ];
MeshTotal = ElementMeshRegionProduct[meshX1d, meshY1d];
MeshTotal["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

In this case we get `Q3=-2.03978` W/m, `deltaQ=193.113` W/m.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer again, especially for showing the application of heat balance check. I was having a hard time understanding it from the tutorials.

Comment: Everything works fine, for the tests I have run. The net energy balance works good. However, there is one discrepancy which I would like to point out, i.e., the value of `Q3`, which comes out as significant. In your example, it is around `-17.698`, although, this left solid boundary is insulated. However, the net energy balance is within `1.27 %`. Insulated is the default b.c. in NDSolve.

Comment: Since you have a grasp about such flow and heat transfer problems, I would like your advice on Point 3 in my update section. Please, have a look. It is a conceptual doubt, I cannot seem to address satisfactorily.

Comment: As to value of `Q3`. Yes, at first  glance this value confuses a little. However we should don't forget that FEM is the approximate method. And the heat fluxes recalculated from temperature field  will tend to Neumann b.c. used with decreasing of element size near boundary. In addition temperature gradients near point {0,0} are large and adaptive mesh should be used in this region for better approximation.

Comment: As to experimental values of heat flux $Q$ and flow rate $\frac{dV}{dt}$. For inflow velocity we have $u_0=\frac{dV}{dt}\frac{1}{Wd}$ and for heat flux density supplied $q=\frac{Q}{dW}$. Of course the last formula is correct if heat flux is distributed uniformly on surface $y=-e$

Comment: In addition, the flow can be considered to be plane (2D) when $W>>d$. Otherwise 3D problem should be solved. And it makes the problem more complicated, and computations become more time consuming

Comment: Thankyou for the updates. Now it's much clear. It is axial conduxtion in the solid, which is prominent near the inlet sections. Also thankyou for running these time-taking computations and clarifying my doubt regarding conversion from 3D to 2D.