# Coupled heat transfer equations using collocation method

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, matrix, heat-equation

Using the collocation method proposed [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2457908), recently [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262458/unbounded-solution-at-boundaries-with-few-combination-of-values-in-this-bvp-solu) problem has been solved. I am trying to solve a similar problem described by the  equations given below. My attempt in Mathematica is following.

$T$ is in the domain $x\in[0,1], y\in[0,1]$

```
eq1 = \[Lambda]x D[T[x, y], x, x] + \[Lambda]y D[T[x, y], y, y] == 
  0; bc1 = {(D[T[x, y], y] + rh (Tfh[x] - T[x, y]) == 0) /. 
   y -> 1, (D[T[x, y], y] + rc (T[x, y] - Tfc[x]) == 0) /. 
   y -> 0}; eq2 = D[T[x], x] + bh (Tfh[x] - T[x]) == 0;
bc2 = Tfh[0] == 1;
eq3 = D[Tfc[x], x] + bc (T[x] - Tfc[x]) == 0;
bc3 = Tfc[0] == 0;

UE[m_, t_] := Cos[m t] Exp[-m t]
nn = 3;
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; ycol = 
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 Table[UE[n, t1], {n, 0, nn - 1}]; Int1 = Integrate[Psijk, t1];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y;
int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y; M = nn;
M = nn; U1 = Array[a1, {M, M}]; U2 = Array[a2, {M, M}]; G1 = 
 Array[g1, {M}]; G2 = Array[g2, {M}]; G4 = Array[g4, {M}]; G5 = 
 Array[g5, {M}];

Tfhx[x_] := (Psi[x].G5);
Tfcy[x_] := (Psi[x].G4);
Tfh[x_] := (int1[x].G5);
Tfc[x_] := (int2[x].G4);

u1[x_, y_] := (int2[x].U1.Psi[y]) + x Psi[y].G1;
u2[x_, y_] := (Psi[x].U2.int2[y]) + y Psi[x].G2;
uy[x_, y_] := (Psi[x].U2.int1[y]) + Psi[x].G2;
ux[x_, y_] := (int1[x].U1.Psi[y]) + Psi[y].G1;
uxx[x_, y_] := (Psi[x].U1.Psi[y]);
uyy[x_, y_] := (Psi[x].U2.Psi[y]);

\[Lambda]x = 1/0.025^2; \[Lambda]y = 1/0.002^2; bh = 0.625; bc = 
 4 bh; rh = 3000 0.002/390; rc = 3000 0.002/390;

eqn = Join[
   Flatten[Table[(\[Lambda]x uxx[xcol[[i]], 
          ycol[[j]]] + \[Lambda]y uyy[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]]) == 0, {i,
       M}, {j, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     u1[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] == 0, {i, 
      M}, {j, M}]], Flatten[Table[ux[1, ycol[[i]]] == 0, {i, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[uy[xcol[[i]], 1] == 0, {i, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[ux[0, ycol[[i]]] == 0, {i, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[uy[xcol[[i]], 0] == 0, {i, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     uy[xcol[[i]], 1] + rh (Tfh[xcol[[i]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], 1]) == 
      0, {i, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     uy[xcol[[i]], 0] + rc (u2[xcol[[i]], 0] - Tfc[xcol[[i]]]) == 
      0, {i, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     Tfhx[xcol[[i]]] + bh (Tfh[xcol[[i]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], 1]) == 
      0, {i, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     tcy[xcol[[i]]] + bc (u2[xcol[[i]], 0] - Tfc[xcol[[i]]]) == 0, {i,
       M}]], Table[Tfh[xcol[[i]]] == 1., {i, M}], 
   Table[Tfc[xcol[[i]], 0] == 0., {i, M}]];
var = Join[Flatten[U1], Flatten[U2], Flatten[G1], Flatten[G2], 
   Flatten[G4], Flatten[G5]];

{v, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eqn, var];

sol = LinearSolve[mat, -v];

rule = Table[var[[i]] -> sol[[i]], {i, Length[var]}];

{Plot[Evaluate[Tfc[x] /. rule], {x, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
   MeshStyle -> White, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> Tfc], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[Tfh[x] /. rule], {x, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", MeshStyle -> White, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> Tfh], 
 Table[Plot3D[Evaluate[u1[x, y] /. rule], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", MeshStyle -> White, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> T[y]], {y, 0, 1, .5}]}
```

The code above tries to solve the following equations:

$$\lambda_x \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}+\lambda_y \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2}=0 \tag1$$

Zero gradient of $T$ at $x=0,1$.

At $y=0,1$ the solid ($T$) is exposed to two different fluids following opposite to each other (separated by the solid).

$$\frac{\partial T(x,0)}{\partial y}+r_c(T(x,0)-t_c)=0\tag2$$
$$\frac{\partial T(x,1)}{\partial y}+r_h(t_h-T(x,1))=0\tag3$$

The fluid temperatures $t_h,t_c$ are governed by:

$$\frac{\partial t_h}{\partial x}+\beta_h(t_h-T)=0\tag4$$
$$\frac{\partial t_c}{\partial x}+\beta_c(T-t_c)=0\tag5$$

*A reduced order model*

The above problem can be simplified if one averages the solid temperature along the $y$ direction to get the following solid governing equation instead of $(1)$:

$$\kappa \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 T}{\mathrm{d} x^2} + \mu b_h(t_h-T) - \nu b_c(T-t_c)=0 \tag6$$

with $T'(0)=T'(1)=0$. Equation $(6)$ is still coupled with Equation $(4)$ and Equation $(5)$. Some parameter values are `bc=12.38, bh=25.32, mu=1.143, nu=1, kappa=2.16`

**Some cases behaving wierdly**

Although the wavelet method works really fine, but I am facing problems with some particular set of flow configurations, which are physically important. One of them being the following:

`λx = 1/0.025^2; λy = 1/0.001^2; bh = 173.6539; bc = 355.1724; rh = 134.31 0.001/16; rc = 305.2252 0.001/16;`

Upon executing these parameters, with the wavelet method such that `nn=16`, I obtain the following plots of the fluid temperature profiles

[image]

For `nn=40`, the plot is like the following:

[image]

Lastly, the `nn=96` gives:

[image]

As it is clear that the fluid temperature profiles experience spikes. Although, they do decrease in magnitude with increasing `nn`. I would like to know the reason as to why this is happening and if they can be removed. I have checked that the insulation boundary conditions on `x=0,1` are satisfied to the order of `10^-12`.

Comment: There is a typo in `eq2 = D[T[x], x] + bh (Tfh[x] - T[x]) == 0;`.

Comment: If fluid flows at `y=0, y=1`are opposite then it should be `eq2 = D[Tfh[x], x] + bh (Tfh[x] - T[x, 1]) == 0; bc2 = Tfh[0] == 1; eq3 = D[Tfc[x], x] + bc (T[x, 0] - Tfc[x]) == 0; bc3 = Tfc[1] == 0;`

Comment: @AlexTrounev yes you are right about the typos in eq2 and eq3, but they are not being used while solving the system. The implementation of these in `eqn`, I have used `bh (Tfh[xcol[[i]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], 1])` and similarly for the bc equation.

Comment: There is also typo in `eqn` in the line `tcy[xcol[[i]]] + bc (u2[xcol[[i]], 0] - Tfc[xcol[[i]]]) == 0`. `tcy` is not defined.

Comment: What bc do you use for `Tfc`? In your code there is `bc3 = Tfc[0] == 0;`, but I have used opposite `bc3 = Tfc[1] == 0;`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have utilised your code, when I used `UE[m_, t_] := Cos[m t] Exp[-m t]`. I just removed the parts relating to Euler wavelets. So, the `bc3=Tfc[1]==0` is the boundary condition I used to report the results I mentioned in the comments to your answer.

Comment: In the last example there is numerical instability due to large `bc, bh`.  To avoid this instability we need take `dx<Min[{1/bc,1/bh}]`, and `nn=Round[1/dx ] consequently. Therefore,  `nn>355` for this case.  So, we need supercomputer or other method to compute  cases with  large `bc, bh`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thankyou for the explanation. The underlying reason is much clearer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution with Euler wavelets:

```
eq1 = \[Lambda]x D[T[x, y], x, x] + \[Lambda]y D[T[x, y], y, y] == 
  0; bc1 = {(D[T[x, y], y] + rh (Tfh[x] - T[x, y]) == 0) /. 
   y -> 1, (D[T[x, y], y] + rc (T[x, y] - Tfc[x]) == 0) /. 
   y -> 0}; eq2 = D[Tfh[x], x] + bh (Tfh[x] - T[x, 1]) == 0;
bc2 = Tfh[0] == 1;
eq3 = D[Tfc[x], x] + bc (T[x, 0] - Tfc[x]) == 0;
bc3 = Tfc[1] == 0;


UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t]
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 4; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 var1 = Flatten[Table[c[n, m], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]];
nn = Length[var1]
dx = 1/(nn);  xl = Table[ l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; ycol = 
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y; 
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y;
M = nn; U1 = Array[a1, {M, M}]; U2 = Array[a2, {M, M}]; G1 = 
 Array[g1, {M}]; G2 = Array[g2, {M}]; G3 = Array[g3, {M}]; G4 = 
 Array[g4, {M}]; F1 = Array[f1, {M}]; F2 = Array[f2, {M}];


u1[x_, y_] := int2[x] . U1 . Psi[y] + x G1 . Psi[y] + F1 . Psi[y]; 
u2[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U2 . int2[y] + y G2 . Psi[x] + F2 . Psi[x];
uy[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U2 . int1[y] + G2 . Psi[x];
ux[x_, y_] := int1[x] . U1 . Psi[y] + G1 . Psi[y];
uxx[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U1 . Psi[y];
uyy[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U2 . Psi[y];
Tfhx[x_] := Psi[x] . G3; Tfcx[x_] := Psi[x] . G4; 
Tfh[x_] := int1[x] . G3 + th0; Tfc[x_] := int1[x] . G4 + tc0;


\[Lambda]x = 1/0.025^2; \[Lambda]y = 1/0.002^2; bh = 0.625; bc = 
 4 bh; rh = 3000 0.002/390; rc = 3000 0.002/390;

eqn = Join[
   Flatten[Table[(\[Lambda]x uxx[xcol[[i]], 
          ycol[[j]]] + \[Lambda]y uyy[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]]) == 0, {i,
       M}, {j, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     u1[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] == 0, {i, 
      M}, {j, M}]], Table[ux[1., ycol[[i]]] == 0, {i, M}], 
   Table[ux[0., ycol[[i]]] == 0, {i, M}], 
   Table[uy[xcol[[i]], 1.] + rh (Tfh[xcol[[i]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], 1.]) ==
      0, {i, M}], 
   Table[uy[xcol[[i]], 0.] + rc (u2[xcol[[i]], 0.] - Tfc[xcol[[i]]]) ==
      0, {i, M}], 
   Table[Tfhx[xcol[[i]]] + bh (Tfh[xcol[[i]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], 1.]) == 
     0, {i, M}], 
   Table[Tfcx[xcol[[i]]] + bc (u2[xcol[[i]], 0] - Tfc[xcol[[i]]]) == 
     0, {i, M}], {Tfh[0.] == 1.}, {Tfc[1.] == 0.}];
var = Join[Flatten[U1], Flatten[U2], G1, G2, G3, G4, F1, 
   F2, {th0, tc0}];


{v, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eqn, var];


sol = LinearSolve[mat // N, -v];


rule = Table[var[[i]] -> sol[[i]], {i, Length[var]}];
```

Visualization

```
{Plot[Evaluate[Tfc[x] /. rule], {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> Tfc], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Tfh[x] /. rule], {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> Tfh], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[u1[x, y] /. rule], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, MeshStyle -> Black, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> T, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", AxesLabel -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 1]
This code can be testified on antisymmetric solution with `bc=bh, rc=rh, Tfh[0]==1, Tfc[1]==-1`, then we should have solution satisfies equation `tfc[x]+tfh[1-x]==0`. Example 1:

```
eq1 = \[Lambda]x D[T[x, y], x, x] + \[Lambda]y D[T[x, y], y, y] == 
  0; bc1 = {(D[T[x, y], y] + rh (Tfh[x] - T[x, y]) == 0) /. 
   y -> 1, (D[T[x, y], y] + rc (T[x, y] - Tfc[x]) == 0) /. 
   y -> 0}; eq2 = D[Tfh[x], x] + bh (Tfh[x] - T[x, 1]) == 0;
bc2 = Tfh[0] == 1;
eq3 = D[Tfc[x], x] + bc (T[x, 0] - Tfc[x]) == 0;
bc3 = Tfc[1] == -1;


UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t]
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 2; M0 = 7; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 var1 = Flatten[Table[c[n, m], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]];
nn = Length[var1]
dx = 1/(nn);  xl = Table[ l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; ycol = 
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y; 
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y;
M = nn; U1 = Array[a1, {M, M}]; U2 = Array[a2, {M, M}]; G1 = 
 Array[g1, {M}]; G2 = Array[g2, {M}]; G3 = Array[g3, {M}]; G4 = 
 Array[g4, {M}]; F1 = Array[f1, {M}]; F2 = Array[f2, {M}];


u1[x_, y_] := int2[x] . U1 . Psi[y] + x G1 . Psi[y] + F1 . Psi[y]; 
u2[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U2 . int2[y] + y G2 . Psi[x] + F2 . Psi[x];
uy[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U2 . int1[y] + G2 . Psi[x];
ux[x_, y_] := int1[x] . U1 . Psi[y] + G1 . Psi[y];
uxx[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U1 . Psi[y];
uyy[x_, y_] := Psi[x] . U2 . Psi[y];
Tfhx[x_] := Psi[x] . G3; Tfcx[x_] := Psi[x] . G4; 
Tfh[x_] := int1[x] . G3 + th0; Tfc[x_] := int1[x] . G4 + tc0;


\[Lambda]x = 1/0.025^2; \[Lambda]y = 
 1/0.002^2; bh = bc = 0.625; rh = 3000 0.002/390; rc = 3000 0.002/390;

eqn = Join[
   Flatten[Table[(\[Lambda]x uxx[xcol[[i]], 
          ycol[[j]]] + \[Lambda]y uyy[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]]) == 0, {i,
       M}, {j, M}]], 
   Flatten[Table[
     u1[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], ycol[[j]]] == 0, {i, 
      M}, {j, M}]], Table[ux[1., ycol[[i]]] == 0, {i, M}], 
   Table[ux[0., ycol[[i]]] == 0, {i, M}], 
   Table[uy[xcol[[i]], 1.] + rh (Tfh[xcol[[i]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], 1.]) ==
      0, {i, M}], 
   Table[uy[xcol[[i]], 0.] + rc (u2[xcol[[i]], 0.] - Tfc[xcol[[i]]]) ==
      0, {i, M}], 
   Table[Tfhx[xcol[[i]]] + bh (Tfh[xcol[[i]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], 1.]) == 
     0, {i, M}], 
   Table[Tfcx[xcol[[i]]] + bc (u2[xcol[[i]], 0] - Tfc[xcol[[i]]]) == 
     0, {i, M}], {Tfh[0.] == 1.}, {Tfc[1.] == -1.}];
var = Join[Flatten[U1], Flatten[U2], G1, G2, G3, G4, F1, 
   F2, {th0, tc0}];


{v, mat} = CoefficientArrays[eqn, var];


sol = LinearSolve[mat // N, -v];


rule = Table[var[[i]] -> sol[[i]], {i, Length[var]}];
```

Visualization

```
{Plot[Evaluate[Tfc[x] /. rule], {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> Tfc], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Tfh[x] /. rule], {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> Tfh, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Tfc[x] + Tfh[1 - x]] /. rule, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Tfc[x]+Tfh[1-x]"], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[u1[x, y] /. rule], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, MeshStyle -> Black, PlotLabel -> T, 
  PlotTheme -> "Marketing", AxesLabel -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 2]
Therefore the max error of sum `Tfc[x] + Tfh[1 - x]]` is about $6\times 10^{-14}$ for `M=14`.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. However, I have a doubt. Can you inform where the boundary conditions of zero gradient of $T$ at $x=0,1$ or $\frac{\partial T(0,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial T(1,y)}{\partial x}=0$are being implemented in this methodology. Do the Euler wavelets implicitly assume so?

Comment: I am doubtful about this because when I run this system for `bh=bc`, which corresponds to equal flow rates of both the hot and cold fluid, the temperature rise in the cold fluid is not equal to the temperature drop in the hot fluid. However, in the case of equal flow they should be same. In other words for equal flow or `bc=bh` and when the solid faces at `x=0` and `x=1` are insulated, one is supposed to get `Tfc[0]+Tfh[1]=1`.

Comment: However, when I use the `UE[m_, t_] := Cos[m t] Exp[-m t]`, the problem of energy balance is taken care of. I think the `cos` eigen-functions ensure zero $T$ gradients at $x=0,1$. For example for `bh=bc=0.625`, `Tfc[0]+Tfh[1]=1.` with this function as the basis.

Comment: I have also posted the governing equations for a reduced-order model for this problem. The solution to this model is partially available in literature for diffferent set of b.c.(s), i.e. $T'(0)=T'(1)=0$ and $T'(0)=1,T(1)=0$. Please give it a try as it might be helpful for validation of the present system.

Comment: Also, although I have been able to achieve some success with `UE[m_, t_] := Cos[m t] Exp[-m t]`, the temperature profiles I recieve with this set of parameter values `\[Lambda]x = 1/0.025^2; \[Lambda]y = 
 1/0.002^2; bh = 25.32; bc = 12.38; rh = 305.2252 0.002/16; rc = 
 134.31 0.002/16;` are very unphysical. The fluid temperatures basically drop and then rise again, which should not happen. Have a look if time permits.

Comment: @Avrana Please, note, that equations  `Table[ux[1., ycol[[i]]] == 0, {i, M}], 
   Table[ux[0., ycol[[i]]] == 0, {i, M}]` are identical to $\frac{\partial T(0,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial T(1,y)}{\partial x}=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Then it is weird why the energy balance for `bc=bh` is not being respected in the Euler wavelet approach.

Comment: As I understand antisymmetric solution  should be  at `bc=bh, rc=rh` and `bc2 = Tfh[0] == 1; bc3 = Tfc[1] == -1;`, then with basis `Cos[m t] Exp[-m t]` we have `Tfc[x] + Tfh[1 - x]=0` with max error of $3\times 10^{-5}$  at `nn=8` while with wavelets the max error is about  $3\times 10^{-2}$. I will check code with wavelets to get why error is so large.

Comment: Ok, I got a typo in a code with mixing `u1, u2`. In equations for `bc1, Tfh, Tfc` we should use `u2`. Code has been corrected and test example has been added.

Comment: The wavelet method works perfectly, but while testing with some particular very low flow rate configurations involving gases, I have found some weird results which I have added as an extension to the original question. I was wondering if this is due to the matrix inversion step in the code or are the equations themselve cannot describe the phenomena.

Comment: The following definition of `psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1 )/ 2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]` takes the Euler polynomial from the range $t\in[-1,1]$ . I wonder why? EU is symmetric or antisymmetric with respect to t=1/2 on the interval [0,1].  It can be assumed that the accepted definition of the wavelet will not allow us to approximate any symmetric function.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov  Please, pay attention that we don't use orthogonality and symmetry of `Psi` in the approximation $u_{xx}, u_{yy}$, since final solution depends on `u1, u2`. For this method we need `int1, int2` in the explicit form. It is why normally we use the Haar wavelets.  But with the Euler wavelets we can compute solution with zero absolute error. This is the main reason for me to test the Euler wavelets in different applications.

Comment: I wonder which set of Euler polynomials compose complete system? In other words, how do we know that the set of basis functions you have chosen is sufficient to approximate any function [with a sufficiently large number of basis functions in the set]?

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov Don't mix up the Euler polynomials and wavelets base we used. We can replace `EulerE[m, t]` with any other polynomials, like `BernoulliB` or  `ChebyshevT`.

Comment: Ok. You take `EulerE[m, t]` on [-1,1] to fit 2nd derivates. It is known how to use `ChebyshevT` for this aim, and the procedure makes us sure that `ChebyshevT` polynomials compose a complete system of basis funcs. I wonder why do you ignore the requirement of completness for `EulerE[m, t]` on [-1,1]? How can you argue the wavelet method yields correct solution if you are not able to approximate any shape of `uxx` or `uyy`?

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov If you like `ChebyshevT` you can replace `EulerE` with `ChebyshevT`. Run code and compare with `EulerE`. After this test you will be able to understand, that we approximate `uxx, uyy` with using wavelets, not polynomials.