# Symbolic solution for steady-state heat equation i.e. Laplace equation inside cylinder

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, heat-equation

I want to symbolically solve the following boundary value problem in my textbook. It's steady-state heat conduction equation i.e. Laplace equation inside a cylinder

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\Delta u=0\\
\left.u\right|_{\rho=a}=u_{0} \\
\left.u\right|_{z=0}=\left.0 \quad u\right|_{z=h}=0
\end{array}\right.
$$

The following series solution can be found manually by method of separation of variables:

$$
\begin{aligned}
u&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} A_{m} I_{0}\left(\frac{m \pi}{h} \rho\right) \sin \frac{m \pi}{h} z \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{4 u_{0}}{I_{0}\left[\frac{(2 n+1) \pi}{h} a\right](2 n+1) \pi} I_{0}\left[\frac{(2 n+1) \pi}{h} \rho\right] \sin \left[\frac{(2 n+1) \pi}{h} z\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

But `DSolve` can't solve the problem:

```mathematica
eq = D[u[rho, z], {rho, 2}] + D[u[rho, z], {rho, 1}]/rho + 
   D[u[rho, z], {z, 2}] == 0
ic1 = {u[rho, 0] == 0, u[rho, 1] == 0};
ic2 = {u[1, z] == 1};

DSolve[{eq, ic1, ic2}, u, {rho, z}]
```

[image]

Why?

Comment: 2nd $∑_{m=1}^∞$ should be $∑_{n=0}^∞$ , right?

Comment: @xzczd m=2n+1,You can do it by ha
nd, but you can't do it by software

Comment: I mean, there's a typo in your $\LaTeX$, 2nd $m=1$ should be $n=0$. Please correct it.

Comment: @xzczd I have correct it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This post contains several code blocks, you can copy them easily with the help of functions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3535/1871).

---

It's not too surprising to see `DSolve` failing on the problem, because though `DSolve` is improved these years, it's still fragile. So let me show a solution based on finite Fourier sine transform, which is much cleaner and easier to understand than separation of variables.

I'll use [`finiteFourierSinTransform`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155817/1871) for the task.

It's not necessary, but we define 2 functions to make the output pretty:

```
Format@finiteFourierSinTransform[f_, __] := Subscript[ℱ, s][f]    
Format@u0 := Subscript[u, 0]
```

Then we write down the equation and transform. Here I'd like to point out that, except for the 3 b.c.s in the question, there actually exists an **implicit** constraint i.e. the solution is **bounded** for $\rho<a$. In your specific case, the solution is axisymetric, so the constraint is equivalent to

$$\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial \rho}\right|_{\rho=0}=0$$

I'll include this new b.c. in the code to facilitate subsequent discussion:

```
With[{u = u[ρ, z]}, eq = Laplacian[u, {ρ, ϕ, z}, "Cylindrical"] == 0;
  bcz = u == 0 /. {{z -> 0}, {z -> h}};
  bcrexplicit = u == u0 /. ρ -> a;
  bcrimplicit = D[u, ρ] == 0 /. ρ -> 0];

finiteFourierSinTransform[{eq, bcrexplicit, bcrimplicit}, {z, 0, h}, m]
```

[image]

```
% /. Rule @@@ bcz
```

[image]

```
tset = % /. HoldPattern@finiteFourierSinTransform[f_, __] :> f /. u -> (U@# &)
```

[image]

Here I use `U` to represent finite Fourier sine transform of `u` to facilitate subsequent coding.

`tset` is 2nd order ODE with 2 b.c.s, and `DSolve` can handle it:

```
tsol = DSolveValue[tset, U@ρ, ρ] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

> **Remark**
>
> If we haven't included `bcrimplicit` in the code, it's still possible
> to obtain `tsol`, but the discussion is a bit involved. Without
> `bcrimplicit`, we'll need to solve 2nd order ODE with 1 b.c. i.e.
>
> ```
> tsolmid = DSolveValue[tset // Most, U@ρ, ρ] // FullSimplify
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> There remains a constant `C[1]`, which is expected, because we haven't
> use the implicit constraint that the solution is bounded for
> $\rho<a$. Sadly there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to
> impose this condition in `DSolve` at this stage, but by picking up, or
> simply testing properties of `BesselY` a bit, we know that
>
> ```
> BesselY[0, -((I m π ρ)/h)] /. ρ -> 0
> (* -∞ *)
>
> Abs@BesselY[0, -((I a m π)/h)] < Infinity // Simplify
> (* True *)
> ```
>
> So, to keep the solution bounded for $\rho<a$, the coefficient of
> `BesselY[0, -((I m π ρ)/h)]` must be `0` i.e.
>
> ```
> const = Solve[-(((-1 + (-1)^m) h u0)/(m π)) - BesselI[0, (a m π)/h] C[1] == 
>     0, C[1], Assumptions -> h > 0][[1]]
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> Substitute it back to `tsolmid`, we obtain the `tsol` as shown above:
>
> ```
> tsol = tsolmid /. const // Simplify
> ```

The final step is to transform back:

```
sol = inverseFiniteFourierSinTransform[tsol, m, {z, 0, h}]
```

[image]

It's not hard to notice this is already the solution in your question. (Notice I use `C` to represent `Infinity` when designing `inverseFiniteFourierSinTransform`. ) You can make it more pretty, of course:

```
solpretty = 
 sol /. coef_ HoldForm[Sum[expr_, {i_, C}]] :> 
    Inactive[Sum][expr coef, {i, 1, Infinity}] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
solfinal = solpretty /. m -> 2 n + 1 /. {2 n + 1, 1, ∞} -> {n, 0, ∞} // 
 Simplify[#, n ∈ NonNegativeIntegers] &

(*
solfinal = 
 Inactive[Sum][(
  4 u0 BesselI[0, ((1 + 2 n) π ρ)/h] Sin[((1 + 2 n) π z)/
    h])/((1 + 2 n) π BesselI[0, (a (1 + 2 n) π)/h]), {n, 0, ∞}]
 *)
```

[image]

You can use the solution for visualization, of course:

```
hvalue = 1; u0value = 1; avalue = 1; nvalue = 10;

asol = solfinal /. {TraditionalForm -> Identity, ∞ -> nvalue, 
     a -> avalue, u0 -> u0value, h -> hvalue} // Activate;

SliceDensityPlot3D[
  asol /. ρ -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] // Evaluate, 
  "CenterPlanes", {x, y, z} ∈ Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, hvalue}}, avalue]]
```

[image]

Compare it with FEM-based numeric solution:

```
fem[measure_ : Automatic] := {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> measure};

nsol = NDSolveValue[{eq, bcz, bcrexplicit} /. {a -> avalue, u0 -> u0value, 
     h -> hvalue}, u, {ρ, 0, avalue}, {z, 0, hvalue}, Method -> fem[10^-4]];

Manipulate[
 Plot[{#, nsol[ρ, z]} // Evaluate, {z, 0, hvalue}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}], {ρ, 0, avalue}] &@asol
```

[image]

The error is a bit obvious at $\rho=a$, but as an approximation with the first 10 terms of the series only, this isn't bad.

Comment: you say  `finiteFourierSinTransform`,This is the first time I've heard of it. I'm going to learn it

Comment: @我心永恒 Since you can read Chinese, you may want to read this: https://www.zhihu.com/question/412203550/answer/1388426673

Comment: thanks you,I will read it.